# Método não-estático não pode ser referenciado de contexto estático?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Eu estava assistindo a aula de programação em java e basicamente o negócio era calcular a área total de uma casa com uma piscina, porém, eu estou tendo dificuldades. Basicamente eu separei tudo em três arquivos, sendo um deles o principal, mas quando tento compilar, aparece a mensagem dizendo:

> método não-estático não pode ser referenciado de um contexto estático

AreaCasa.java:

```
public class AreaCasa {
    //preço do metro quadrado
    double valorM2 = 1500;

    //calcula a área da casa
    double CasaRet(double l_sala, double c_quarto) {
        double area_s; //área da sala
        double area_q; //área do quarto
        double area_t = 0; //área do total

        if(l_sala < 0 || c_quarto < 0)
             System.out.println("Erro!");

        else{
            area_s = l_sala * l_sala; //calcula area da sala
            area_q = c_quarto * (l_sala/2); //calcula area do quarto            
            area_t = area_s + 2 * area_q; //calcula a area total
        }
        return(area_t);
    }
}
```

AreaPiscina.java:

```
public class AreaPiscina {
    double AreaPiscina(double raio){ 
        return((raio >= 0) ? Math.PI * Math.pow(raio, 2) : -1);
    }
}
```

Projeto.java (é o arquivo principal):

```
public class Projeto {
    double Area(double lateral_1, double lateral_2, double pis_raio) {
        return(AreaCasa.CasaRet(lateral_1, lateral_2) + AreaPiscina.AreaPiscina(pis_raio));
    }

    public void main (String args[]) {
        System.out.println(Area(21.43, 33.4, 2.0));
    }
}
```

Quando tento compilar este último arquivo aparece:

```
[user@localhost TesteJava]$ javac Projeto.java
Projeto.java:3: error: non-static method CasaRet(double,double) cannot be referenced from a static context
    return(AreaCasa.CasaRet(lateral_1, lateral_2) + 
                   ^
Projeto.java:4: error: non-static method AreaPiscina(double) cannot be referenced from a static context
    AreaPiscina.AreaPiscina(pis_raio));
               ^
 2 errors
```

não consigo entender porque está dando erro, as funções dentro da classe projeto nem são estáticas (eu acho)! Eu acho que fiz tudo direitinho passando os valores por referência para outra função.

Comment: Exatamente isso! Você está tentando acessar metodos não-estáticos de forma estática.

Comment: como assim de forma estática? O terminal de fato me informou, mas como eu posso tornar as funções da classe Projeto.java em não-estáticas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está tentando acessar métodos não-estáticos de forma estática.

Ao fazer `AreaCasa.CasaRet(lateral_1, lateral_2) + AreaPiscina.AreaPiscina(pis_raio);` você está chamando os métodos das classes `AreaCasa` e `AreaPiscina` de forma estática(Classe.método) sem que os métodos sejam estáticos(identificado por `static`), sem contar que está tentando dar um `return`  em um construtor.

Para usar os métodos da forma como você os escreveu, é preciso instanciar as classes antes de usar seus métodos:

> OBs.: O construtor não retorna valores, então você precisa criar um
>   método com nome diferente da classe `AreaPiscina`.

```
    public class AreaPiscina {

    double calcularArea(double raio){ 
      return((raio >= 0) ? Math.PI * Math.pow(raio, 2) : -1);
    }

}
```

E depois fazer a chamada:

```
 double Area(double lateral_1, double lateral_2, double pis_raio) {
         AreaCasa casa = new AreaCasa();
         AreaPiscina piscina = new AreaPiscina(); 
        return(casa.CasaRet(lateral_1, lateral_2) + piscina.calcularArea(pis_raio));
    }
```

E na classe do main:

```
public void main (String args[]) {
    Projeto p = new Projeto();
    System.out.println(p.Area(21.43, 33.4, 2.0));
   }
```

Veja funcionando no **[ideone](http://ideone.com/TDX8ZP)**.

---

Outra solução seria alterar as classes e métodos para `static`:

Classe AreaPiscina:

```
    public static class AreaPiscina {

    static double calcularArea(double raio){ 
      return((raio >= 0) ? Math.PI * Math.pow(raio, 2) : -1);
    }

}
```

Classe AreaCasa:

```
public static class AreaCasa {
    //preço do metro quadrado
    static double valorM2 = 1500;

    //calcula a área da casa
    static double CasaRet(double l_sala, double c_quarto) {
        double area_s; //área da sala
        double area_q; //área do quarto
        double area_t = 0; //área do total

        if(l_sala < 0 || c_quarto < 0)
             System.out.println("Erro!");

        else{
            area_s = l_sala * l_sala; //calcula area da sala
            area_q = c_quarto * (l_sala/2); //calcula area do quarto            
            area_t = area_s + 2 * area_q; //calcula a area total
        }
        return(area_t);
    }
}
```

Sua classe Projeto e o método `Area`:

```
public class Projeto {
 static double Area(double lateral_1, double lateral_2, double pis_raio) {
        return(AreaCasa.CasaRet(lateral_1, lateral_2) + AreaPiscina.calcularArea(pis_raio));
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
      System.out.println(Area(21.43, 33.4, 2.0));
    }
}
```

Funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/Ew197K)**.

Seguem alguns links daqui mesmo do SOPT para leitura:

[Qual a função de um método estático?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54021/28595)

[Qual o uso de uma variável estática ou final em java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17136/28595)

Answer (score 0):

```
static double CasaRet(double l_sala, double c_quarto) {
    double area_s; //área da sala
    double area_q; //área do quarto
    double area_t = 0; //área do total

    if(l_sala < 0 || c_quarto < 0)
         System.out.println("Erro!");

    else{
        area_s = l_sala * l_sala; //calcula area da sala
        area_q = c_quarto * (l_sala/2); //calcula area do quarto            
        area_t = area_s + 2 * area_q; //calcula a area total
    }
    return(area_t);
}
```

Só faltou adicionar o `static` no método.
Caso contrario você deve instanciar um objeto da classe e assim chamar o método.

```
AreaCasa ac = new AreaCasa();
ac.CasaRet(valor1, valor2);
```

Comment: Isso não resolve totalmente o problema da pergunta. A classe `AreaPiscina` também está tendo um método referenciado de forma equivodada, e isso só trata da classe AreaCasa.