# Usuário ver somente Itens da unidade Operacional que está no seu cadastro

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, mvc, spring-security

Tenho um sistema de gerenciamento de veículos. A empresa em que trabalho tem varias unidades de negócio, então o usuário só pode ver os carros da unidade em que ele  trabalha. Isso eu consegui fazer, porem sempre que alguém loga no sistema ele substitui os dados da sessão atual pela sessão que entrou por ultimo.
Criei um UserStatic que fez o usuário ver somente o que é da unidade dele, porem sempre que alguém entra ele substitui os dados. Postei o código do meu loginControle, pois é ai que quando um usuário entra ele seta para o userStatic um novo usuário. Se alguém souber uma nova forma de fazer isso.

```
 public String logar() {
    usuario = usuarioFacade.buscarUsuario(login, senha);
    if (usuario != null) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        roles.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl(usuario.getPermissaoUsuario().toString()));
        UserStatic.setUsuario(usuario);
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        context.setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                login, senha, roles));
```

Comment: Um usuário estático não irá funcionar mesmo.

Comment: Esse trecho que você postou é do seu Bean de usuário certo?

Comment: é do meu bean Login, tbm tenho usuarioControle

Comment: Bom me passaram a informação pra usar Usuário estático, como eu deveria fazer então ?

Comment: respondi sua pergunta, não sei se fui muito claro mas qualquer dúvida é só falar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, creio que o problema esteja em seu `UserStatic`. De uma nesse trecho que retirei de uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17015/qual-o-uso-de-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-est%C3%A1tica-ou-final-em-java) do @utluiz:

> Atributos static: Os atributos static possuem o mesmo valor para todas
>   as instâncias de um objeto (dentro de uma mesma JVM, dentro de um
>   mesmo ClassLoader).

Deu pra entender né? Basicamente todas as instâncias do seu objeto terão o mesmo valor.

Voltando ao problema, no seu `Bean` de login você pode criar uma variável pra representar o usuário logado, da seguinte forma:

```
private Usuario usuarioLogado;
```

Esse seu `Bean` deve estar anotado como `@SessionScoped`. Depos no seu método de logar é só armazenar o retorno do `buscarUsuario()` nesse `usuarioLogado`.

Feito isso você consegue recuperar esse usuário em outros `Beans` usando a anotação `ManagedProperty` que permite injetar um `Bean` no outro, ex:

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{loginBean}")
private LoginBean loginBean;
```

Depois pra recuperar o usuário logado é só fazer:

```
//Pega os atributos do usuário Logado 
loginBean.getUsuarioLogado().getLogin();
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas só nao entendi muito bem como implementar isso..

Comment: Qual parte não entendeu?

Comment: No meu loginControle eu vou colocar private Usuario usuarioLogado; só isso ?

Comment: no meu loginControle ficaria assim ?
 public String logar() {
        usuario = usuarioFacade.buscarUsuario(login, senha);
        usuarioLogado = usuarioFacade.buscarUsuario(login, senha);

Comment: Fiz dessa forma mais ele está salvando direto, se eu entrar como outro usuário ele mantem os dados do usuário que logou primeiro..

Comment: Você definiu seu Bean como SessionScoped?

Comment: Sim 
Named
SessionScoped
public class loginControle implements Serializable {

Comment: E no seu Bean que deseja manipular o usuário vc está pegando o usuarioLogado, o mesmo que foi declarado no LoginBean?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45384/discussion-between-leandro-santos-and-diegoaugusto).

Comment: Resolvido como o @DiegoAugusto informou acima. Obrigado