# Erro "Cannot make static reference to the non-static fiel

Tags: java

Estou a fazer um exercício  com uma classe `Carro` e subclasses `Familiar` `Citadino` e `Jipe`... Só que ao fazer uma classe `Testabuzinar1` que instancia cada uma das subclasses e depois chama o método buzinar (que está na classe `Carro`) e aparece me um erro

> Cannot make astatic reference to the non-static field...

Segue o codigo da classe Testa buzina

```
public class TestaBuzinar1 {
    public Citadino citadino = new Citadino(); //ou Citadino citadino=new citadino()
    public Familiar familiar = new Familiar();
    public Jipe jipe = new Jipe();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        citadino.buzinar();
        familiar.buzinar();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro é claro, você está tentando acessar campos não estáticos dentro do main, que é estático.

Se precisa mesmo que sejam campos de classe adicione `static` para que os campos possam ser acessados diretamente no main:

```
public class TestaBuzinar1 {
    public static Citadino citadino = new Citadino(); //ou Citadino citadino=new citadino()
    public static Familiar familiar = new Familiar();
    public static Jipe jipe = new Jipe();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        citadino.buzinar();
        familiar.buzinar();

    }

}
```

Ou também você pode simplesmente criar uma instancia da classe `TestaBuzinar1`:

```
public class TestaBuzinar1 {
    public Citadino citadino = new Citadino(); //ou Citadino citadino=new citadino()
    public Familiar familiar = new Familiar();
    public Jipe jipe = new Jipe();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TestaBuzinar1 testb = new TestaBuzinar1();    
        testb.citadino.buzinar();
        testb.familiar.buzinar();

    }

}
```

Como foi bem lembrado pelo [@Anderson](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/195974/erro-cannot-make-static-reference-to-the-non-static-fiel/195976#comment403627_195976), há uma solução mais simples, que é tornar os campos locais dentro do `main`:

```
public class TestaBuzinar1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Citadino citadino = new Citadino(); //ou Citadino citadino=new citadino()
        Familiar familiar = new Familiar();
        Jipe jipe = new Jipe();

        citadino.buzinar();
        familiar.buzinar();

    }

}
```

Leitura recomendada:

[Qual o uso de uma variável estática ou final em java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17015/qual-o-uso-de-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-est%C3%A1tica-ou-final-em-java/17136#17136)

Comment: Ou inclui as instâncias das classes no método `main`, fazendo-os locais.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss tinha me esquecido dessa possibilidade

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda