# Por que é obrigatório inicializar uma variável final quando uma instância é construída?

Tags: java

Em uma revisão para certificação, me deparei com o seguinte código:

```
public class Initializer {
    static int si = 10;
    int i;
    final boolean bool; 
}
```

Ele gera erro de compilação na declaração da variável `final boolean bool`, pois esta não foi inicializada.
Perceba que a variável `int i` também não foi inicializada, mas não tem problema algum, pois as variáveis de instância (não final?) são inicializadas implicitamente.

**Mas então, por que há essa diferenciação com `final` e é obrigatório inicializar uma variável final quando uma instância é construída?**

Comment: Acho que [essa resposta do Luiz](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17136/4808) ou [essa do bigown](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17018/4808) já respondem sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

De modo simples o modificador final em variáveis serve para torna-la imutável, então para que ela seja imutável ela deve ter seu valor inicializado no comando em que ela é declarada ou no construtor da classe.

Em java todas as variáveis são inicializadas com seus valores padrões mesmo que seja null, sendo assim se a variável final fosse inicializada com um valor padrão ela seria inútil pelo fato de ser imutável é não poder ter seu valor modificado.