# Chamando elemento de um método em outro método

Tags: java, método

Quando rodo o programa, no método `"exibirVetores(int[] vet, int[] vetInvertida)"`, as *Strings* "invertida" e "normal" estão vazias (`null`).

```
public class metodos02 {

    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int vet[];
    static String normal;
    static String invertida;

    public static void obterNumeros(int[] vet) {
        System.out.println("Informe 5 números: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < vet.length; i++) {
            vet[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public static void inverterOrdemNumeros(int[] vet, int[] vetInvertida) {
        vetInvertida[0] = vet[4];
        vetInvertida[1] = vet[3];
        vetInvertida[2] = vet[2];
        vetInvertida[3] = vet[1];
        vetInvertida[4] = vet[0];
        invertida = (vetInvertida[0] + ", " + vetInvertida[1] + ", " + vetInvertida[2] + ", " + vetInvertida[3]
                + ", " + vetInvertida[4]);
        normal = (vet[0] + ", " + vet[1] + ", " + vet[2] + ", " + vet[3] + ", " + vet[4]);
    }

    public static void exibirVetores(int[] vet, int[] vetInvertida) {
        System.out
                .println("Números informados: "+normal+". Número em ordem inversa: "+ invertida +".");
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual a ordem de execução dos seus métodos? você deve chamar primeiro o `inverterOrdemNumeros()` e depois o `exibirVetores()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código está muito parecido com um estilo procedural de programar, tem algumas coisas que precisam ser adaptadas. Se for sua intenção desconsidere alguns comentários.

```
public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int vet[];
static String normal;
static String invertida;
```

Não faz muito sentido declarar o Scanner como atributo da sua classe, ele pode ser excluído após o uso do método `obterNumeros()` que é o único lugar onde ele aparece. Também não faz muito sentido declarar as variáveis como static a não ser que seja sua intenção criar essas variáveis globais. Sugiro que leia: [Qual o uso de uma variável estática ou final em java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17015/qual-o-uso-de-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-est%C3%A1tica-ou-final-em-java).

Além disso se você recebe tudo por parâmetro em seus métodos não seria necessário os atributos da classe.

```
public static void obterNumeros(int[] vet) {
    System.out.println("Informe 5 números: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < vet.length; i++) {
        vet[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Aqui você usa `vet.length` sem ter declarado vet (me refiro ao atributo da classe) como um array de 5 números. Se deseja algo mais dinâmico sugiro que uso o [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) ou alguma de suas implementações suas implementações.

```
public static void inverterOrdemNumeros(int[] vet, int[] vetInvertida) {
        vetInvertida[0] = vet[4];
        vetInvertida[1] = vet[3];
        vetInvertida[2] = vet[2];
        vetInvertida[3] = vet[1];
        vetInvertida[4] = vet[0];
        invertida = (vetInvertida[0] + ", " + vetInvertida[1] + ", " + vetInvertida[2] + ", " + vetInvertida[3]
                + ", " + vetInvertida[4]);
        normal = (vet[0] + ", " + vet[1] + ", " + vet[2] + ", " + vet[3] + ", " + vet[4]);
    }
```

Aqui você está manipulando variáveis recebidas na assinatura do método, não as que foram declaradas como atributo da sua classe.

O código correto seria o seguite:

```
public class metodos02 {
    // Atributos de classe encapsulados e inicializados
    private int vet[] = new int[5];
    private int vetInvertida[] = new int[5];
    private String normal, invertida;

    public void obterNumeros(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Informe 5 números: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            vet[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public void inverterOrdemNumeros() {
        vetInvertida[0] = vet[4];
        vetInvertida[1] = vet[3];
        vetInvertida[2] = vet[2];
        vetInvertida[3] = vet[1];
        vetInvertida[4] = vet[0];

        this.invertida = Arrays.toString(vetInvertida);
        this.normal = Arrays.toString(vet);
    }

    public void exibirVetores() {
        System.out.println("Números informados: "+normal+".\nNúmeros em ordem inversa: "+ invertida +".");
    }  
}
```

No método main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    metodos02 m = new metodos02();
    m.obterNumeros();
    m.inverterOrdemNumeros();
    m.exibirVetores();
}
```

Output:

```
run:
Informe 5 números: 
1
2
3
4
5
Números informados: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].
Números em ordem inversa: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1].
```

Veja também o porque do encapsulamento [aqui](http://www.devmedia.com.br/encapsulamento-em-java-primeiros-passos/31177).