# Como contar o numero de todas as instâncias de uma classe e as suas respetivas subclasses?

Tags: java, herança, declaração-de-variável

Eu tenho uma classe `A`, onde `A` estende-se em `B` e em `C`. Eu tenho um contador de instâncias em `A`.

```
public Class A {

...

   private int nInstancias = 0;

   ...

   public A(){
      nInstancias+=1;
      ...
   }

   ...

   public int getnInstancias() {
       return nInstancias;
   }

   ...

}
```

No entanto, sempre que faço print do `nInstancias` com o respetivo `getNInstancias`, dá sempre 0.

O que estou a fazer mal e como posso fazer para incrementar o nInstancias sempre instâncio `A` ou qualquer subclasse de `A`?

É por também ter de alterar o nInstancias no construtor das subclasses?

Comment: `private int nInstancias = +;` isso nao é uma declaracao válida do java,

Comment: desculpe o erro. não tinha reparado @Articuno

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente alterar a variável para estática, assim, o valor dela independerá da instancia a qual ela está vinculada:

```
private static int nInstancias = 0;
```

e dentro do construtor de `A`:

```
public A(){
   nInstancias++;
   ...
}
```

Obs.:  Tendo em vista que as outras classes estendem de A, o contador irá incrementar cada vez que uma instancia de B e C forem criadas tambem. Veja o teste:

```
public  class ClasseA {

    private static int instances = 0;

    public ClasseA() {
        instances++;
    }

    public static int getNumberInstances(){
        return instances;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Instanciando ClasseA...");
        ClasseA a = new ClasseA();
        System.out.println("No. de instancias: " + ClasseA.getNumberInstances());

        System.out.println("Instanciando ClasseB...");
        ClasseB b = new ClasseB();
        System.out.println("No. de instancias: " + ClasseA.getNumberInstances());

        System.out.println("Instanciando ClasseC...");
        ClasseC c = new ClasseC();
        System.out.println("No. de instancias: " + ClasseA.getNumberInstances());
    }
}


class ClasseB extends ClasseA {

}

class ClasseC extends ClasseA{

}
```

Resultado:

> ```
> Instanciando ClasseA...
> No. de instancias: 1
> Instanciando ClasseB...
> No. de instancias: 2
> Instanciando ClasseC...
> No. de instancias: 3
> ```

Funcionando: https://ideone.com/gPyfaD

Referência:

- [How to Count Number of Instances of a Class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28947625/5524514)
- [Qual o uso de uma variável estática ou final em java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17015/28595)

Comment: muito obrigado! estava a tentar resolver isto ha tanto tempo