# Setar variável final dentro de um lambda dá erro, mas se não for final, dá outro erro

Tags: java

```
public UserEntity findByEmail(String email) {
    final UserEntity result;
    getDatabase().forEach((Long id, UserEntity user) -> {
        boolean isName = user.getEmail().equals(email);
        if (isName) {
            result = user;
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Queria entender por que esse método não compila. Quando eu retiro o `final` do `result`, ele diz:

> Variable used in lambda expression should be final or effectively
>   final

Quando eu coloco `final`:

> Cannot assign a value to final variable 'result'

Esse é o meu `getDatabase()`. Ele é só um `Map`.

```
protected Map<Long, E> getDatabase() {
    return database;
}
```

Comment: Você precisa colocar o final no isName, que é a variável dentro do forEach, e não no result.

Comment: Uma variável declarada fora do lambda (no caso, fora do `forEach`) só pode ser usada dentro dele [se for `final`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50456920). Mas uma variável `final` só pode ter um valor setado [apenas uma vez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17136/112052), mas dentro desse loop existe a possibilidade dela ser setada mais de uma vez. Então a solução é refatorar seu código e não depender de setar a variável dentro do loop - usando um `for` normal, ou, se `getDatabase()` for um *stream*, usar `filter` e `findFirst`, por exemplo.

Comment: getDatabase() não tem o método stream...

Comment: Então por favor clique em **[edit]** e informe o que é `getDatabase()`. Tente ver se ele tem outro método para percorrê-lo, por exemplo

Comment: Editado. O database é um map.

Comment: Pra percorrer um `Map`, use um `for` normal, assim não tem esse problema do `final`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46898

Answer (score 3):

O uso da palavra reservada `final` no java restringe que aquela variável receberá um valor na definição e nunca mais poderá ser alterado. Como você não deu nenhum valor inicial, a variável será nula para sempre.

O uso do forEach para filtrar o dado que deseja também não é recomendável para este tipo de operação. Se você precisa do primeiro e-mail correto encontrado, você pode usar o filter.

```
User retorno = getDatabase()
                          .entrySet()
                          .stream()
                          .filter(user -> user.getEmail.equals(email))
                          .findFirst()
                          .get();
```

Além dessas considerações, se você estiver pegando esta lista de usuários de um banco de dados, já poderia buscar apenas o registro correto direto na consulta.

Comment: getDatabase() não tem o método stream...

Answer (score 3):

A variável `result` foi declarada fora do lambda (no caso, fora do `forEach`), então ela só pode ser usada dentro dele [se for `final`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50456920).

Mas uma variável `final` só pode ter um valor atribuído [apenas uma vez](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17136/112052). Só que dentro do seu *loop* existe a possibilidade dela ser setada mais de uma vez (se tiver mais de um usuário com o email indicado, por exemplo, entrará duas vezes no `if`, setando a variável `final` duas vezes).

Ou seja, se usar `final`, dá um erro, mas se não usar, dá outro.
Então a solução é refatorar seu código e não depender de setar a variável dentro do `forEach`. Como `getDatabase()` retorna um `Map`, basta percorrê-lo com um `for` normal:

```
public UserEntity findByEmail(String email) {
    for (Map.Entry<Long, UserEntity> entry : getDatabase().entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().getEmail().equals(email)) {
            // encontrou o email, já retorna o usuário
            return entry.getValue();
        }
    }

    // não encontrou nada, retorna null (ou pode lançar uma exceção)
    return null;
}
```

O método [`entrySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet--) retorna um conjunto de [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html), a partir do qual é possível acessar a chave e o respectivo valor do `Map`. Usando `getValue()`, eu obtenho o `UserEntity`, e aí é só fazer as verificações que você precisa.

---

Mas como você só está verificando os valores e ignorando as chaves, pode usar somente o método [`values()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--), que já retorna diretamente todos os `UserEntity`:

```
public UserEntity findByEmail(String email) {
    for (UserEntity user : getDatabase().values()) {
        if (user.getEmail().equals(email)) {
            // encontrou o email, já retorna o usuário
            return user;
        }
    }

    // não encontrou nada, retorna null (ou pode lançar uma exceção)
    return null;
}
```