# Calculadora que faz operações sobre o resultado de uma operação anterior

Tags: java

Na minha aula de Java estamos aprendendo orientação a objetos, e meu prof. pediu uma calculadora. Nesta calculadora, o usuário vai digitar a expressão inteira, por exemplo `10+10`, e o algoritmo precisa reconhecer qual expressão está sendo executada e mostrar o resultado na tela, ou seja, `10+10 = 20`. Até aí eu fiz e entreguei.

Porém, ele pediu para complementarmos essa calculadora, de forma que, após a exibição do resultado `10+10 = 20`, o usuário digite, por exemplo, `+10`, e o resultado então será `30`. Se o usuário informar outras operações elas precisam "agregar" no resultado também.

```
public class Calc {

public int som(int num1, int num2) {

    return num1 + num2;

}
public int sub(int num1, int num2){

    return num1 - num2;

}
public int div(int num1,int num2){

    return num1 / num2;

}
public int mult(int num1, int num2){

    return num1 - num2;

}



public static void main (String args[]){

    //criando um objeto c a apartir do metodo calc
    Calc c = new Calc();

    //declarando as varíaveis
    int opcao = 5;
    int num1;
    int num2;

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  


    System.out.println("-Escolha uma opção-");
    System.out.println("1. Soma");  
    System.out.println("2. Subtracao");  
    System.out.println("3. Multiplicacao");  
    System.out.println("4. Divisao");  
    System.out.println("0. Sair");  
    System.out.println("Operação: ");  

    opcao = input.nextInt();

    while (opcao != 0) {


        if (opcao == 1) {



            Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);  

            System.out.println("Qual o primeiro numero: ");
             num1 = input1.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Qual o segundo numero: ");
             num2 = input1.nextInt();

             /***/
                int operacao = c.som(num1, num2);

                System.out.println(operacao);
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Seja bem vindo! Você sabe usar variáveis static? [Qual o uso de uma variável estática ou final em java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17015/qual-o-uso-de-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-est%C3%A1tica-ou-final-em-java) Acredito que ai mora o segredo, mais a noite poderei olhar seu código com calma, por agora a dica que dou é tentar colocar static em alguma das 3 variaveis: private `Double valorCalculado;
private Double valorUm;
private Double valorDois;`

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer que a calculadora aceite expressões como "+10" que somem 10 ao resultado atual, então a `Calculadora` deve guardar o resultado atual internamente, e as operações executadas devem operar sobre este resultado atual. Então ficaria algo do tipo:

```
public class Calculadora {

    private int resultadoAtual = 0;

    public int calcular(String expressao) {
        // separar a expressão por espaços
        String[] tokens = expressao.split(" ");
        if (tokens.length == 3) { // 3 partes (um número, operação, outro número)
            int op1 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
            int op2 = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
            this.executaOperacao(op1, op2, tokens[1].charAt(0));
        } else if (tokens.length == 1) { // 1 parte (casos como "+10")
            int op = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0].substring(1));
            this.executaOperacao(this.resultadoAtual, op, tokens[0].charAt(0));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Expressão não reconhecida");
        }

        return resultadoAtual;
    }

    private void executaOperacao(int op1, int op2, char op) {
        switch (op) {
            case '+':
                this.resultadoAtual = op1 + op2;
                break;
            case '-':
                this.resultadoAtual = op1 - op2;
                break;
            case '*':
                this.resultadoAtual = op1 * op2;
                break;
            case '/':
                this.resultadoAtual = op1 / op2;
                break;
        }
    }

    public void limpar() {
        this.resultadoAtual = 0;
    }
}
```

Eu criei o campo `resultadoAtual` que servirá para guardar o resultado atual da calculadora. O método `calcular` recebe uma `String` contendo a expressão, e como é um exercício, estou assumindo algumas premissas:

- expressões com dois operandos (como `"10 + 20"` ou `"5 * 12"`) sempre possuem espaços separando as suas partes (ou seja, não poderia ser `"10+20"` - embora seja possível, veja uma opção no final)
- expressões que "agregam" ao resultado atual (como `"+10"` ou `"*30"`) não possuem espaços entre a operação e o número
- o código assume que [`Integer.parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) sempre recebe um número inteiro válido (não estou [tratando as exceções](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21933/112052))
- as operações são sempre feitas em números inteiros, então o resultado de 11 / 4 será 2 (o Java arredonda quando os operandos são `int`) - de qualquer forma, se tiver `"3.2"` na expressão, vai dar erro, conforme o item anterior

Resumindo, o código não faz validações mais complexas na expressão digitada (em um sistema real ele faria isso, mas é bem complicado aceitar qualquer expressão numérica válida, e acredito que já fuja ao escopo do exercício).

Enfim, o método `calcular` assume todas as premissas acima e faz o cálculo, armazenando o resultado em `resultadoAtual` (e este fica guardado, para poder ser "agregado" em futuras operações). Em linhas gerais, a calculadora funciona assim:

- se for digitado `10 + 20`, o `resultadoAtual` será 30
- em seguida, se for digitado `+5`, o `resultadoAtual` passa a ser 35
- se for digitado outra expressão, como `1 + 2`, o `resultadoAtual` passa a ser 3 (esta é uma expressão completa, que não "agrega" ao resultado atual, então entendo que o valor anterior deve ser sobrescrito)
- e assim por diante...

Também incluí uma opção para "limpar" o resultado atual e setá-lo para zero (mais ou menos como a tecla <kbd>C</kbd> das calculadoras).

E eu fiz dessa forma (lendo a expressão inteira), porque você disse que o usuário vai "digitar a expressão inteira" (ou seja, "10 + 20", em vez de digitar cada parte separadamente como você fez). Uma forma de usar a calculadora seria:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculadora calc = new Calculadora();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String expressao = "";
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("-Escolha uma opção-");
        System.out.println("Digitar uma expressão (ex: '10 + 20', ou simplesmente '+20')");
        System.out.println("'c' - Limpar o resultado atual");
        System.out.println("'q' - Sair");
        System.out.println("> ");
        expressao = input.nextLine();
        if ("q".equals(expressao)) {
            break; // sai do while
        }

        if ("c".equals(expressao)) {
            calc.limpar();
        } else {
            System.out.println(calc.calcular(expressao));
        }
    }
}
```

O `while(true)` fica rodando indefinidamente, permitindo que o usuário digite quantas expressões quiser. Se digitar `q`, ele sai do `while`.

---

Apenas como curiosidade (pois acho que já foge do escopo do exercício), para aceitar a expressão sem espaços (`"10+20"`), uma opção seria usar [expressões regulares (no pacote `java.util.regex`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html):

```
public int calcular(String expressao) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)?\\s*([-+*/])\\s*(\\d+)").matcher(expressao);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        int op1;
        if (matcher.group(1) == null) { // não tem o primeiro operando (é uma expressão do tipo "+10")
            op1 = this.resultadoAtual;
        } else {
            op1 = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
        }
        char op = matcher.group(2).charAt(0);
        int op2 = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
        this.executaOperacao(op1, op2, op);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Expressão inválida");
    }
}
```

[Existem outras opções também](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3422673), mas como é um exercício, provavelmente querem que você implemente tudo "na mão" mesmo...