# Lista C# retornando nula

Tags: c#, .net

Possuo um problema, em que a lista "ActiveDownloads" retorna como null em um método de consulta, mesmo quando ela é alimentada pelo método "DownloadAsync", não consegui visualizar onde está o erro.

Quando debugo colocando um ponto de depuração dentro do while em que ela é alimentada, consigo identificar que todas as instancias da lista "ActiveDownloads" estão alimentadas.

Inicialização da Lista:

```
private List<DownloadStatus> ActiveDownloads;
public DownloaderTorrent()
{
    ActiveDownloads = new List<DownloadStatus>();
}
```

Método em que ela é alimentada, a partir do while:

```
private async Task DownloadAsync(MagnetLink magnet)
{

    const int httpListeningPort = 55125;
    var engineSettingBuilder = new EngineSettingsBuilder
    {          
        AllowPortForwarding = true,
        AutoSaveLoadDhtCache = true,
        AutoSaveLoadFastResume = true,             
        AutoSaveLoadMagnetLinkMetadata = true,
        HttpStreamingPrefix = new Uri($"http://127.0.0.1:{httpListeningPort}")
    };
    var torrentSettingsBuilder = new TorrentSettingsBuilder
    {
        MaximumConnections = 60,
    };

    var dpath = "Downloads";

    if (!Directory.Exists(dpath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dpath);
    var downloadsPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, dpath);

    var engine = new ClientEngine(engineSettingBuilder.ToSettings());   
             
    await engine.AddAsync(magnet, downloadsPath, torrentSettingsBuilder.ToSettings());

    foreach (TorrentManager manager in engine.Torrents)
    {
        await manager.StartAsync();

        var peers = await manager.GetPeersAsync();

    }
    
    while (engine.IsRunning)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"DownloadSpeed: {engine.TotalDownloadSpeed}");
        foreach(TorrentManager manager in engine.Torrents)
        {
            var peers = await manager.GetPeersAsync();
            Console.WriteLine($"Peers: {peers.Count()}");
            DownloadStatus downloadActive = ActiveDownloads.FirstOrDefault(x => x.InfoHash == manager.InfoHash);
            if (downloadActive != null)
            {
                downloadActive.Name = manager.MagnetLink.Name;
                downloadActive.Peers = peers.Count();
                downloadActive.DownloadSpeed = engine.TotalDownloadSpeed;
                downloadActive.State = manager.State.ToString();
                downloadActive.Progress = manager.Progress;
            }
            else
            {
                ActiveDownloads.Add(new DownloadStatus()
                {
                    InfoHash = manager.InfoHash
                });
            }  

        }
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        Console.Clear();               
    }           
}
```

Método para consulta da lista:

```
public List<DownloadStatus> getDownloads()
{
    
    var activeDownload = this.ActiveDownloads;
    return activeDownload;
}
```

Classe "DownloadsStatus"

```
public class DownloadStatus
{
    [Key]
    public InfoHash InfoHash { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public double? Progress { get; set; }
    public int? Peers { get; set; }
    public long? DownloadSpeed { get; set; }  
    public string? State { get; set; }

}
```

Tentei uma pequena alteração utilizando o index da lista, mas sem sucesso:

```
DownloadStatus downloadActive = ActiveDownloads.FirstOrDefault(x => x.InfoHash == manager.InfoHash);

if (downloadActive != null)
{
    var indexDownload = ActiveDownloads.FindIndex(x => x.InfoHash == manager.InfoHash);
    ActiveDownloads[indexDownload].Name = manager.MagnetLink.Name;
    ActiveDownloads[indexDownload].Peers = peers.Count();
    ActiveDownloads[indexDownload].DownloadSpeed = engine.TotalDownloadSpeed;
    ActiveDownloads[indexDownload].State = manager.State.ToString();
    ActiveDownloads[indexDownload].Progress = manager.Progress;
}
else
{
    ActiveDownloads.Add(new DownloadStatus()
    {
        InfoHash = manager.InfoHash
    });
}
```

Comment: não dá pra saber bem sem ver o código todo mas, a variável não é iniciada toda vez que chama a classe? daí quando o método `getDownloads()` é chamado a lista está vazia? pra variável permanecer com valor ela precisa ser *static* ou implementar um *singleton* por exemplo, pelo que vejo ai, ela é preenchida quando chama o método `DownloadAsync`, mas no momento que o outro método é chamado, pode ser outra instancia ou algo assim

Comment: O problema era static, como não sei exatamente pra que serve vou pesquisar, na hora que declarei como static funcionou, muito obrigado.

Comment: sugiro ler isso, a resposta é para java mas o conceito é o mesmo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17015/qual-o-uso-de-uma-vari%c3%a1vel-est%c3%a1tica-ou-final-em-java

Answer (score -2):

Como visto nos comentários, consegui resolver declarando a variavel ActiveDownloads como static e inicializei ela antes do while.

```
private static List<DownloadStatus> ActiveDownloads;
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).