# Quando devo escolher entre utilizar ou não um ponteiro ao criar um objeto?

Tags: c++, ponteiro, objetos

Em C++, estou acostumado a ver objetos sendo criados através do operador `new`, que é quando o objeto é referenciado por um ponteiro, assim:

```
MinhaClasse *mc1 = new MinhaClasse();
```

Essa forma me parece a mais natural de criar um objeto pois me lembra Java, onde tudo são ponteiros com exceção dos tipos primitivos (`int`, `char`, `byte`, etc..).

Entretanto, em C++ existe a possibilidade de instanciar um objeto sem a criação de um ponteiro, assim:

```
MinhaClasse mc2;
```

Existem diferenças na criação dos objetos usando essas duas maneiras? Se sim, quais seriam elas? Quando cada uma deve ser escolhida sobre a outra?

Comment: Acho que para objetos grandes que serão passados para outros objetos utiliza-se com ponteiro. Já a criação `MinhaClasse mc2;` exige a passagem por cópia.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A diferença é justamente se vai usar o objeto como valor ou como referência. Isto é importante porque determina o local onde dados do objeto serão alocados.

A segunda forma costuma colocar na *stack*. Embora poderia colocar no *heap* também se o objeto estiver sendo alocado em um tipo que está no *heap* (se a declaração for colocada diretamente em um *container*).

A forma com o operador `new` alocará memória no *heap* e armazenará o objeto lá (o `new` é o alocador, o `MinhaClasse()` é o inicializador). O valor usado para esta variável será um ponteiro ([indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101)), por isto ele é considerado um valor por referência. Este ponteiro que é o valor a ser usado neste dado geralmente é colocado na *stack* - caso do exemplo - mas também pode ser colocado como membro de outro objeto no *heap*. Note que o fato do ponteiro e o conteúdo do objeto estarem no *heap* não significa que eles estão juntos, pelo contrário. São coisas independentes que tem uma relação porque uma referencia a outra.

C++ deixa o consumidor do tipo decidir onde ele quer alocar. Isto é diferente do Java por exemplo, em que todos os objetos são alocados no *heap* através de ponteiros - exceto os tipos primitivos, conforme salientado na pergunta. A filosofia do C++ não é facilitar o uso e sim facilitar o melhor uso dos recursos computacionais. O consumidor tem mais informações do que é melhor naquele momento.

#### [Tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101)

O tempo de vida costuma determinar mais como a alocação é feita. Mesmo que você tenha um objeto relativamente grande para ser alocado e o programador sabe que ele só viverá dentro daquele escopo ou ele entende bem e o escopo e ele pode ser facilmente determinado, que não há riscos de chamadas recursivas ou outras funções que alocam outros objetos grandes, é possível alocar na *stack* sem ponteiro. Não é prática comum, é difícil fazer certo e só compensa em casos de extrema otimização.

É possível criar ponteiros para a *stack* também, sem o uso do `new`. Isto também é incomum. É mais comum usar uma referência para isso, que é um ponteiro por baixo dos panos, mas você não precisa saber disto e o controle é melhor, ainda que pode dar alguns problemas na versão atual de C++ se o tempo de vida for menor que o esperado (há previsão para versões futuras não deixar isto acontecer na mesma linha que Rust faz e não deixa usar tempo de vida errado).

#### Tamanho do objeto

Em casos em que o objeto é grande a cópia custará caro, então é melhor armazenar em um local que o tempo de vida pode ser indeterminado e acessar esta informação através de uma indireção (um ponteiro). Isto costuma ser menos eficiente, por isso o uso de referência é mais adotado.

Em geral quando o objeto tem tamanho determinado e é pequeno não costuma fazer sentido usar o ponteiro direto (referência sim). Mesmo que o dado tenha um tempo de vida além da função onde ele está sendo usado ([ver como funciona a *stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)) ou precise ser usado fora de um objeto onde ele está declarado, a cópia do dado que pode ser necessária nestes casos pode custar muito barata.

Evidentemente que alguns objetos **podem** ser grandes, então costuma-se consideram o pior caso. Aí é uma situação onde o consumidor tem mais informação. Um tipo pode ter sido criado considerando que o objeto pode ser grande mas em um caso específico de uso ele tem um tamanho determinado e é pequeno. Em Java isso não seria considerado. Em C++ um bom programador opta por usar a alocação *inline*, possivelmente na *stack*.

Mas objetos pequenos podem ser usados por referência quando se sabe que eles têm um tempo de vida determinado ainda que não tão óbvio.

A indeterminação do tamanho do objeto pode ser outro bom motivo para preferir o uso de ponteiro. Mesmo que você saiba que o objeto será pequeno mas não pode determinar seu tamanho exato, como linearizar isto dentro de outro objeto? Criando um ponteiro que tem tamanho fixo referenciando o objeto de fato que tem tamanho variável.

## O intercâmbio não é tão livre assim

Há casos em que o tipo foi criado pensando em uma forma de alocação e usar da outra forma provavelmente trará problemas.

É comum usar algum padrão além da documentação para informar qual é a forma preferida de alocação. Pode-se usar `struct` para casos em que deve alocar o valor direto e `class` quando a preferência é usar uma indireção. Algumas linguagens como C# e D, e de uma certa forma Java, se considerar que os tipos primitivos agem como estruturas (e que Java futuro provavelmente terá como o programador criar suas próprias), determinam a forma de alocação dependendo de como o tipo foi declarado. Para C++ `struct` e `class` são quase sinônimos (a única diferença é a visibilidade *default* dos seus membros) e não determina a alocação. No máximo recomenda-se os desenvolvedores adotarem esta convenção.

Em geral [tipos mutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) se dão melhor quando alocados através de ponteiros ou referências, caso contrário pode ocorrer um fenômeno chamado [*slicing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/286437/101).

Um ponteiro é uma indireção, o que dá alguma flexibilidade.

## Gerenciamento de ponteiros

Lembrando que na maioria dos casos, em C++, deve-se usar os [*smart pointers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) e não ponteiros crus. Assim ganha-se o gerenciamento automático de memória. Se não fizer e não existir algum mecanismo interno na própria classe ou no sistema de alocação (`new` pode ser sobrecarregado e pode até mesmo alocar em um *garbage collector*, embora incomum e pouco prático hoje em C++) o programador tem que garantir que o `delete` correspondente seja executado.

Alguns casos o tipo indica uma semântica e controla o uso de ponteiros por conta própria. `String` é exemplo de classe que internaliza o ponteiro. É um caso que, em geral, não tem porque alocar um ponteiro porque o dado que o programa tem acesso direto é pequeno, a parte grande e variável do texto será melhor alocado pela classe, possivelmente usando um ponteiro (ela pode otimizar casos pequenos e não fazer isto, depende de implementação).

## Conclusão

A escolha deve ser sempre alocar na *stack* - que é relativamente pequeno e basicamente fixo - até que exista um motivo para escolher o *heap*, e o motivo principal é o dado precisar sobreviver ao fim de uma função e ser potencialmente grande demais para ser copiado. Um motivo secundário é ser potencialmente grande demais para caber na *stack* ou tornar um objeto de tamanho indeterminado ou grande demais.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: E isso, crianças, é o que acontece quando você salva para responder a questão depois do almoço e tem um bigown a solta por ai. Muito bom, haha.

Comment: Complementando um pouco, o processo de alocação com o new constuma ser oneroso e consome alguns ciclos de clock, enquanto a alocação no stack é praticamente free, normalmente é apenas a atualização de um registrador. Isso é importante, principalmente para o povo que vem do java, que usa o new em tudo que é parte e depois reclama que o programa em c++ é lento.

Answer (score 10):

Utilizando ponteiros, você cria referências,

**Exemplo:**

```
#include <iostream>

//Classe de exemplo
class Objeto{

public:
//Inicializa o valor como 0 por padrão na criação de objetos da classe
    Objeto(){

        this -> valor = 0;
    }

    int valor;      
};

int main()
{
     //Referência
    Objeto *a = new Objeto();   

    Objeto *b = a;  //cria o objeto b que aponta para a

    a -> valor = 5; //muda o valor de a. Também muda o de b, pois b aponta para a.

    std::cout << "a: " << a -> valor << "\n"
              << "b: " << b -> valor << std::endl;

    //Valor
    Objeto c;
    Objeto d = c; //Cria o objeto d, que será cópia de c

    c.valor = 8; // Não muda o valor de d que será mantido como inicializado (0)

    std::cout << "c: " << c.valor << "\n"
              << "d: " << d.valor << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Saída:**

```
a: 5
b: 5
c: 8
d: 0
```

`a` e `b` apontam para o mesmo objeto, ou seja, na verdade somente um objeto foi criado, mas duas variáveis o acessam. Ja `d` é apenas a cópia de `c`. Os dois vão seguir caminho próprio após a criação. Escolha a primeira opção quando quiser modificar dados em um objeto por meio de "outro". Para ter mais segurança de dados e evitar que um objeto modifique o dados de outro utilize cópias.