# Qt5 criando uma QAction que chama uma janela de informações

Tags: qt

Estou desenvolvendo uma solução no qt5.4.2, na minha barra de menus, ao clicar uma opção, uma nova janela deve abrir com aquelas informações.

Eu tinha pensando em fazer uma `QDialog`, mas dependendo ia ficar complicado editar algumas coisas e colocar imagens, por exemplo. Então criei *ui*'s que serão chamadas por essas ações disparada pelo sinal `triggered`.

Mas eu não consigo fazer com que a janela chamada abra quando o sinal é disparado.

Eu importei a biblioteca `.h` da janela que quero chamar, no caso a `aboutMain`. Criei um objeto dela (uma nova janela) e agora quero mostrar.

É desta maneira?

**brprint.h -> .h principal**

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "loading.h"

namespace Ui {
class BrPrint3D;
}

class BrPrint3D : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit BrPrint3D(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~BrPrint3D();
    void init();

private slots:    
    void on_actionSobre_BrPrint3D_triggered();

private:
    Ui::BrPrint3D *ui;

};
```

**brprint3d.cpp**

```
#include "brprint3d.h"
#include "ui_Pandora.h"
#include "aboutbrprint.h"
#include <stdio.h>

//Sobre->Sobre o BrPrint3D
void BrPrint3D::on_actionSobre_BrPrint3D_triggered()
{
    //Chamar Janela Sobre o BrPrint
    aboutBrPrint window;
    window.show();


}
```

**aboutBrPrint.h**

```
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class aboutBrPrint;
}

class aboutBrPrint : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit aboutBrPrint(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~aboutBrPrint();

private:
    Ui::aboutBrPrint *ui;
};
```

Main

```
#include "brprint3d.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "loading.h"
#include <QTranslator>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    BrPrint3D w;
    w.show();
    w.init();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Então, e uma ação da barra de menu, então quando eu crio um item lá ele já cria uma action direto, eu só defino depois qual é o sinal. No caso eu escolhi o triggered, que é a ação mais parecida com click que tem lá. Quando eu dou build, outras funcionalidades funcionam, mas qndo eu clico nesse item, nada acontece. Eu cliquei com o botão direito no item, Go To Slot, action Triggered. Está declarado como Slot privado.

Comment: Editado guilherme.

Comment: Essa forma de declaração é deprecada no qt 5.2. é daquela forma direta que fiz mesmo...

Comment: Desculpe Lays, uso o qt desde a versão 5.0 e não sabia disto, poderia me fornecer a fonte de tal informação? Até aonde sei estes "estilos" de escrita/execução são do C++ e não do QT e talvez ele mude conforme a versão do C++ e não do QT, por exemplo do c++89 para o C++11 houve mudanças. Ficaria grato se pude-se me fornecer o link de tal informação. Grato.

Comment: Bem eu me baseei, na própria main gerada pelo Qt. Pois lá mostra como ele chama a janela Main por exemplo. Vou colocar o exemplo de código lá em cima.

Comment: Eu não consigo fazer o signal na mão, pq a pandora.ui não reconhece o objeto aboutBrPrint. E esse signal é gerado automaticamente quando crio o item na barra de menu. Não consigo fazer outro que o sobreescreva, senão já teria resolvido o caso, pois fiz isso com outra questão de janelas. Eu não consigo criar um connect separado. =/ Pq nesse caso a ação eh disparada por uma opção da barra de menu, e não em um push buttom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acredito que é necessário usar o `new`, pois a primeira janela gerada já está vinculada ao `QApplication`, as novas janelas devem receber o `this` para ficarem umas vinculadas as outras, então o correto seria isto:

```
void BrPrint3D::on_actionSobre_BrPrint3D_triggered()
{
    aboutBrPrint *window = new aboutBrPrint(this);
    window->show();
}
```

No caso `exec` também pode funcionar (note que provavelmente isto irá bloquear a janela "pai" enquanto estiver aberto), pois o `exec` consegue fazer referencia a janela "pai", para desbloquear a janela pai basta fechar o aboutBrPrint:

```
void BrPrint3D::on_actionSobre_BrPrint3D_triggered()
{
    aboutBrPrint window;
    window.exec();
}
```

No main.cpp não usamos o construtor `new` pois a primeira janela já está vinculada ao `QOBJECT` (acredito eu) que fica ligado a aplicação, então o `new` não está em "desuso", aproveite e leia este link [Quando devo escolher entre utilizar ou não um ponteiro ao criar um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50165/3635)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    BrPrint3D w;
    w.show();
    w.init();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Essa sua primeira solução funcionou, mas em vez de abrir na janela separada, ela abriu o texto dentro da janela pai.

Comment: @LaysRodrigues "dentro" como se tive-se usado "addChild" ou apenas sobreposta a "janela pai"? Mande um exemplo do problema em zip se puder.

Comment: Já consegui resolver com a seguinte solução:
void BrPrint3D::on_actionSobre_o_BrPrint3D_triggered()
{   QWidget *x;
    aboutBrPrint *w= new aboutBrPrint(x);
    w->show();
}

Comment: Haha depois fuço mais, pois estou naquela situação: Se funcionar-> próximo item. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. ;)