# O que significa criar um objeto com aquele asterisco?

Tags: c++, qt, ponteiro

Apesar de conhecer programação a um tempo razoável, aprendendo C++ com QT, me deparei com algo que eu não havia visto em outras linguagens. Notei que alguns objetos (não todos) precisam ser criados com um asterisco precedendo o nome. Por exemplo:

```
QMessageBox *box = new QMessageBox();
```

Ou seja, a classe `QMessageBox` pra ser instanciada, precisa daquele asterisco ali ao nome do objeto. Minha pergunta é: qual o significado daquele asterisco?
Tem algo a ver com arrays, ou ponteiros?

Agradeço a quem me der alguma pista pra eu poder pelo menos começar a pesquisar no Google pelo assunto. Eu devo pesquisar pelo quê?

Comment: Relacionada: [Quando devo escolher entre utilizar ou não um ponteiro ao criar um objeto?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50165/3117)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando há o asterisco junto ao nome da variável significa que é um ponteiro. Mas, é possível também declarar ponteiros mantendo o asterisco junto ao tipo da variável. As duas formas abaixo tem o mesmo significado.

```
int *pnumber1;
int* pnumber2;
```

---

Pois bem, mas **o que é um ponteiro?**

Um ponteiro é uma variável que armazena um endereço em memória que contém dados de um determinado tipo.Então, as duas linhas acima representam "um ponteiro para inteiro".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Porque usar ponteiros?

- podemos utilizar a “notação” de ponteiros para manipular arrays, o que é frequentemente “mais rápido”;
- ponteiros facilitam o acesso a grandes porções de dados;
- ponteiros permitem a alocação dinâmica de memória;

---

Um exemplo usando ponteiros

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int number = 10;
    int* pnumber;

    pnumber = &number;

    std::cout << "Value-Of number variable  : " << number << std::endl
              << "Address-Of number variable: " << pnumber << std::endl
              << "Value-Of pnumber variable : " << pnumber << std::endl
              << "Value-Of pnumber pointer  : " << *pnumber << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

As saídas serão:

Value-Of number variable  : 10
Address-Of number variable: 003BFCCC
Value-Of pnumber variable : 003BFCCC
Value-Of pnumber pointer  : 10

Fonte:
[Blog do Elemar Jr.](http://elemarjr.net/2011/09/22/c-101-parte-4-ponteiros-conceitos-bsicos/)

Answer (score 2):

Esta instrução declara a varíavel `box` como ponteiro.

Ponteiros, ao contrário de variáveis comuns, não contém dados, mas um endereço para algum dado.

Esse é um assunto bem complexo e confunde bastante no começo. Dê uma olhada aqui: [Ponteiros em C](http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/pont.html).

Comment: Interessante!!! Vou tentar dar uma aprofundada no assunto pra entender melhor. Obrigado a todos os que responderam!