# Ponteiro de char ou array de char?

Tags: c, array, ponteiro

Há um programa que eu peguei numa empresa, em que são utilizados ponteiros de `char`, tipo `char*`, e depois alocado uma memória para ele com o `malloc()`, feito as operações e no final desalocado essa memória. Recebe normalmente todos os caracteres, até o tamanho máximo.

Um *array* de `char` pode ter desempenho melhor ou mais segurança? Tipo controlar o tamanho máximo que pode receber, o estouro de memória, etc.

```
{
char* x;
x = (char*)malloc(16*sizeof(char));
x = (char*)NULL //aparentemente é pra alocar uma memória limpa
func(INPUT y, OUTPUT x);

free(x);         //aqui ele
x = (char*)NULL; //limpa a variável
}//essa é o tipo de função que eles usaram

{
char x[16];
memset(x,'\0',strlen(x)); //também é pra ter uma memória limpa
func(INPUT y, OUTPUT x);

memset(x,'\0',strlen(x)); //limpa a variável
}//essa seria a mesma função só que com um array de char
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O *array* de `char` pode dar melhor performance, afinal evitará uma alocação dinâmica de memória, que é algo relativamente caro. Não importa se o tamanho será determinado em tempo de compilação ou de execução.

No exemplo da pergunta seria melhor usar essa forma, mas nem sempre isso é possível.

## Segurança e confiabilidade

Segurança é sempre obtida sabendo o que está fazendo, entendendo como o computador funciona, como a linguagem trabalha, os detalhes da API que está usando, etc. O uso de *array* no lugar da alocação dinâmica nem ajuda nem prejudica a segurança diretamente. Não há nada em um recurso ou outro que impeça o estouro de uso de memória. Em C é um problema do programador tratar isto.

O uso de memória dinâmica costuma ser menos confiável. Não por ela em si, mas porque os programadores costumam errar mais no seu uso, e o que não é tão confiável pode ser menos seguro, mas é algo indireto.

## Quando usar

Normalmente a alocação do *array* é feita na [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) - por isso é rápido - o que não permite ter um *array* **muito** grande (muito menos se o tamanho não puder ser determinado na compilação ou pelo menos garantido que ele não será muito grande), nem que ele sobreviva ao final de uma função (ou escopo), então há casos que a alocação no *heap* - com `malloc()` - é a única solução viável.

Mesmo nos casos da alocação ser em uma estrutura, pode fazer ela ficar grande demais, e nem sempre é o que se deseja, principalmente porque praticamente obrigaria a sua alocação no *heap* (alocação dinâmica), o que nem sempre é desejável.

No fundo a diferença entre o *array* e a alocação dinâmica, está mesmo só na alocação, uma não oferece mais recursos que outra. Depois de alocado, dá na mesma, a linguagem não diferencia uma da outra.

O padrão é sempre usar a forma mais simples, que é a alocação do *array*, a não ser que exista um motivo para alocar dinamicamente. Isto não é otimização prematura, pelo contrário, a alocação dinâmica deve ser evitada sempre que possível, sempre que ela não trouxer problemas específicos. Ela é mais simples, mais confiável e mais rápida, só tem vantagens quando o que precisa não será limitado pela sua característica.

## Conclusão

Olhando por cima, no geral este código é mal escrito e não atende padrões modernos. Aparentemente pode ter sido escrito por quem ainda não conhece a linguagem direito ainda, até por outros erros.

[Veja mais sobre a decisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50165/101) (é C++, mas essencialmente é a mesma coisa).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: É que basicamente tô vendo vários problemas desses durante o programa, aloca a memória bem no início da função, e não antes de usá-la. Tem uma função que tem um ponteiro de char que tem no seu conteúdo, concatenado, basicamente uma super string, que é recebida da leitura de um arquivo de configuração. Aloca a memória e já recebe a função de leitura, só que é mandado no retorno da função, então não é desalocado. Isso tá gerando um problema chato. Como eu consigo colocar o conteudo em uma variável não dinâmica e retornar essa variável? Tem que retornar ponteiro de char.

Comment: Para retornar tem que ser dinâmica mesmo, este é o motivo de existir isso. Ou tem que passar ela alocada como parâmetro, assim que precisa do valor é que aloca.

Answer (score 0):

Na parte dos dois códigos, a função do tipo que eles usaram está errada inclusive, então seria uma escolha fácil pelo segundo tipo.

Usar essa linha logo após o malloc é um erro:

```
x = (char *)NULL //sem ";" ainda por cima...
```

**Opinião considerando que os dois trechos funcionam:** 
Varia muito de acordo com o caso.

Alocação dinâmica costuma ser vantajoso na parte de performance e memória se há flutuações grandes de objetos. Você não precisa ficar com 256 posições alocadas se usa geralmente 3 ou 4. A parte ruim é que costuma ser mais complicado de gerenciar.

Ainda mais se você for implementar seguranças automáticas, a performance entre as duas vai ser alterada. Só que hoje em dia, o hardware costuma permitir que os programadores tenham esses "mimos". Tem que ver qual o motivo para esse código legado ser assim, mudar todo o código agora seria bobagem também se ele for muito grande e difícil de testar.

Dito isso, hoje em dia vale à pena deixar otimização como uma das últimas prioridades ao programar. Se o código vai começar a ser criado agora, de preferência a clareza e facilidade de manutenção. Depois, se perceber que algum método precisa de performance, aí você pode procurar onde espremer.