# Diferença de parâmetro char *str e char str[] em função?

Tags: c

Qual a diferença em utilizar nessa função `void removeSpaces(char *str)` e `void removeSpaces(char str[])`

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116333/101