# Programa não espera pra ler o conteúdo recebido

Tags: c, string, scanf

Estou criando um programa que lê o nome do aluno, o número de faltas, 3 notas e retorna se o aluno foi aprovado, reprovado por falta ou reprovado por média, sabendo que o limite de faltas é 15, a nota mínima para aprovação é 7 e que a reprovação por falta sobrepõe a reprovação por média.

Mas acontece que após imprimir na tela "digite o número de faltas", o programa não espera que eu entre com um número, mas finaliza logo o programa. Qual o erro?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main() {    
char nome;
int f;
float n1,n2,n3;
float mf=(n1+n2+n3)/3;
printf("Digite o nome do aluno: \n");
scanf("%c", &nome);
printf("Digite o numero de faltas do aluno: \n");
scanf("%d", &f);
if (f > 15)
    printf("Aluno reprovado por falta. \n");
else {
    printf("Digite a primeira nota do aluno: \n");
    scanf("%f", &n1);
    printf("Digite a segunda nota do aluno: \n");
    scanf("%f", &n2);
    printf("Digite a terceira nota do aluno: \n");
    scanf("%f", &n3);
    if(mf>=7)
        printf("Aluno aprovado! \n");
    else 
        printf("Aluno reprovado por media. \n");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você está mandando ler apenas um caractere, precisar pedir uma *string*, e claro, antes precisa alocar memória para ela.

Comment: como faço isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O primeiro erro e que está descrito na pergunta é que está pedindo um caractere apenas. Precisa pedir uma *string*, com [`%s` no `scanf()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string).

Claro que antes precisa alocar memória para ela com um [*array* de `char`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116333/101).

Também tem um erro que tenta calcular a média antes de pedir as notas, o que obviamente vai dar resultado errado.

Fora isto, o código precisa ser um pouco mais organizado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {    
    char nome[30];
    int f = 0;
    printf("Digite o nome do aluno: ");
    scanf("%s", nome);
    printf("\nDigite o numero de faltas do aluno: ");
    scanf("%d", &f);
    if (f > 15) printf("\nAluno reprovado por falta.");
    else {
        float n1, n2, n3;
        printf("\nDigite a primeira nota do aluno: ");
        scanf("%f", &n1);
        printf("\nDigite a segunda nota do aluno: ");
        scanf("%f", &n2);
        printf("\nDigite a terceira nota do aluno: ");
        scanf("%f", &n3);
        float mf = (n1 + n2 + n3) / 3;
        if (mf >= 7) printf("\nAluno aprovado!");
        else printf("\nAluno reprovado por media.");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qsPxnJ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pqxpjybr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/MediaGrade.c).

Comment: perfeito!! muito obrigado