# Problema com char retornando caracteres estranhos

Tags: c, array, string, ponteiro

A intenção é substituir todas as palavras `toda` por `0`, contudo após X caracteres ele começa a retornar valores estranhos como pode ser observado nos comentários.

Creio que eu esteja manuseando errado os parâmetros, mas em que ponto? Por que?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

/*
 * @brief
 * PHP's str_replace ported to C
 * @author Silver Moon (m00n.silv3r@gmail.com)
 * 
 */

char *str_replace(char *search , char *replace , char *subject)
{
    char  *p = NULL , *old = NULL , *new_subject = NULL ;
    int c = 0 , search_size;

    search_size = strlen(search);

    //Count how many occurences
    for(p = strstr(subject , search) ; p != NULL ; p = strstr(p + search_size , search))
    {
        c++;
    }

    //Final size
    c = ( strlen(replace) - search_size )*c + strlen(subject);

    //New subject with new size
    new_subject = malloc( c );

    //Set it to blank
    strcpy(new_subject , "");

    //The start position
    old = subject;

    for(p = strstr(subject , search) ; p != NULL ; p = strstr(p + search_size , search))
    {
        //move ahead and copy some text from original subject , from a certain position
        strncpy(new_subject + strlen(new_subject) , old , p - old);

        //move ahead and copy the replacement text
        strcpy(new_subject + strlen(new_subject) , replace);

        //The new start position after this search match
        old = p + search_size;
    }

    //Copy the part after the last search match
    strcpy(new_subject + strlen(new_subject) , old);

    return new_subject;
}


char* change(char *original) {
    char end[100];

    strcpy(end, str_replace("toda",        "0", original));

    return end;
}

int main()
{
    char *original[100],
         *final[100];

    printf("digite:");

    fgets(original, sizeof(original), stdin); // obtem valor -> toda toda toda toda toda toda toda toda

    strcpy(final, change(original)); // salva em final o valor alterado
    printf("[%s]", final); // retorna: [0 \336\3770 0 0 0 0 \220\360\277_\377]

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Porque você quer ter 100 strings diferentes? E porque elas não estão sendo alocadas?

Comment: @bigown sou estudante, não sei muito o que fiz, coloquei [100] para o meu depurador parar de dar warning quando ele tenta executar o fgets e strcpy

Comment: Não é assim que a coisa funciona, toda vez que encontrar um problema tem que entender o que é e como resolvê-lo. Se começar procurar soluções aleatórias só aumenta o problema.O que deveria aparecer? Oito 0s? Precisa mesmo desta função `change()`? Me parece que ela está de alegre aí. Eu até estou fazendo uma resposta e tirei isso. Minha internet está caindo toda hora, e vou ter que interagir menos e complementar quando der.

Comment: @bigown no final do codigo percebi que comecei errado, tudo errado :/. A intenção é que apareça 8x`0` sim. Podes me explanar meus erros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tinha porque usar ponteiro ali na declaração das variáveis iniciais. Se fosse usar o ponteiro não deveria usar *array*, aí alocaria com `malloc()` que por sinal é usado da função de *replace* e dava erro por não ter o seu `include`.

Na função `change()` deveria usar um `malloc()` para alocar no *heap*. Veja os *links* abaixo para entender melhor. Mas na verdade essa função nem é necessária, dá para simplificar. Ela até poderia ser útil para abstrair a operação, mas não vejo ganho nesse caso. Eu acho até que a variável `final` é desnecessária, mas não vi se tem algum efeito colateral em `str_replace()` que crie algum complicador.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char *str_replace(char *search , char *replace , char *subject) {
    char  *p = NULL , *old = NULL , *new_subject = NULL ;
    int c = 0 , search_size;
    search_size = strlen(search);
    //Count how many occurences
    for (p = strstr(subject , search) ; p != NULL ; p = strstr(p + search_size , search)) {
        c++;
    }
    //Final size
    c = ( strlen(replace) - search_size )*c + strlen(subject);
    //New subject with new size
    new_subject = malloc( c );
    //Set it to blank
    strcpy(new_subject , "");
    //The start position
    old = subject;
    for (p = strstr(subject , search) ; p != NULL ; p = strstr(p + search_size , search)) {
        //move ahead and copy some text from original subject , from a certain position
        strncpy(new_subject + strlen(new_subject) , old , p - old);
        //move ahead and copy the replacement text
        strcpy(new_subject + strlen(new_subject) , replace);
        //The new start position after this search match
        old = p + search_size;
    }
    //Copy the part after the last search match
    strcpy(new_subject + strlen(new_subject) , old);
    return new_subject;
}

int main() {
    char original[100], final[100];
    printf("digite:");
    fgets(original, sizeof(original), stdin);
    strcpy(final, str_replace("toda", "0", original));
    printf("[%s]", final);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/fA9P7F). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/oibruvwp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/AllocationString.c).

Se for usar mesmo o `change()`, o que é um desperdício:

```
char* change(char *original) {
    char *end = malloc(100);
    strcpy(end, str_replace("toda", "0", original));
    return end;
}
```

Perguntas relacionas com mais detalhes:

- [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)
- [Ponteiro de char ou array de char?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116333/101)
- [Diferença entre array de char e ponteiro de char](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130792/101)
- [Alocação dinâmica de memória X vetor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120103/101)
- [Performance de acesso a dados na heap e stack e alocação de objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101)
- [Qual a diferença entre ponteiro para vetor e ponteiro para variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/193507/101)
- [Arrays são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101)

Comment: Muito obrigada, estou a ler tudo que relacionou. Contudo continuo com o problema, a existencia da função `change` é realmente desnecessária, mas exigência do comando do meu trabalho.. e aparentemente o problema está com ela, pois o erro persistiu..

Comment: Mostrei que está funcionando. Se tem erro é outra coisa.

Comment: você excluiu a função `change` por isso não vê que o erro persiste, ela precisa existir. Como consigo por `malloc` nela para que funcione? Os links relacionados não demonstram isso.

Comment: @Elaine botei como ela deve ser. Mas reforço, isto não é só desnecessário, é um erro, ainda que funcione.

Comment: acho que faltei contigo, essa função `change` serve para mudar não só uma palavra mas uma centena delas, e fazer o inverso também.. não coloquei isso na pergunta pois seria informação demais, sendo que o problema está apenas nos parametros (eu acho).. vou pesquisar para encontrar como solver esse problema. Obrigada

Comment: O que está na pergunta está respondido. E mesmo com o que falou, é um erro fazer isto desta forma.