# Qual a forma correta de se declarar um string em C?

Tags: c, string

Existe varias formas de se declarar uma variável do tipo *string* em C como:

```
char *str;
char str[];
char str[100];
char str[1][100];
```

O que eu gostaria de saber é, existe uma forma correta para declarar uma variável do tipo *string* ou mais recomendada para determinados casos?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nenhuma delas está declarando *strings* mesmo, estão declarando variáveis que podem suportar *strings*.

A última me parece estranha, mas funciona, se usado certo, de forma geral não é usado a não ser que tenha um motivo específico. As outras estão todas corretas.

Esta declara que a variável `str*` será um ponteiro para caracteres. Onde estão estes caracteres é problema de outra parte do código dizer, o que precisa é que depois coloque o endereço da *string* nesta variável.

```
char *str;
```

Já a seguinte não é permitida porque não tem como determinar o tamanho do *array*.

```
char str[];
```

Está já muda um pouco porque ela já reserva o espaço para 100 caracteres (99 úteis) e a *string* ficará junto da variável alocado já no *stack*. O conteúdo será colocado em seguida.

```
char str[100];
```

Na verdade o mais comum é fazer assim, no *stack* ou na área estática:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[] = "teste";
    char *strx = "teste";
    printf("%s", str);
    printf("%s", strx);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Ws6anW). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ycmijvwl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/Declaration.c).

Veja mais em [Ponteiro de char ou array de char?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116333/101).

[Entenda a diferença entre *array* e ponteiro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101).

E ainda leia:

- [Diferença entre array de char e ponteiro de char](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130792/101)
- [char[] ou *char malloc?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141975/101)
- [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)

Comment: Já vi pessoas inicializando uma string usando a função strcpy(), é recomendável utilizar ela? Se sim, em quais casos?

Answer (score 1):

Brinquei um pouco com struct para ver se conseguia fazer uma implementação de string. Até consegui, mas acho que não funciona para gravar num arquivo texto. Ainda não fiz o teste.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// Declaração do tipo string.
typedef struct STRING *string;

// Declaração de um struct usando o tipo string.
typedef struct DISCIPLINA{
    int cod;
    string nome;
}Disciplina;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Declarando uma variável do tipo string
    string frase;

    // Primeiro teste.
    frase = "teste de string";
    printf("%s\n", frase);

    // Segundo teste, alterando o valor da variável.
    frase = "outro teste de string";
    printf("%s\n", frase);

    // Terceito teste, fazendo uma entrada pelo teclado.
    printf("Digite algo: "); fflush(stdin); 
    frase = gets(malloc(100));
    printf("Voce digitou: %s.\n", frase);

    // Quarto teste, Fazendo a estrada na struct pelo teclado.
    Disciplina d;
    d.cod = 1;
    //d.nome = "orientacao a objetos";
    printf("Digite o nome da disciplina: "); fflush(stdin); 
    d.nome = gets(malloc(100)); 
    printf("Cod: %i Nome: %s\n", d.cod, d.nome);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lembrando que ao declarar um ponteiro do tipo char, se você não declarar o conteúdo da string diretamente, poderá gerar um erro **segmentation fault** (por acessar endereços indevidos), já que não foi alocado memória para armazenar determinada string. Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *string;
    fgets(string, 30, stdin); // Fazendo a leitura da string
    printf("%s\n", string);   // Irá apresentar um erro segmentation default
    return 0;
}
```

Maneira correta (alocando memória para armazenar a string):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *string;
    string = malloc(30 * sizeof(char)); // Alocando 30 bytes para armazenar a string
    fgets(string, 30, stdin);           // Fazendo a leitura da string
    printf("%s\n", string);             // Imprimindo a string na tela
    free(string);                       // Liberando memória alocada
    return 0;
}
```