# Teste iguais ao da questão porém está dando erro

Tags: c

Resolvi que 2018 iria aprender a programar, e estou estudando por conta própria, e pesquisando encontrei esse juiz chamado uri, estou com dificuldade em encontrar o erro que tem no meu código, fiz todos os teste, e quando eu envio a questão só da 10 % de erro alguém poderia me ajudar.

[Link da questão](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2690)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
 int i, j, vetor[100], c = 0, teste, k;
 char nome[100];
 char primeiro[6] = {'a', 'k', 'u', 'G', 'Q'}, segundo[6] = {'b', 'l', 'v', 
 'I', 'S'};
 char terceiro[7] = {'E', 'O', 'Y', 'c', 'm', 'w'}, quarto[7] = {'F', 'P', 'Z', 'd', 'n', 'x'};
 char quinto[6] = {'J', 'T', 'e', 'o', 'y'}, sexto[7] = {'D', 'N', 'X', 'f', 'p', 'z'};
 char setimo[6] = {'A', 'K', 'U', 'g', 'q'}, oitavo[6] = {'C', 'M', 'W', 'h', 'r'};
 char nono[6] = {'B', 'L', 'V', 'i', 's'}, deimo[5] = {'H', 'R', 'j', 't'};

 scanf("%d", &teste);
 for(k = 0; k < teste; k++)
 {
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    fgets(nome, 40, stdin);
    int tam = strlen(nome);
    for(i = 0, c = 0; i < tam; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(primeiro); j++)
        {
            if(nome[i] == primeiro[j])
            {
                vetor[c++] = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(segundo); j++)
        {
            if(nome[i] == segundo[j])
            {
                vetor[c++] = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(terceiro); j++)
        {
            if(nome[i] == terceiro[j])
            {
                vetor[c++] = 2;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(quarto); j++)
        {
            if(nome[i] == quarto[j])
            {
                vetor[c++] = 3;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(quinto); j++)
        {
            if(nome[i] == quinto[j])
            {
                vetor[c++] = 4;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(sexto); j++)
        {
            if(nome[i] == sexto[j])
            {
                vetor[c++] = 5;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(setimo); j++)
        {
            if(nome[i] == setimo[j])
            {
                vetor[c++] = 6;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(oitavo); j++)
        {
            if(nome[i] == oitavo[j])
            {
                vetor[c++] = 7;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(nono); j++)
        {
            if(nome[i] == nono[j])
            {
                vetor[c++] = 8;
                break;
            }
        }
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(deimo); j++)
        {
            if(nome[i] == deimo[j])
            {
                vetor[c++] = 9;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(c <= 11)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < c; i++)
        {
            printf("%d", vetor[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            printf("%d", vetor[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    memset(vetor, 0, sizeof(vetor));
}
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

Fico feliz por ter resolvido começar aprender programar e começado por C. Tenho más notícias: começar fazendo sem entender bem o que está fazendo não costuma funcionar. E pior, parece que funcionou e a pessoa fica em [efeito Dunning-Krugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

O enunciado é um pouco falho, então não posso garantir que passará. Esta foi minha interpretação. E falta validação.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char convertido[13];
    char nome[101];
    char *grupos[10] = { "akuGQ", "blvIS", "EOYcmw", "FPZdnx", "JTeoy", "DNXfpz", "AKUgq", "CMWhr", "BLVis", "HRjt" };
    int teste = 3;
    scanf("%d", &teste);
    for (int i = 0; i < teste; i++) {
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);
        fgets(nome, 100, stdin);
        int indiceConvertido = 0;
        for (int posicao = 0; indiceConvertido < 12 && nome[posicao] != '\0' && nome[posicao] != '\n'; posicao++) {
            if (nome[posicao] != ' ') {
                for (int grupo = 0; grupo < 10; grupo++) {
                    for (int item = 0; grupos[grupo][item] != '\0'; item++) { //verifica se ainda não chegou no fim
                        if (nome[posicao] == grupos[grupo][item]) {
                            convertido[indiceConvertido++] = grupo + '0'; //transformando o número em caractere
                            grupo = 10; //para sair dos dois laços
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        convertido[indiceConvertido] = '\0'; //garante que a *string* finaliza após o último caractere
        printf("%s\n", convertido);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/fA0oHx). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bteimhwo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/General.c).

Um problema é que seu código considerava o espaço, e embora o enunciado não fale nada, tem indícios que ele não deve ser considerado.

Outro problema que considerei importante é usar um *array* de inteiros, eu acho que a intenção era gerar caracteres.

Não que dê resultado errado por isso, mas o código individualizou algo que é coletivo. Claramente o há um *array* com grupos de letras. Este é o *array* real. É um [*array* de *strings*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236175/101), e todo [*array* de *strings* tem como tipo `char *` (ponteiro para `char`)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/130792/101). Aí toda lógica muda.

Eu preferi não usar a `string.h` por ser um exercício, mas poderia ter eliminado um laço usando uma função pronta (que tem o laço dentro). É mais "jeito de C" evitar as funções, especialmente a [`strlen()` que é lenta se o que você deseja não é a quantidade de caracteres da *string*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/167528/101), e nestes caso não é o que deseja, precisa saber apenas quando termina a *string*.

O código é confuso, então é até difícil analisar tudo. Eu deixei ele muito mais claro. Se não para ti é porque ainda lhe falta conhecimento para entender um algoritmo deste tipo e está queimando etapas e deixando buracos no aprendizado.

Acho que se tem outras dúvidas deve fazer perguntas específicas já que queria saber o que tem de errado.

Answer (score 0):

Segue uma possível solução para o problema:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SAIDA_MAX_TAM    (12)
#define SENHA_MAX_TAM    (20)


char * converter( char * saida, const char * senha )
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    char * conjuntos[10] = {"GQaku","ISblv","EOYcmw","FPZdnx","JTeoy","DNXfpz","AKUgq","CMWhr","BLVis","HRjt"};

    /* Para cada caractere da senha... */
    for( i = 0; i < strlen(senha) && i < SENHA_MAX_TAM; i++ )
    {
        /* Se o caractere for uma letra... */
        if( isalpha(senha[i]) )
        {
            /* Para cada conjunto... */
            for( j = 0; j < 10 && k < SAIDA_MAX_TAM; j++ )
            {
                /* Se o caracter da senha pertencer ao conjunto... */
                if( strchr( conjuntos[j], senha[i] ) )
                {
                    /* Traduz saida */
                    saida[k++] = '0' + j;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    saida[k] = '\0';

    return saida;
}


int main( void )
{
    int i = 0;
    char saida[ SAIDA_MAX_TAM + 1 ];
    char * entrada[] = {
        "Quem traz CD, LP, fax, engov e whisky JB?",
        "Jane quer LP, fax, CD, giz, TV e bom whisky.",
        "Bancos fúteis pagavam-lhe queijo e whisky xadrez.",
        "Blitz prende ex-vesgo com cheque fajuto.",
        "Jovem craque belga prediz falhas no xote.",
        "Um pequeno jabuti xereta viu dez cegonhas felizes.",
        "Gazeta publica hoje breve nota de faxina na quermesse.",
        "Juiz faz com que whisky de malte baixe logo preco de venda.",
        "Zebras caolhas de Java querem mandar fax para moca gigante de New York.",
        "3",
        "o rato roeu a roupa de margarida",
        "O Rato Roeu A Roupa de Margarida",
        "OlA TuDo CeRtO" };

    for( i = 0; i < sizeof(entrada) / sizeof(entrada[0]); i++ )
        printf( "[%s] => [%s]\n", converter( saida, entrada[i] ), entrada[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
[004297057583] => [Quem traz CD, LP, fax, engov e whisky JB?]
[403460478350] => [Jane quer LP, fax, CD, giz, TV e bom whisky.]
[803248594885] => [Bancos fúteis pagavam-lhe queijo e whisky xadrez.]
[818955743344] => [Blitz prende ex-vesgo com cheque fajuto.]
[441422706041] => [Jovem craque belga prediz falhas no xote.]
[625460434901] => [Um pequeno jabuti xereta viu dez cegonhas felizes.]
[005490501182] => [Gazeta publica hoje breve nota de faxina na quermesse.]
[408550524260] => [Juiz faz com que whisky de malte baixe logo preco de venda.]
[341708204170] => [Zebras caolhas de Java querem mandar fax para moca gigante de New York.]
[] => [3]
[470947440074] => [o rato roeu a roupa de margarida]
[290949440694] => [O Rato Roeu A Roupa de Margarida]
[216405474992] => [OlA TuDo CeRtO]
```

Comment: Bom vi que o resultado, deram certos, só que essa solução está um pouco complicada para eu entender, você poderia editar, a parte que pode colocar vários casos de testes como a questão pede?, Obrigado desde já

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas maneiro, é quem está começando é errando que se aprende, infelizmente a solução não passou, agora não estou preocupado com a solução, sei que não tem haver com o post da pergunta, mas você poderia me recomendar algum livro para quem está começando a programar ?