# Como o malloc() organiza a memória?

Tags: c, memória, gerenciamento-de-memória, malloc

Quando eu aloco memoria com `malloc()`, os endereços ficam igual a um vetor? Ou ficam espalhados pela memória do PC?

Eu quero criar uma lista de `structs`, para fazer isso, eu tenho que ter vários `structs` no caso, eu posso fazer isso apenas alocando memoria com (`malloc()`) ou existe outra maneira de fazer?

Exemplo :

```
int n=7,cout;
Node *lista;  <- Essa lista Node vamos supor que eu tenha criado antes do main.
for(cout=1;cout<=n;cout++){
    lista = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node)*n);
}
```

Fiz isso para criar 7 nós.

Ao fazer isso, eu estou realmente usando os conceitos de lista? E se eu quiser ligar o meu ponteiro que esta na `struct` em outro nó, como faço para identificar o outro nó já que todas são do tipo `Node` e tem o mesmo nome? E o que o `malloc()` difere de um vetor? Mas pergunto isso não no sentido de uma ser estática e outra dinâmica, mas sim nas posições de memória.

Comment: Gente, só uma correção : Esqueçam aquele for ali, eu só queria alocar 7 espaços mesmo, nem sei porque fiz um for ali.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A alocação por [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) é [igual ao *array*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91336/101) no ponto de vista da pergunta, é tudo contínuo, **quando está alocando uma sequência de dados**.

Bom, fisicamente pode não ser assim por causa da memória virtual, mas isto não importa para seu programa, ele verá os endereços como se fossem contínuos.

O que muda é o local de armazenamento, o `malloc()` alocará no *heap* e o *array* alocará na *stack* (a não ser que ele faça parte de outra estrutura que vá no *heap*, porque aí o *array* não está alocando de fato, está só reservando espaço em outra estrutura). Tecnicamente a `stack* é uma estrutura de dados, então o *array* sempre está reservando espaço. É verdade que o *heap* também, mas a estrutura é externa à aplicação, então realmente é uma alocação.

Se estiver fazendo alocações isoladas, não há garantias de onde cada uma delas serão acessadas, então elas podem estar espalhadas, ainda que seja provável que não esteja, na maioria das situações simples, o que pode levar a erro porque as pessoas não se preocupam em fazer o certo, apenas em fazer funcionar, que são coisas muito diferentes.

Este código não parece fazer sentido. Acho que é só isto que deseja:

```
Node *lista = malloc(sizeof(Node) * 7);
```

Mas se fizer:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) Node no[i] = malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/Malloc.c).

Já não garante que a alocação será contínua.

Se está fazendo uma [lista ligada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164085/101), aí provavelmente quer outra coisa, mas também diferente do que está na pergunta.

Tem várias formas de alocar memória, depende do que precisa.

Estude:

- [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)
- [Alocação dinâmica de memória X vetor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120103/101)
- [Ponteiro de char ou array de char?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/116333/101)

Não respondi o resto porque são outras perguntas, faça em separado. Inclusive porque elas não possuem informação suficiente para responder.

Comment: Então,  se por exemplo, se em uma parte do meu algoritmo eu usar um malloc sem multiplicar, e em outra parte do meu algoritmo eu voltar a usar o malloc novamente, esses espaços alocados podem tanto estar juntinhos ali como podem estar separados ali na memoria ? Obrigado, já estou lendo aqui os links :D

Comment: Sim, só há garantia se for uma única operação de alocação.

Comment: Ahhh sim,valeu brow