# Como faco para usar o free() e retornar o mesmo conteúdo?

Tags: c, ponteiro, memória, alocação

Queria usar o `free()` em `ls_retorna` na seguinte função, como poderia fazê-la com a melhor maneira?

```
char* MemCpyX(char *as_origem, int an_inicio, int an_quantidade)
{
    char *ls_retorno = (char*)malloc(an_quantidade);

    memcpy(ls_retorno, as_origem + an_inicio, an_quantidade);

    return(ls_retorno);
}
```

Comment: Você deseja usar o free em qual variável?

Comment: Se quer usar `free()` em `ls_retorno` não vai produzir nenhum resultado útil. Se quer usar em `as_origem`, não é uma boa ideia fazer aí.

Comment: estava pensando em fazer no ls_retorno

Comment: a memoria não fica alocada mesmo depois do fim da função?

Comment: Não, o free libera a memoria alocada, neste caso não deverá ser utilizada

Comment: Se fizer isso vai matar o que acabou de criar, aí não faz sentido retornar esse endereço. Pode até for funcionar por coincidência que é a pior coisa que pode acontecer em um código em C que "funcione". Fica alocada se não der `free()`. Pra falar a verdade o ideal é dar `free()` sempre onde aloca. Aí você pode pensar, então é aí que eu vou fazer. O erro é que o `malloc()` não deve deve estar aí. O ideal é alocar e desalocar no local de uso, deixar a função só para fazer o estritamente necessário.

Comment: e se trocar o `ls_retorno`  por um vector simples? não haveria necessidade de usar o free

Comment: Mas aí você não poderia retorná-lo porque ele deixaria de existir quando a função encerrar.

Comment: acho que vou faze-la criando variável fora da função e passando o endereço como parâmetro, essa seria uma solução?

Comment: Eu acho que seria melhor.

Comment: @bigown formula essa resposta, que aceito ela, ajudou bastante

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seria interessante entender o funcionamento da [*stack* e *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Entenda [porque devemos usar o *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56580/101). Também: [Quando devo escolher entre utilizar ou não um ponteiro ao criar um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50165/101).

De uma maneira geral devemos alocar e liberar uma memória na mesma função. Claro que toda "regra" pode ser violada se houver um bom motivo, mas fazendo assim ajuda organizar mais e evitar complicação no gerenciamento da memória e evitar vazamentos.

Se alocar no *stack*, fica fácil, encerrou o [escopo, o tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) dela acaba e é destruída (e pelo menos pode ser, então mesmo que o dado ainda esteja lá não pode usá-lo confiavelmente. Um objeto criado na pilha só pode ser garantidamente acessada dentro deste escopo, em geral uma função, ou nas funções chamadas por ela. Você pode criar um objeto ali e passar uma referência para ele como argumento de uma chamada de função sem problemas.

Se precisar de um tempo de vida maior, ou seja fazer um objeto sobreviver ao escopo que foi criado, tem que ser no *heap*. O mesmo vale se o objeto for potencialmente muito grande. Se alocar no *heap* (provavelmente com `malloc()`) tem que liberar manualmente (provavelmente com `free()`, ou uma função que tenha o `free()`), o ideal é que faça na mesma função para não perder o controle do que deve liberar (o que talvez diminua um pouco uma das suas vantagens).

Então no caso da pergunta não tem muito como resolver de forma ideal sem tirar a alocação dela. Se alocar, como está fazendo, e liberar dentro dela, a memória torna-se inválida e não deve mais ser acessada, portanto retornar um ponteiro para o endereço do objeto alocado é um erro.

Deixar sem liberar a memória pode funcionar se tiver certeza que quem chamar essa função `MemCpyX()` fará a liberação. Um perigo, não?

O melhor é alocar fora, passar uma referência para essa memória alocada. Algo assim:

```
void MemCpyX(char *as_origem, char *ls_retorno, int an_inicio, int an_quantidade) {
    memcpy(ls_retorno, as_origem + an_inicio, an_quantidade);
}
```

Aí chama assim:

```
char *retorno = malloc(quantidade);
MemCpyX(origem, retorno, inicio, quantidade);
//faz alguma coisa
free(retorno);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/MemCpy.c).

Também poderia ser:

```
char retorno[quantidade];
MemCpyX(origem, retorno, inicio, quantidade);
```

Mas convenhamos, assim essa função ficou meio sem motivo para existir, a não ser que pretenda fazer algo a mais ali nela :)

Comment: quando eu chamo a função dessa maneira, acontece o  erro `SIGSEGV`, o certo não seria `MemCpyX(&origem, retorno, inicio, quantidade);`?

Comment: Pode ser sim, depende de como essa variável foi declarada. Presumi que ela era um ponteiro, se não é, então tem que fazer dessa forma.

Comment: e na verdade o usei essa função como exemplo da minha duvida, tenho varias funções diferentes com o mesmo formato que ela, mas só para colocar como exemplo que usei essa função sem sentido, obrigado

Comment: @LucasFernandes imaginei.

Answer (score 1):

Minha opinião é que deve modificar a função para não precisar usar o `free()`

Segue uma sugestão de como fazer isso:

```
char* MemCpyX(char *as_origem, char *ls_retorno, int an_inicio, int an_quantidade)
{
    memcpy(ls_retorno, as_origem + an_inicio, an_quantidade);
}
```

Mas assim não haveria necessidade de dessa função, já que poderia usar o `memcpy` no lugar da `MemCpyX`