# Em que realmente são usados ponteiros em C++?

Tags: c++, variáveis, ponteiro, memória, c++11

Em que realmente é usado ponteiros?

Eu já procurei em tantos lugares e o exemplo é sempre teórico.

Gostaria de saber uma situação real, um exemplo dentro de um projeto real no qual é utilizado ponteiros.

Outras dúvidas são:

Se eu não estiver utilizando ponteiros, isso é errado?

Posso fazer tudo em C++ utilizando apenas variáveis?

Comment: Ué, tem a mesma utilizada que no C. Serve para referenciar um espaço  de memória, um uma variável simples o um objeto.

Comment: Mas porque referenciar um espaço na memória? onde se aplica isso?como eu disse eu já entendi essa parte mas não sei onde se aplica.

Comment: Quando você quer utilizar uma estrutura de dados mais complexa, ou algo com tamanho diferente dos tipos nativos. Vai ter que alocar a memória no braço e guardar um ponteiro para esse espaço de memória. Porem, ponteiros servem para diversas coisas. Vai da sua necessidade ou criatividade. Lembrando que C++ é baseado no C. Se quer entender ponteiro, procura tutoriais que mostram como usar e para que serve no C.

Comment: Os objetos podem ficar em três lugares: na pilha, no heap e na seção de variáveis globais. Objetos no heap só podem ser acessados via ponteiros, porque eles podem ou não estar lá, o heap é uma espécie de "terra de ninguém". Ponteiro é essencialmente uma referência anulável (ou uma referência é um ponteiro que nunca pode ser nulo), a sintaxe da linguagem garante que variáveis globais ou na pilha sempre existam, mas não no heap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talvez esteja procurando pela informação na ordem errada. Talvez ainda lhe falte um punhado de informações mais básicas antes de chegar nos ponteiros. Talvez esteja estudando o assunto sem uma estrutura. Quando estudamos passo a passo, na ordem certa a necessidade do ponteiro aparece naturalmente.

Em geral não devemos procurar uma utilidade para um mecanismo. Procuramos o mecanismo quando temos uma necessidade.

## Variável

Vamos começar pelo básico: uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é um local de armazenamento de dados com um nome. Ela é um conceito abstrato que usamos para entender melhor o código. Computadores não possuem e não entendem variáveis.

Nesses locais de armazenamento temos valores que serão úteis no processamento que estamos realizando.

Se esses valores não precisam ser referenciados nominalmente não precisamos de variáveis, podemos trabalhar só com valores. A variável é um instrumento útil para acessar o mesmo valor mais de uma vez de forma fácil. Também é usada quando é necessário um passo intermediário complexo. Em alguns casos ela pode ser usada só para efeito de documentação do que está fazendo.

Os dados que são armazenados na memória podem ser por valor, ou seja, o dado útil está no local de armazenamento, possivelmente com um nome. Ou os dados podem ser por referência, desta forma há dois locais de armazenamento, um deles a referência dizendo onde está o dado útil, e outro é esse local do dado útil.

## Memória

Essa referência é como se fosse um endereço postal, e o dado é a casa onde mora a família. A referência é implementada como um ponteiro. Existem várias formas de ponteiro em C++.

É comum que os ponteiros apontam para um local no *heap*. Mas é possível apontar para outras áreas da memória, como a *stack* e a área estática do código. Veja mais sobre isso em [O que são e onde estão a "stack" e "heap"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

De uma maneira geral o acesso ao *heap* é feito através de ponteiros.

> É possível fazer tudo sem ponteiros, só com valores diretos?

Sim, na teoria é possível.

Mas quer saber na prática, e aí a resposta é não. Primeiro que a performance seria trágica tendo que ficar copiando dados grandes toda hora, teria que sempre ter memória reservada para tudo até o máximo que é permitido, o que seria um enorme desperdício, não poderia fazer aproveitamento de dados repetidos, uma série de técnicas ficariam inviabilizadas, como a composição de dados e a troca de dados dinamicamente.

Ponteiro deve ser uma das 5 ou 6 coisas mais importantes para se aprender em codificação C++, ainda que ele bruto não seja tão usado.

E se vai aprender C++, aprenda C++, não aprenda C e ache que está aprendendo C++. São linguagens muito compatíveis, mas totalmente diferentes. Em C ponteiros são mais usado de forma direta. Não caia no erro de usar C++ para programar C, como muitos fazem. Você pode aprender as duas linguagens, mas a primeira coisa é entender que elas são muito diferentes que devem ser usados de formas diferentes.

> Se eu não estiver utilizando ponteiros isso é errado?

Não sei, depende do caso. Não existe resposta única. Não existe receita de bolo, não existem "boas práticas" universais. Existe a necessidade e o mecanismo que a soluciona, tem que aprender tudo sobre o assunto, experimentar (para ganhar experiência) para entender quando usar e quando não usar.

A ideia é evitar usar até que seja necessário. Se não terá ganho em usar um ponteiro, não use.

> Eu já procurei em tantos lugares e o exemplo é sempre teórico

Em geral é isso que encontrará. A não ser que saia fuçando em códigos já existentes, aí todos são exemplos bem práticos. É uma boa forma de complementar estudos. Hoje não faltam projetos com código aberto.

Se você faz uma pergunta teórica, receberá uma resposta teórica. Se procura pela teoria, encontrará teoria. Ainda bem, sem ela não é possível entender o que está acontecendo. E ninguém programa de verdade sem entender a teoria.

Obviamente que excluo quem copia o que já foi feito antes e preenche lacunas. Isso não é programar.

Um dos maiores problemas para responder isso é que eu posso responder e você ficar na mesma porque eu não sei o que já sabe. Quando há um estudo estruturado, onde não se pula etapas, cada novo conhecimento é dado sabendo o que você já sabe.

Em exemplo sem contato provavelmente não será para muita coisa.

## Uso de ponteiro

A pergunta sequer é clara se está falando de ponteiro bruto ou qualquer forma de ponteiro. Em tese em um projeto todo seu é relativamente fácil ficar sem usar ponteiros brutos, desde que não use bibliotecas externas que resultem em um ponteiro bruto.

Toda vez que precisa armazenar dados dinamicamente (*heap*), vai usar ponteiro. Se fará isso com ponteiro bruto, com uma [referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56470/101), com um [*smart pointer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), ou se o objeto que vai usar faz o tratamento do ponteiro para você de forma transparente, é uma questão de escolha de acordo com a necessidade. O que posso adiantar é que ponteiro brutos são evitadas em C++ moderno. Se não der para usar referência, a opção é pelo [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) ou outra forma gerenciada de ponteiro.

Um ponteiro é um [indireção](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection). Acessar dados de forma indireta dá muita flexibilidade porque você passa ter um intermediário que pode ser variável. Então podemos ter uma variável de algo variável.

> All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection
>
> -- David Wheeler

O ponteiro pode ser uma [abstração](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(software_engineering)) para o valor concreto. Abstrações são muito úteis para facilitar o entendimento e até solucionar certos problemas. É comum ter outros níveis de abstração que escondem o ponteiro, mas ele ainda está lá.

Um *array* ou outras formas de coleções de dados (listas, pilhas, árvores, grafos, filas) normalmente são acessados através de ponteiros, afinal o *array* é um *subset* da memória. Se um ponteiro é um dado variável e portando aponta para dados diferentes, ele se encaixa como uma luva em *array* cujo valor é composto por uma série de variáveis. Dá para programar sem *array*? Dá, mas é insano. A não ser que esteja falando de problemas e exercícios muito simples e autocontidos.

Tem mais detalhes em [Quando devo escolher entre utilizar ou não um ponteiro ao criar um objeto?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50165/101).

Tem [várias perguntas sobre o assunto aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ponteiro?sort=votes&pageSize=50), muitas delas são bem práticas. A maioria é C, mas se for ponteiro bruto é igual.

Conforme for avançando vai saber onde pode ser usado de forma natural. Faça perguntas mais específicas aqui com problemas mais específicos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).