# Funcionamento do operador new

Tags: c++, classes, operadores

Eu queria entender basicamente qual a lógica por trás dos objetos das classes que usam o operador `new` por exemplo, tenho o seguinte programa em linguagem D:

```
import std.stdio;

class Hello
{
 public this(){} //construtor

 public void print()
 {
  writeln("Hello World");
 }
}

void main()
{
  Hello h = new Hello();
  h.print();
}
```

Em C++

```
#include <iostream>

class Hello
{
  public:
  Hello(){} //construtor

 void print()
 {
   std::cout<<"Hello World";
 }
}

void main()
{
  Hello *h = new Hello();
  h->print();
}
```

Como é funciona essa alocação de ponteiro do objeto na linguagem para que o programador faça `h.print()` e não `h->print()`?

O compilador gera código a mais por trás e faz alocação ou o desenvolvedor da linguagem define essa forma de trabalhar na própria linguagem?

Teria como simular isso em C++ fazendo assim?

```
Hello h = new Hello();
h.print();
```

ao invés de:

```
Hello *h = new Hello();
h->print();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Começo por indicar que:

```
ponteiro->metodo();
```

Corresponde a

```
(*ponteiro).metodo();
```

E é o que se costuma de chamar *syntactic sugar*, ou seja, uma forma mais conveniente de o programador fazer o mesmo.

Analisando a instrução, vemos que se está a obter o valor apontado pelo ponteiro com o `*` e sobre esse valor aceder ao `metodo`.

Significa que o exemplo que apresentou poderia também ser escrito assim:

```
Hello *h = new Hello();
(*h).print();
```

No entanto seria bem menos pratico.

**Operador `new`**

O operador `new` em C++ devolve sempre o endereço de memória onde foi colocado o objeto pelo alocador de memória. Este é equivalente ao [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) em C.

E por isso sempre se vê código que guarda o resultado do `new` num ponteiro, tal como o que apresentou:

```
Hello *h = new Hello();
h->print();
```

Mas não é obrigatório. Poderia guardar apenas valor apontado pelo ponteiro recebido, assim:

```
Hello h = *(new Hello()); //atente no * para obter o objeto que o ponteiro aponta
h.print();
```

Mas acaba por não simplificar propriamente a utilização e irá dificultar mais à frente quando necessitar de passar o ponteiro para o objeto noutras funções

Comment: Muito interessante tenho que tomar vergonha na cara e meter a fuça aprende ponteiro,alocação, realocação e gerenciamento de memória..

Comment: Mas como assim "irá dificultar mais à frente quando necessitar de passar o ponteiro para o objeto noutras funções" se eu entendi bem vc esta querendo dizer que dificultaria o uso deste ponteiro para criar um novo objeto é isso?

Comment: @dark777 Refiro-me a situações em que as funções estão à espera de ponteiros e você tendo objetos voltar a ir buscar o endereço para poder chamar a função. Estou basicamente a falar a nível de sintaxe. Mas em todos os códigos que vemos em C++ é sempre usado o `new` e guardardo o valor num ponteiro, é o que é considerado de boas praticas

Comment: entendi criei este tópico sobre a duvida pra entender se tal façanha era possivel e se fosse como ele trabalharia por tras se fazia somente alocação ou realocação de memória ou se ele dava retorno de *this dentro de algum tipo de construtor para tal mas ja me elucidou bem a duvida... Obrigado pelos feedbacks ....

Comment: @dark777 Sem problema. É sempre importante perceber e aprofundar bem a parte de ponteiros e memoria pois é vital no C/C++. Bons estudos.

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma enorme diferença entre C++ e D. D cria classes sempre por referência e aloca no *heap* gerenciado. Em C++ uma classe é apenas uma estrutura (`struct`) cujos membros são privados por padrão, mas nada. Se deseja alocar no *heap* não gerenciado deve usar o `new` para dizer isto ao compilador. Em D é só para deixar legível que é sua intenção mesmo.

Po outro lado em C++ moderno é raro usar esta forma, hoje costuma-se usar memória semi-gerenciada com [ponteiros inteligentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/175967/101).

Em geral compiladores geram códigos "a mais" o tempo todo, é uma de suas principais funções.

A alocação é feita pelo operador `new` e para aí. Internamente o operador provavelmente usa a função `malloc()`, mas não necessariamente. É possível definir na classe seu próprio operador `new`.

C++ gosta de ser explícito quanto à forma de acesso ao objeto ao passo que D não se importa com isto, então tentar usar o operador de ponto no lugar da seta é gambiarra e não idiomático em C++.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).