# Quando utilizar new e delete em c++?

Tags: c++, dinâmico

Estou estudando sobre ponteiros em c++, eu ainda não entendo muito bem como utilizar mas eu já tenho uma noção, e uma das utilidades que vi é "alocação dinâmica". Eu já ouvi falar disso em linguagem C com `malloc()` e `free()`, porém eu não achei nenhum conteúdo em português falando de `new` e `delete` (vi em inglês, porém meu inglês ainda não é desse nível)

**Minhas dúvidas são**: Como funciona `new` e `delete`? E quando usar?

Answer (score 2):

O `new` nos permite alocar memória dinamicamente na chamada memória *Heap*, ao invés de alocá-lo na memória *Stack* (*veja a nota abaixo*). O `delete`, por sua vez, permite-nos liberar essa memória que foi alocada. Os principais usos do `new` são os seguintes:

1. Criar objetos dinamicamente;
2. Criar arrays dinamicamente.

**P.S.**: Esta afirmação nem sempre é verdadeira, pois como dito por Augusto Vasques em seu comentário, é possível explicitamente alocar a memória na *Stack* através do uso da função `alloca()` junto com o `new`. Todavia, como ele falou, isso pode acarretar um **Stack overflow** se não for usado com cuidado. Assim sendo, esse artifício deve ser usado com prudência.

### Criar objetos dinamicamente

#### Por que usar new para criar objetos dinamicamente?

Algumas vezes se deseja criar objetos que são muito grandes para serem armazenados na memória *Stack* (a memória stack é bem menor do que a memória *Heap*, mas isso não quer dizer que deve-se sempre usar essa ao invés daquela), ou então se deseja **criar um objeto cujo tempo de vida seja maior do que o tempo de vida da função ou do bloco de código que o gerou** (quando inicializada normalmente, p.e.: `int a = 10`, uma variável é "destruída" após o fim do bloco). Nesses casos, é possível recorrer ao `new` para criar os objetos na memória *Heap*.

##### Como usar new para alocar objetos dinamicamente?

Para se inicializar uma variável usando `new`, é preciso saber que a variável deve ser de tipo ponteiro (`int *intPtr`, por exemplo) e **é também necessário lembrar de deletar a memória alocada usando `delete` no fim da utilização da variável**. Abaixo estão alguns exemplos de gerenciamento de memória dinâmica usando `new` e `delete`.

```cpp
// Exemplo #1
// ponteiro para int intPtr não inicializado - evite essa situação sempre que possível
int* intPtr;
intPtr = new int; // intPtr agora aponta para uma região de memória Heap correspondente a uma variável inteira
*intPtr = 10; // Alteração do valor na variável dinâmica para 10;
std::cout << *intPtr << std::endl; // Mostra o valor 10 na saída
delete intPtr; // Liberação da memória alocada dinamicamente usando new

// Exemplo #2
int* iPtr = new int{10}; // A memória é alocada dinâmicamente e o valor 10 é atribuído à variável correspondente
std::cout << iPtr << std::endl; // Imprime o valor 10 na tela
delete iPtr; // Liberação da memória alocada dinâmicamente usando new
```

Vale a pena notar que nos exemplos acima eu tomei o cuidado de usar `delete` ao fim do uso da minha variável para evitar um **vazamento de memória** (isto é, evitar que a memória alocada na `Heap` permanecesse "consumida" até o fim do programa). Se houverem muitos vazamentos em um programa (principalmente em um grande programa), a performance do sistema pode ser bastante degradada ou a pode acontecer a interrupção da execução.

Um outro ponto importante é a necessidade de se usar o **operador de "desreferenciação"**, o símbolo *****, para acessar o valor na memória alocada dinamicamente para qual o ponteiro aponta (se quiser saber mais sobre o funcionamento dos ponteiros, escrevi um [artigo sobre o assunto](https://cppmoderno.com/o-que-e-um-ponteiro-em-cpp/) no meu website).

### Criar arrays dinamicammente em C++

Outra utilidade do `new` é a criação de arrays de forma dinâmica. Aqui, como na criação de variáveis dinamicamente, a memória utilizada pelo array é alocada na *Heap*, e não na *Stack*. Uma vantagem de fazer isso é evitar o famoso **Stack overflow** ao se alocar arrays estáticos muito grandes (ou de maneira recorrente).

#### Como usar new para criar arrays dinamicamente

Para se criar uma array usando `new`, é preciso ter um ponteiro que guardará o endereço do primeiro elemento do array, e a sintaxe é a seguinte: `tipo* nomeDoArray = new tipo[tamanho-do-array]`.
Vejamos abaixo alguns exemplos de alocação de um array na memória *Stack*, e um outro exemplo de alocação de array na memória *Heap*, usando `new`.

```cpp
// Alocaçao na stack
size_t arraySize = 10;
int staticArray[arraySize]; // Array com valores não-inicializados - situação perigosa a se evitar
int anotherStatArray[] = {10, 20, 30, 40}; // Inicialização por lista de valores - ok
... // Uso do array no código - não é preciso liberar a memória manualmente

// Alocação na memória Heap usando new
int* intArray = new int[arraySize]; // Array alocado dinamicamente usando new - valores não inicializados
... // Uso do array no bloco de código;
delete[] intArray; // Liberação da memória usada pelo array usando delete[]
```

Como se pode ver nos exemplos acima, na alocação de memória dinâmica, é preciso usar  `delete[]` para liberar a memória usada pelo array (note os colchetes [] após o delete, para indicar que se está desalocando uma região de memória para um array, e não apenas um único objeto). Com a alocação estática, o usuário não precisa se preocupar com isso.

#### Por que não usar new para criar arrays em C++?

Atualmente, sempre que possível é melhor evitar o uso de `new` e `delete[]` para gerenciar memória de arrays manualmente. Isso se dá principalmente pelas seguintes razões:

1. É difícil liberar a memória alocada dinâmicamente em sistemas grandes ou pequenos, mas com complexidade importante;
2. Entre a alocação e a liberação da memória, uma parte do programa pode ser interrompida (por uma excepção, por exemplo) antes da instrução `delete` e a memória permanecerá alocada até o fim da execução do programa inteiro.
3. Há alternativas melhores para os arrays em C++

##### Quais alternativas usar ao invés do new e delete para criar arrays em C++

Ao invés de se criar arrays manualmente com `new` e `delete`, é recomendado utilizar os containers da biblioteca padrão, como o `std::vector` (uma espécie de array que pode aumentar ou diminuir de tamanho automaticamente), por exemplo, ou o `std::array` (um equivalente do array estático, com tamanho fixo), ambos os quais tem **gerenciamento automático de memória*, ou seja: não é preciso usar `new` e `delete` para gerenciar a memória destes containers, e eles cuidam da memória alocada quando o bloco onde foram criados termina sua execução. Se quiser saber mais sobre o assunto, você pode verificar o Cpp reference ou o meu [artigo sobre as razões para não se criar arrays usando new em C++.](https://cppmoderno.com/criar-array-com-new-em-cpp-3-razoes-contrarias/)

### No fim, quando usar `new` e `delete`?

Normalmente, a razão mais plausível para se usar `new` e `delete` é a necessidade de se extender a vida do objeto criado para além da função, ou do bloco, que o criou. Todavia, para arrays, é recomendável evitar completamente o uso do `new` e `delete`, e utilizar os containers da biblioteca padrão ao invés disso; para objetos, sempre que possível é melhor usar ***smart pointers*** (p.e.:  `shared_pointer`,  `unique_pointer` etc. Há uma boa seção sobre isso na [resposta de Maniero sobre quando utilizar ou não um ponteiro para criar um objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50165/quando-devo-escolher-entre-utilizar-ou-n%C3%A3o-um-ponteiro-ao-criar-um-objeto)), pois eles gerenciam a própria memória de maneira automática.

P.S.: Para saber mais sobre as diferenças entre *Heap* e *Stack*, aconselho [essa resposta sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3797/o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-onde-est%C3%A3o-a-stack-e-heap).

Comment: Sua primeira afirmação *....O new nos permite alocar memória dinamicamente na chamada memória Heap, ao invés de alocá-lo na memória Stack. ...* nem sempre é verdadeira, em c++ é possível que o operador `new` aloque memória no stack veja esse exemplo https://ideone.com/QsS7CY . Nesse caso está sendo usado uma das muitas [sobrecargas do operador `new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) em conjunto da função [`alloca()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html) que aloca memória no stack. **Não recomendável pois o uso imprudente causa o Stack Overflow.**

Comment: Muito obrigado pela observação Augusto. Você tem razão. Nessa frase eu me referia ao uso comum do new sem especificar explicitamente que queríamos alocar na stack (com o uso do `alloca()`, como você falou). Irei adicionar isso à repsosta para corrigí-la e evitar confusões. Valeu!

Comment: Obrigado por adicionar a informação a resposta.

Comment: Por nada. Eu que agradeço pela ajuda ;)

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente, `new` e `delete` são uma alternativa segura ao uso direto de `malloc()` e `free()`.

`new` e `delete` são invólucros (*wrappers*) de C++ para `malloc()` e `free()`, ou seja, por baixo dos panos eles utilizam estas funções e adicionam alguns tratamentos a elas.
Dentre os tratamentos estão a garantia de uma operação segura, evitando o acesso a localidades de memória inválidas, além de assegurarem que o retorno não será *null* (caso `malloc()` retorne *null*, `new` lançará uma *exception*).

Answer (score -1):

Com o operador `new` podemos inicializar o valor ou alocar memória em runtime.

```
int *a = new int(25);
int *b = new int[10];
```

A variável fica em memória até fazer `delete`.

```
delete a;
delete[] b;
```

A alocação dinâmica permite-nos definir arrays de tamanho variável.

```
void foo(int size) {
    int* c = new int[size];
    ...
    delete [] c;
}
```

Se não usarmos este método a memória é alocada na compilação e fica fora de escopo se saírmos da função. Devemos usar apenas quando necessário para evitar memory leaks.