# Qual é a principal diferença entre um Tuple e um List?

Tags: python, lista, tupla

Quais são as diferenças entre um `Tuple` e um `List` no `Python`?

Exemplo:

```
>a = [1, 2, 3] 
# [1, 2, 3]
>b = (1, 2, 3)
# (1, 2, 3)
```

O `Tuple`, grotescamente falando, é uma constante que aceita um `List`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do ponto de vista técnico em Python uma tupla é [imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) e uma lista é mutável.

Do ponto de vista conceitual você deveria usar tuplas para montar estruturas de dados heterogêneos enquanto a lista deveria ser usada para dados homogêneos, ou seja, todos seus elementos deveriam ser do mesmo tipo.

Como Python é uma linguagem dinâmica isso não pode ser garantido, cabe ao programador decidir fazer isto.

Por ser usado para dados heterogêneos (diversidade de tipos entre os membros) a tupla normalmente possui poucos elementos mas nada impede que tenha muitos. Tuplas frequentemente são usadas para simular classes que não precisam ser definidas, cujo uso é mais efêmero e não depende de contratos mais específicos. Só tome o cuidado de usar uma tupla como se fosse uma lista, funciona, mas não costuma ser adequado em quase todas situações.

Mas mesmo que você tenha uma lista de elementos que normalmente será pequena, se ela se parece mais como uma lista e não um conjunto limitado e fixo de dados, a lista deve ser usada.

Se os dados são do mesmo tipo, é quase certo que você tem uma lista, claro que existem exceções. Por exemplo um `Point` poderia ser uma tupla cujos elementos são dois inteiros. É óbvio que isto não é uma lista de dados, mas um conjunto limitado de dados que por acaso são do mesmo tipo.

A tupla funciona como um registro de dados, como uma linha de um banco de dados, um conjunto de colunas. A lista funciona como a tabela, são as linhas como um todo.

Eu imagino, mas nunca testei, que tuplas são ligeiramente mais rápidas, mas elas não devem ser usadas por causa disto, use de acordo com a semântica adequada.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Boa explanação! A questão da diferença velocidade entre tuplas e listas sempre me intrigou também!

Comment: Você poderia enxergar a tupla como um conjunto de dados que não faz sentido de forma desirmanada. Por exemplo, um vetor ou uma coordenada, onde os números perdem imediatamente o sentido se manipulados em separado.

Comment: A velocidade de acesso aos dados é a mesma. A diferença na criação, se houver, é minima, e um detalhe não importante de implementação.

Comment: Outro ponto interessante é que precisamos de menos bits para armazenar as tuplas. Ao usar uma tupla ao invés de uma lista estamos economizando espaço. Se vc for usar uma variável que precisará ser modificada ao longo do código é melhor usar listas.

Comment: Faltou exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a resposta do usuário **Maniero**, as `tuplas` são **imutáveis**, portanto não é possível **modificar** o conteúdo sem sobrescrever a variável que a representa, enquanto que a lista possui vários métodos que alteram a sua estrutura.

Quando é necessário representar uma estrutura que não deve ser modificada, deve-se usar uma `tupla` ao invés da `lista`, garantindo a integridade dos dados e assegurando que até o programador não consiga modificar sua estrutura.

Por exemplo:

```
t = (1, 2, 3)
t = t + (4, 5)  # incremento de 2 elementos na tupla t, sobrescrita na variável t
l = [1, 2, 3]
l.extend([4,5])  # incremento de 2 elementos na lista l
```

Comment: Deixei meu -1 pelo fato da resposta não ser inteiramente verdade. É fato que a tupla é um tipo imutável, como dito também na outra resposta, porém não há relação alguma ao fato de representar estruturas que não devem ser modificadas. Inclusive o fato de uma tupla ser imutável não significa que seus elementos também são. Por exemplo, uma tupla de listas pode sofrer alterações livremente, pois a lista é mutável. Veja um [exemplo](https://ideone.com/trSynd).

Comment: Sim, acabei me expressando mal. Estava falando de estrutura somente da tupla e não de seu conteúdo.

Comment: Olá! Eu, ainda, gostaria de entender melhor por que tuplas são mais usadas para tipos de dados heterogêneos e as listas para dados homogêneos. Isso não é obrigatório, mas por que isso é mais adequado?

Comment: Geralmente as tuplas são usadas para representar um conjunto de dados em que cada posição tem um valor bem definido, como na resposta de @maniero com o exemplo do Point, em que cada elemento da tupla é um número, sendo a primeira posição para x e a segunda para y. Nesse exemplo, a tupla é heterogênea, mas pode-se usar elementos homogêneos também. Tuplas é um representação de um conjunto de dados com uma quantidade definida, enquanto que na lista pode-se incrementar elementos.

Answer (score 2):

Apenas complementando, uma outra característica das tuplas e listas é a adição de elementos unitários em cada uma. Por exemplo para adicionar o elemento '4' em cada um:

```
st = (1,2,3)  # Declaração de tupla
st = [1,2,3]  # Declaração de lista

st += [4]
sl += (4,)   #Sem a vírgula ele retorna um erro que não se pode concatenar um inteiro a uma tupla
sl += (4,5,6) # Para adições desse modo não há problema
```