# Existe diferença performática entre Tuple e List?

Tags: python, desempenho, lista, tuple

Em Python, sei que existe a diferença entre uma `Tuple` e uma `List`. A `Tuple` é imutável, e a `List`, mutável.

Inclusive já tem essa pergunta aqui: [Qual é a principal diferença entre um Tuple e um List?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52799/qual-%C3%A9-a-principal-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-um-tuple-e-um-list)

Porém, eu gostaria de saber se, em termos de performance, uma pode ser melhor que a outra.

O `Tuple`, por ser imutável, pode gerar mais desempenho/performance do que se fosse usar um `List`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tuplas são mais simples porque são imutáveis e por outros motivos.

No [SO tem uma resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68817/221800) do [Mark Harrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116/mark-harrison) que já mostra como o *bytecode* do Python é montado em cada caso e dá para ver que Tupla é mais eficiente.

> ```
> >>> def a():
> ...     x=[1,2,3,4,5]
> ...     y=x[2]
> ...
> >>> def b():
> ...     x=(1,2,3,4,5)
> ...     y=x[2]
> ...
> >>> import dis
> >>> dis.dis(a)
>   2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
>               3 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
>               6 LOAD_CONST               3 (3)
>               9 LOAD_CONST               4 (4)
>              12 LOAD_CONST               5 (5)
>              15 BUILD_LIST               5
>              18 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
>
>   3          21 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
>              24 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
>              27 BINARY_SUBSCR
>              28 STORE_FAST               1 (y)
>              31 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
>              34 RETURN_VALUE
> >>> dis.dis(b)
>   2           0 LOAD_CONST               6 ((1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
>               3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
>
>   3           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
>               9 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
>              12 BINARY_SUBSCR
>              13 STORE_FAST               1 (y)
>              16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
>              19 RETURN_VALUE
> ```

A [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3340881/221800) do [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli), que é um especialista em Python, em outra pergunta diz que tuplas são construídas mais rapidamente.

> ```
> $ python3.1 -mtimeit -s'x,y,z=1,2,3' '[x,y,z]'
> 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.379 usec per loop
> $ python3.1 -mtimeit '[1,2,3]'
> 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.413 usec per loop
>
> $ python3.1 -mtimeit -s'x,y,z=1,2,3' '(x,y,z)'
> 10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.174 usec per loop
> $ python3.1 -mtimeit '(1,2,3)'
> 10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0602 usec per loop
>
> $ python2.6 -mtimeit -s'x,y,z=1,2,3' '[x,y,z]'
> 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.352 usec per loop
> $ python2.6 -mtimeit '[1,2,3]'
> 1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.358 usec per loop
>
> $ python2.6 -mtimeit -s'x,y,z=1,2,3' '(x,y,z)'
> 10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.157 usec per loop
> $ python2.6 -mtimeit '(1,2,3)'
> 10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0527 usec per loop
> ```

O fato delas serem imutáveis dá o direito dos códigos que a acessam não precisar fazer certas verificações, há algumas garantias a mais. Isso economiza tempo.

Há uma outra [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5626776/221800) do [Glenn Maynard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/136829/glenn-maynard) que mostra como o Python manipula internamente a lista:

```
case BINARY_SUBSCR:
    w = POP();
    v = TOP();
    if (PyList_CheckExact(v) && PyInt_CheckExact(w)) {
        /* INLINE: list[int] */
        Py_ssize_t i = PyInt_AsSsize_t(w);
        if (i < 0)
            i += PyList_GET_SIZE(v);
        if (i >= 0 && i < PyList_GET_SIZE(v)) {
            x = PyList_GET_ITEM(v, i);
            Py_INCREF(x);
        }
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Reflection/ListInternal.c).

Isso faz com que o acesso, que é o que mais importa, seja praticamente a mesma coisa.

Tuplas também ocupam menos espaço, o que pode ajudar no cache de dados.

Pode haver outras implicações. Cada situação pode ter um efeito diferente. Mas a pergunta não é clara quanto a qual situação está falando.

A conclusão é a mesma de sempre. Use o que for mais adequado para cada situação e não se preocupe com a performance. Nesse caso, como em muitos, a diferença é mínima e se quiser performance mesmo, faça em C, C++ ou outra linguagem onde a performance pode ser a máxima.

Answer (score 0):

> Tuplas são armazenadas em um único bloco de memória. Tuplas são
>   imutáveis, então não requerem espaço adicional para armazenar novos
>   objetos.
>
> Listas são alocadas em dois blocos, um fixo com todos as informações de
>   objetos python e um bloco de espaço variável para os dados.
>
> Essa é a razão pelo qual tuplas são mais performáticas.
>
> Também explica o porquê da pequena diferença na velocidade de
>   indexação que nas listas, porque nas tuplas para indexação seguem menos
>   ponteiros.

referência: [learnbatta](https://learnbatta.com/blog/why-tuple-is-faster-than-list-in-python-22/)