# Para que serve e como funciona então uma tupla no python?

Tags: python

Qual é mesmo o objectivo final da utilização de uma tupla?
Eu já sei a diferença entre uma tupla e uma lista. Quero perceber como funciona a tupla e qual o seu verdadeiro objectivo a nivel de utilização.

Comment: É duplicata? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52799/101

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165773/101

Comment: @bigown eu referi precisamente que sei a diferença entre elas, e até consultei essas perguntas antes... obrigado na mesma.

Comment: Lá na resposta aceita da outra pergunta tem: "Do ponto de vista conceitual você deveria usar tuplas para montar estruturas de dados heterogêneos [...]". Pronto.