# Diferenças entre list, tuple e set

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, tupla, set

Sei que em Python existem três estruturas que aparentemente se assemelham, mas que no fundo possuem diferenças. São elas: `list`, `tuple` e `set`.

**List**

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

**Tuple**

```
a = (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

**Set**

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Fiz diversas pesquisas aqui no SOpt e encontrei uma pergunta que explica perfeitamente a diferença entre `list` e `tuple`, (aqui: [Qual é a principal diferença entre um Tuple e um List?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52799/qual-%C3%A9-a-principal-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-um-tuple-e-um-list)) entretanto essa pergunta não fez a comparação dessas duas estruturas com o `set`, e por isso ela não serviu para esclarecer minha dúvida.

Pergunto: quais a diferenças entre essas três estruturas? Diferenças no conceito e na aplicação?

Comment: [Qual é a principal diferença entre um Tuple e um List?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52799/5878) | [Quando usar listas e quando usar tuplas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192727/5878) | [Existe diferença performática entre Tuple e List?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/165773/5878) | [Para que serve o set no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77699/5878)

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual é a principal diferença entre um Tuple e um List?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52799/qual-%c3%a9-a-principal-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-um-tuple-e-um-list)

Comment: @Ivan a pergunta que você citou como possível duplicata não aborda a questão do set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

São três estruturas de dados diferentes - tanto no nível do uso quanto na implementação - e cada uma delas pode servir melhor para um objetivo. (Nota - no texto abaixo acabo usando de forma alternada os nomes em inglês e Python com as traduções "lista", "tupla" e "conjunto")

A **list** e a **tuple** são mais parecidas entre si - ambas são Sequências (Sequences) - o que significa que elas contém dados de forma ordenada. A maior diferença e que uma lista é uma sequência mutável: isso é, depois de criada a lista, você pode continuar incluindo elementos na mesma, alterando outros elementos e ate excluindo elementos. A tupla é uma sequência *imutável*: isso é, depois de criada, ela não pode mais ser alterada.

**tuple**: Em termos de uso, a imutabilidade da tupla faz com que ela possa ser usada como chave de um dicionário, por exemplo - já, listas, não podem ser chaves de dicionário.

Além disso, quase que mais por tradição e por praticidade, há uma tendência que cada elemento de uma tupla represente um dado específico - quase como se fosse uma "estrutura", mas que não precisa ser declarada. Tanto é que, em algum ponto inventaram as "namedtuple" - objetos que funcionam exatamente como tuplas, mas que tem de fato campos, e cada elemento pode ser acessado além de por índice, com o operador `[ ]`, também por nome, usando o `.`. Tuplas são geradas automaticamente pelo Python em algumas situações - em particular, se não houver ambiguidade, os parenteses em volta da tupla são opcionais e é só escrever os elementos separados por vírgula.

**list**: Em contraste, listas em geral são usadas para dados mais homogêneos, e "anônimos" - dificilmente alguém cria uma lista com 3 elementos em que o primeiro é um índice numérico, o segundo uma string, e o terceiro a string normalizada - é mais comum que, por exemplo, cada elemento da lista seja uma palavra de um texto, ou uma linha de um arquivo. Note que nada obriga que seja assim - esses usos distintos acabam surgindo naturalmente conforme se ganha experiência com a linguagem.

Internamente, tuplas são um pouco mais eficientes que listas - mas do ponto de vista do programador em Python isso não faz muita diferença.

**set**: Já conjuntos, ou "sets", são bem diferentes: assim como a tupla e a lista eles contém dados (os três são "containers") - mas os dados não tem uma ordem: não importa em que ordem você coloca os dados em um conjunto, você só pode pegar de volta ou um dado aleatório, ou percorrer todos os elementos (com um  `for`), mas numa ordem desconhecida.
 Mais ainda, cada elemento só pode estar presente num conjunto uma única vez. Se você adiciona um elemento repetido, essa cópia é simplesmente ignorada.  Nesse sentido são como os conjuntos definidos em matemática (que aprendemos desde o pré-primário). Se eu tenho, em matemática, o conjunto de números impares de 1 até 9, e tentar adicionar o número "3" nesse conjunto, ele não muda: o 3 já estava dentro dele antes.

Outra diferença dos sets em Python para as tuplas e listas é que todos os objetos em um conjunto tem que ser imutáveis - (ou pelo menos tem que ter um hash bem definido). Ou seja: listas não podem ser inseridas em conjuntos, mas tuplas podem.

Em particular, por conta de não haver ordem nos elementos de um conjunto, a única coisa que você pode saber é se um elemento pertence a um conjunto - com o operador `in`:  `0 in {0, 2, 3, 4}` vai retornar `True`, por exemplo.  E essa operação para "verificar se um elemento está num conjunto" pode ser muito mais rápida para um conjutno do que para uma lista. Até *milhares* de vezes mais rápida - por que o algoritmo para saber se um elemento está em um conjunto leva um tempo constante - independente do tamanho do conjunto. Em sequências, a verificação de pertencimento de um elemento é feita de forma linear.  Na prática para sets ou lists de até 20 elementos a diferença é negligível, mas se você tem que filtrar quais de 100.000 elementos estão numa massa de dados de 100.000.000 de elementos, pode ser a diferença entre um programa que leva horas pra rodar, e um que termina em dois segundos.

Mas você não existem os métodos `.index` ou `.find` (que existem para listas e tuplas) para saber a posição de um elemento: os elementos em um set não tem posição.

Um uso muito comum de sets é justamente remover duplicatas de uma sequência. Vamos supor que você tem uma lista de palavras que extaiu de um texto - algumas repetidas dezenas de vezes, e quer ter apenas uma palavra de cada - basta fazer: `palavras = set(lista_de_todas_as_palavras)` - todas as duplicadas "colapsam" automaticamente, e você passa a ter um conjunto com uma palavra de cada (lembrando: fora de ordem)

Além disso, os sets implementam as operações mais comuns com conjutnos que aprendemos em matemática: intersecção, união, diferença entre outras - você tanto pode usar os métodos com os nomes apropriados (faça `dir(set())` no prompt interativo para ver os métodos disponíveis), quanto algumas dessas operações funcionam direto com os operadores matemáticos e lógicos do Python:

```
In [189]: a = {1, 2, 3}

In [190]: b = {3, 4, 5}

# diferença
In [191]: a - b 
Out[191]: {1, 2}

# união
In [193]: a | b
Out[193]: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

# intersecção: 
In [194]: a.intersection(b)
Out[194]: {3}
```

É possível se passar anos programando em Python sem nunca *precisar* usar conjuntos. Mas quando a oportunidade aparece, só deles existirem, podem economizar várias horas e dezenas de linhas de código de uma só vez.

**frozenset**: Um outro tipo bem menos conhecido - entre outras coisas por que não tem uma sintaxe separada na linguagem, ao contrário de sets, lists e tuples, são os "frozenset" - o frozenset praticamente está para os sets como as listas estão para as tuplas: uma vez criado, ele não pode ser alterado: não se pode adicionar novos elementos nem remover nada do que está lá. Assim sendo, os frozenset podem ser usados como chaves de dicionário e elementos de sets (e claro, de frozensets também) - o que os sets normais não podem.

Você cria um frozenset chamando-o como se fosse uma função, e passando como único parâmetro um objeto iterável (os 4 tipos que tratamos aqui são iteráveis): `meus_dados = frozenset({1, 2, 3, 4})`

Comment: Você ilustrou bem a diferença entre cada estrutura de dados, e ainda abordou uma estrutura que até então não era conhecida por mim no Python. Ótima resposta +1