# Como modificar um elemento dentro de uma lista em Python?

Tags: python, lista

Eu tenho a seguinte lista:

```
pessoa=("Filipe", 40, True)
```

Escrevo o comando print para cada elemento:

```
print(pessoa[0])
print(pessoa[1])
print(pessoa[2])
```

as respostas sao:

```
Filipe
40
True
```

Quando tento modificar o primeiro elemento:

```
pessoa[0]="Marconi"
```

```
recebo a resposta de erro abaixo:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Licença/Scripts/A5825_Listas.py", line 16, in <module>
   pessoa[0]="Marconi"
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Como faco para modificar um elemento de uma lista em Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade você esta tentando modificar uma tupla, tuplas são como listas, só que imutáveis ou seja, uma vez criada não pode ser modificada.

Ao tentar modificar um elemento da tupla:

```
numeros = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
print(numeros[2]) # 3
# Ao tentar modificar
numeros[2] = 99 # TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Não podemos alterar os elementos da tupla, mas podemos colocar lista dentro dela. No exemplo abaixo será adicionada na tupla `numeros` uma tupla que contém apenas um elemento.

```
numeros = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
print(numeros)
numeros = (99)
print(numeros)
```

> Veja funcionando em [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ContentImaginativeStegosaurus)

Caso seu caso, criamos uma nova tupla: `('Marconi',)` e adicionamos nela os elementos da tupla anterior `+ pessoa[1:]`, mas começando da posição 1 até a última posição, que no caso é dois. Note que não foi informado a posição final, logo caso tenha mais elementos na tupla, os mesmos também serão adicionados na nova tupla.

```
pessoa=("Filipe", 40, True)
pessoa = ('Marconi', ) + pessoa[1:]
print(pessoa)
```

> Veja funcionando em [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/WearyMustyHermitcrab)

#### Referências

- [Mutabilidade e tuplas](http://www3.ifrn.edu.br/%7Ejurandy/fdp/doc/aprenda-python/capitulo_09.html#id2)
- [Qual é a principal diferença entre um Tuple e um List?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52799)
- [O que “imutável” realmente significa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15510)

Comment: O AP claramente perguntou "lista" - então ele está confundindo listas e tuplas - acredito que uma resposta legal deveria abordar isso e explicar a diferença.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, você está tentando alterar um tupla, uma tupla é um objeto imutável quer dizer que uma vez criada a tupla não podemos modificar seus valores, por outro lado temos a lista:

```
pessoa=["Felipe",40,True] <- Criando uma lista
pessoa[0]="Marcos" <- Alterando o primeiro valor da lista
print(pessoal) <- Mostrando lista no terminal
```

Saída:
`['Marcos',40,True]`

As vezes confundimos  listas com tuplas por isso vamos colocar da seguinte forma **[]** <- **LISTA**, **()** <- **TUPLA**