# Como apagar uma palavra de uma só vez?

Tags: java, android

Estou utilizando este método para apagar o último caractere digitado numa TextView:

```
texto = txtTexto.getText().toString();
int length = texto.length();  
txtTexto.setText(texto.substring(0, length - 1));
```

Quando aparecer uma palavra tipo ***seno*** eu quero que apagar ela inteira.

Comment: Mas você quer apagá-la seja onde for que ela aparece, ou só se ela aparecer no final da string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode-se utilizar o método [`String#replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) para eliminá-la.

Porém se você fizer:

```
texto = txtTexto.getText().toString();
texto.replace("seno", "");
```

O código acima não vai funcionar do modo esperado, isso não vai modificar o objeto chamador pois *strings* (ou melhor, *variáveis*) em Java são [imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/6454), então o que você precisa fazer é atribuir o resultado a uma nova *string* ou para a mesma variável assim:

```
texto = txtTexto.getText().toString();
texto = texto.replace("seno", "");
```

Outras funções semelhantes que podem a vir ser úteis a você:

- [`String#replaceFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)): Substitui a primeira ocorrência de uma palavra num texto.
- [`String#replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)): Faz a mesma coisa que a função [`String#replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)), mas essa aceita o uso de expressões regulares.

Comment: `String#replaceFirst()´ ocorre no primeiro e para substituir a ultima  ocorrência de uma palavra num texto.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o `replace`:

```
texto.replace("seno","")
```