# Remover X primeiros elementos de uma string

Tags: c#, string

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
copia = num.Text;
copia = copia.Substring(cobrar.Length + 1, copia.Length);
num.Text = copia;
```

Onde `copia` recebe uma string de um textbox e `cobrar` é uma string pré definida, quero que ele "apague" a string `cobrar` da minha string `copia`.

**Exemplo:**

```
cobrar = "teste";
copia = "numero";
num.Text = cobrar + copia; //não é só isso, por isso quero remover com o Substring
resultado seria = "numero";
```

Quando rodo o programa ele fecha nessa hora, a IDE fala para mim olhar meu startIndex que seria cobrar.Length .. Qual o erro que estou comentendo?

Comment: Cara, melhora um pouquinho teu exemplo que eu te ajudo. Ainda tá meio confuso.

Comment: Já deu certo mano, esse é um pouquinho mais difícil de explicar que o outro, mas seria remover parte de uma string. Minha string principal é a união de duas ou três string, daí queria remover uma string dessa string principal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [`string.Remove(int start, int count)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/d8d7z2kk(v=vs.110).aspx) que retorna uma string removendo conteudo. Conteúdo da documentação MSDN:

> Retorna uma nova cadeia de caracteres em que um número especificado de
>   caracteres na instância atual, começando na posição especificada foram
>   excluído.

Por exemplo,

```
string nome = "Leonardo VIlarinho";

// começa do primeirao caracter, e remove os 5 primeiros.
nome = nome.Remove(0, 5); // retorna "rdo VIlarinho"
```

Ou ainda você pode usar o método `string.Substring(int start)` ou `string.Substring(int start, int count)`, que contém funcionamento semelhante ao `Remove()`. Por exemplo,

```
string nome = "Leonardo VIlarinho";

// retorma uma substring começando em 5 até o fim
nome = nome.Substring(5); // retorna "rdo VIlarinho"
```

ou

```
string nome = "Leonardo VIlarinho";

// retorma uma substring começando em 5 até o 3 caracteres
nome = nome.Substring(5, 3); // retorna "rdo"
```

Existe ainda a imutabilidade da `string` em .Net, vale a pena olhar este post: [O que "imutável" realmente significa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15510/o-que-imut%C3%A1vel-realmente-significa)

Comment: Testei funcionou, mas tinha feito de outro jeito funcional também usando um monte de condição e dois bool, daí deu preguiça de apagar e deixei como estava, mas da próxima já sei como fazer! kk

Comment: Sim, existem várias abordagens, mas recomendo que você utilize os métodos que já existem nos tipos. Há também o `substring` que pode te ajudar a cortar sua string.