# Como passar string por referência?

Tags: c#, .net, string, passagem-por-referência

Passei uma *string* como parâmetro. Pelo que sei ela é passada por referência, então se eu alterar alguma coisa nela dentro do método, quando sair dele o valor continuará alterado.

Fiz o teste abaixo e não aconteceu o que eu esperava. Estou enganado no que estou pensando? Certamente não é *bug* da linguagem.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string text = "text";
        ChangeText(text);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
    static void ChangeText(string text) { 
        text = "new text";
    }
}
```

Fiz um [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IXt1zH).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Na verdade o que é passado por referência é objeto, não a própria referência. A referência é passada por valor, portanto por cópia, então se mudar a referência não vai refletir no argumento passado. Se mudasse o objeto aí sim refletiria no argumento passado, mas como `string` é imutável isto não é possível, só pode mudar o objeto todo, mas se fosse outro objeto mutável, sim, o que você alterasse internamente, sem mudar a identidade do objeto, seria visto por quem chamou. Nesse exemplo mudou o objeto todo.

Se deseja mesmo permitir que a referência seja trocada, ou seja, que outro objeto seja vinculado àquele parâmetro e reflita no argumento, tem que passar a própria referência por referência. Pode parecer estranho, mas faz todo sentido se entender que a referência é um valor simples já que é apenas um ponteiro e não o objeto todo.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var text = "text";
        ChangeText(text);
        WriteLine(text);
        ChangeText(ref text);
        WriteLine(text);
    }
    static void ChangeText(string text) => text = "new text";
    static void ChangeText(ref string text) => text = "new text";
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qmuAeW). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bJS9AE). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ReferenceTypeByRef.cs).

Note que a [assinatura dos métodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) é diferente, então nem precisei mudar o nome.

Complemento: [O que "imutável" realmente significa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15510/o-que-imut%c3%a1vel-realmente-significa/15512#15512)

Answer (score 10):

No `C#` para passar uma variável por referência, utilize a keyword `ref`. Basta alterar seu método para:

```
static void ChangeText(ref string text) { 
        text = "new text";
}
```

e sua chamada para:

```
ChangeText(ref text);
```

Fiz essas alterações no mesmo Fiddle, caso queira ver:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/FvijX6

Answer (score 6):

Em C#, `string` é, sim, um tipo por referência. `Strings` no C# são imutáveis, ou seja, você nunca realmente altera ao valor de uma `string` e sim obtém uma cópia alterada que então é atribuída à uma variável. Exemplo:

```
string s = "foo";
s = "bar";
```

O que o código acima faz é criar uma cópia da string "foo", atribuir para ela o valor "bar" e passar essa nova `string` para a variável `s`.

Por causa desse comportamento, é recomendável utilizar o `StringBuilder` do C# para manipulação de strings, assim evita-se a criação de diversas cópias em memória.

[Mais detalhes aqui.](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx)

Uma maneira simples de resolver o problema colocado, seria alterar o tipo de retorno da função `ChangeText` para string e reatribuir o valor da variável `text` com o retorno da função:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string text = "text";
    text = ChangeText(text);
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
static string ChangeText(string text) { 
    text = "new text";
    return text;
}
```

[Exemplo funcional no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z3qS1i)

Uma outra alternativa para resolver passando por referência, seria utilizando a classe StringBuilder da biblioteca padrão do C#:

```
public static void Main()
{
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder("text");
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    ChangeText(text);
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
static void ChangeText(StringBuilder text) { 
    text.Replace(text.ToString(), "new text");
}
```

[Exemplo funcional no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/glhHhl)

Answer (score -1):

Eu não te vou explicar mas vou dar-te o que precisas

```
internal Object funcao(object obj)
{
     return new Object(); // Estas a criar algo dentro da função e retornas o teu objecto
}

internal void funcao(ref object obj)
{
     obj = new Object(); // Das o teu objecto, e retornas o objecto modificado
}

internal void funcao(out Object obj)
{
     Object obj = new Object(); // Aqui tens de o declarar sempre, e o que modificares aqui sai para fora
}

internal void funcao(Object obj)
{
     obj = new Object(); // O que modificares aqui dentro não sai para fora
}
```

Comment: Seria melhor dar uma explicação  melhor, pois o usuário busca uma explicação para o comportamento apresentado, por favor complemente sua questão.