# Pegar valor da variável em outro método

Tags: c#, .net, variáveis, asp.net-core, método

Dentro de um mesmo arquivo eu tenho 2 métodos:

```
public IActionResult OnGet(){
    CarregarMenu();

    //Gostaria de pegar aqui o valor da variável lcMenuPrincipal

    Return Page();
}
```

E a outra:

```
public static void CarregarMenu(){
    string lcMenuPrincipal = "";

    lcMenuPrincipal = "Bom Dia Família";
}
```

Como eu faço para pegar, no `OnGet()`, o valor da variável que está no segundo método `CarregarMenu()`?

Answer (score 3):

Você quer fazer um retorno simples, mas neste caso nem precisa de uma variável:

```
public IActionResult OnGet() {
    var variavelAqui = CarregarMenu();
    Return Page();
}

public static void CarregarMenu() => string lcMenuPrincipal = "";
```

Se realmente tiver outras coisas e quiser deixar a variável, mas não faz sentido se não tiver outras coisas nesse método (na forma apresentada não faça desta forma):

```
public IActionResult OnGet() {
    var variavelAqui = CarregarMenu();
    Return Page();
}

public static void CarregarMenu() {
    string lcMenuPrincipal = "Bom Dia Família";
    return lcMenuPrincipal;
}
```

Não faz o menor sentido passar uma variável por referência como argumento. Se precisa passar um valor de um lugar para o outro, oque a pergunta não mostra, então pode fazer isto:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main() {}
    public static void OnGet() {
        string lcMenuPrincipal = "";
        lcMenuPrincipal  = CarregarMenu(lcMenuPrincipal);
        return;
    }

    public static string CarregarMenu(string lcMenuPrincipal) {
        WriteLine(lcMenuPrincipal); //estou fazendo alguma coisa com esse valor, caso contrário não sentido receber esse parâmetro
        return "Bom Dia Família";
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/01soqA). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2YzvXy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/ChangeVariableValue.cs).

Comment: *"Não faz o menor sentido passar uma variável por referência como argumento"* pode até ser Maniero, mas como ele disse que está estudando .Net, didaticamente seria interessante conhecer todas as opções, afinal referência faz parte da linguagem :)

Comment: Opções sim, mas você não deu como opção, depois mudou para dizer que é uma opção. Na verdade a pergunta não faz muito sentido, ela não está clara o que ele quer, ou falta informações do que realmente quer ou não precisa de nada disso, só respondi porque tinha uma resposta falando para complicar algo simples, o mais certo era fechar a pergunta por não ter um problema real claro.

Answer (score 2):

Precisa que a visibilidade da variável seja ampla para os dois métodos. Nesse caso, precisa declarar no escopo da classe:

```
class NomeDaSuaClasse
{
    // aqui a variável será visível para todos os métodos da classe
    string lcMenuPrincipal = "";

    public IActionResult OnGet(){
        // pode acessar a variável aqui e também no método CarregarMenu
    }
}
```

Uma outra alternativa seria declarar a variável do escopo do método `onGet`, e receber por retorno do método `CarregarMenu`. Nesse caso ele não poderia ser void, seria string.

```
    public IActionResult OnGet(){
        string lcMenuPrincipal = CarregarMenu();
    }

    public static string CarregarMenu(){

        return "Bom Dia Família";
    }
```

Ainda pode passar a variável por referência para o método, uma outra solução:

```
public IActionResult OnGet(){
    string lcMenuPrincipal = "";
    CarregarMenu(ref lcMenuPrincipal);
}

public static void CarregarMenu(ref string lcMenuPrincipal){

    lcMenuPrincipal = "Bom Dia Família";
}
```

Se quiser entender melhor como funciona um parâmetro por referência, veja essa outra pergunta: [Como passar string por referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194151/como-passar-string-por-refer%C3%AAncia)

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta, poderia deixar um exemplo da segunda maneira?

Comment: sim, editei a pergunta