# Por que usar modificadores de parâmetros?

Tags: c#, terminologia, característica-linguagem

Enquanto escrevemos funções e sub-rotinas, utilizamos parâmetros para se interagir com o algoritmo da função. Estes parâmetros podem ter várias finalidades, como passar um valor, uma referência, ou dele sair um valor ou referência.

No C# pelo menos, temos o [`in`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/in-parameter-modifier), o [`ref`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref) e o [`out`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier). O primeiro, faz com que somente o valor seja passado ao argumento, o segundo, faz com que o valor e a referência seja passada, e altera seu valor e referência, já o terceiro, faz com que nada entre, somente a referência (com valor) saia.

Mas nenhum é obrigatório, todos são opcionais.

### Por que e quando usá-los?

Imagine o cenário mais simples para isso: um procedimento que soma de dois inteiros. Podemos fazer com retorno, referência ou atribuição. Qual usar?

````
// situação 1 - retorno na função sem modificadores
public static int Soma(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
} // uso: z = Soma(x, y);

// situação 2 - retorno na função com modificadores de entrada
public static int Soma(in int a, in int b) {
    return a + b;
} // uso: z = Soma(x, y);

// situação 3 - sem retorno, com modificador de entrada e saída
public static void Soma(in int a, in int b, out int c) {
    c = a + b;
} // uso: Soma(x, y, out var z);

// situação 4 - sem retorno, com modificador de entrada e referência
public static void Soma(in int a, in int b, ref int c) {
    c = a + b;
} // uso: int z = 0; Soma(x, y, ref z);
```

Outro exemplo, é o retorno de mais de uma variável por uma rotina:

```C#
// usando tuplas
public static (float val, float abs, float resto) Dividir (float a, float b) {
    (float val, float abs, float resto) saida;
    saida.val = a / b;
    saida.abs = Math.Abs(a / b);
    saida.resto = a % b;
    return saida;
}

// usando modificadores de parâmetros
public static void Dividir(in float a, in float b, out float val, out float abs, out float resto) {
    val = a / b;
    abs = Math.Abs(a / b);
    resto = a % b;
}
````

Como podemos ver acima, há várias maneiras de fazer a mesma coisa, mas não consigo entender qual e quando usar corretamente.

Por fim,

- Quando usar `in`, `out` e `ref`?
- Por que devemos usá-los?
- Qual se enquadra melhor em cada situação, como descrito acima?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O funcionamento deles já foi descrito em [O que são os parâmetros out e ref](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82630/101) (o exemplo do `ref` é artificial e não muito bom, é o mesmo da pergunta aqui) e [Para que serve esse 'in' em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/309784/101) e até um pouco em [O que são ponteiros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/266756/101), por isso não vou dar muitos detalhes.

> O primeiro, faz com que somente o valor seja passado ao argumento

Isto está incorreto, o `in` apenas promete que receberá um objeto por referência e que não o modificará.

Os exemplos com `in` não deveriam usar nada disto, não há ganhos de cópia porque o tamanho do ponteiro é até maior que o dado inteiro. Se não tem um objeto grande não use o `in`.

O terceiro exemplo não é mais necessário como demonstrado pela própria pergunta e na verdade nem tupla deveria ser usada (o exemplo é bem ruim, até o uso de tupla está errado ali).

O último exemplo é um caso clássico de método que faz coisas demais e deveria ser destrinchado em vários.

O uso dos três sempre ocorre com objetos que não queremos copiar diretamente por alguma razão.

A principal razão é que este objeto é grande demais para ser copiado (em geral mais de 16 bytes) o que custaria caro pra isso existe principalmente o `in` já que a ideia é ter um objeto no *stack* (uma `struct` e mais ainda uma `ref struct` que tem mais chance de ser um objeto grande) e quer passá-la para o método chamado sem copiar o objeto que é grande. C# recentemente tem dado preferência por alocar objeto no *stack* para reduzir a pressão no *garbage collector* que torna o código mais lento e com pausas e por isso tem abusado um pouco de objetos grandes no *stack* o que não acontecia no passado. Não se preocupe com o `in` se não está adotando o padrão preferencial de alocação no *stack*, ele é para programação mais avançada que exige dominar vários conhecimentos para fazer certo (não que qualquer pessoa não possa usar, mas se não entender todos os compromissos fará uso errado, por isso que eu falo que não pode escolher oque aprender, ou aprende tudo ou fica sempre na superfície).

O `ref` pode ser usado para isto mas ele não dá garantias sobre sua modificação o que muitas vezes a garantia é desejada, e com essa garantia o compilador pode fazer algumas otimizações. Em parte pode pensar nele como um `in` que permite modificar seu valor normalmente. Em parte ele serve para outra que vou citar abaixo.

Mas o `ref` também pode ser usado para efetivamente permitir uma mudança que normalmente não seria permitida. Por exemplo, se passar uma *string* como argumento para um método, ela é uma referência, e como *string* é imutável se quiser mudar algo só criando outra *string*, mas se criar outra como vai dizer para quem chamou que agora ela deve ter outro objeto? Normalmente são coisas independentes, e uma das formas é retornar essa nova *string* e torcer para quem chamou guardar na mesma variável que foi passada como argumento, o que nem sempre acontecerá, [passando com `ref` isso é garantido, mudou a referência da *string* para uma nova *string* a variável usada como argumento é que receberá a mudança e apontará para a nova *string*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194151/101). Então `ref` é ainda mais usada para garantir que qualquer mudança dentro de um método se reflita no método chamador.

Já o `out` era muito usado para casos onde precisava retornar mais de um valor em um método, como era possível retornar só um você passava uma referência para o método, sem ter nada de valor útil e o método chamado se encarregava de por um valor ali. Sempre pode fazer de outra forma, mas era feito e mais complicado, com o advento das tuplas por valor ficou fácil e este mecanismo deve ser bem menos usado, a não ser para fazer algumas coisas em um nível mais baixo, como é a desconstrução de objetos em tuplas e interoperabilidade com outras linguagens como C por exemplo.

Inclusive já existe o `return ref` que faz o `out` ser menos necessário ainda.

Note que todos são referências, só tem garantias um pouco diferentes.

Se não está fazendo algo mais baixo nível, interoperabilidade, ou usando uma API que exige isto ou quer dar mais performance de forma geral não precisa disto.

O *stack* sempre foi mais interessante de usar, e ai contrário de Java, C# sempre gostou mais dele que do *heap*, agora ele está gostando mais e precisa ter esses mecanismos, então C# se aproxima mais de linguagens como C, C++, Rust, etc.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Útil para compreensão de heap e stack: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3797/o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-onde-est%C3%A3o-o-stack-e-heap