# Não estou entendendo o uso do ref em C#

Tags: c#, parâmetros, referência

1:

```
static void Main()
{
    int v1,v2,r;
    v1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    v2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    r = soma(v1,v2);//pode fazer assim ou como está abaixo
    Console.WriteLine("a soma de {0} e {1} É {2}",v1,v2,soma(v1,v2));
}

static int soma(int n1,int n2)
{
    int res = n1+n2;
    return res;// esse modo é preciso fazer como está no metodo Main
}

/*static void soma (int n1,int n2){
    int res = n1 + n2;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}",n1,n2,res);
}*/ //pode usar esse jeito, basta chamar esse metodo no Main indicando os valores parametros
```

2:

```
static void Main()
{
    int num = 10;
    dobrar2(num);
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}

static void dobrar1(ref int valor)
{
    valor *= 2;
}

 static void dobrar2(int valor)
{
    valor *= 2;
}
```

Por que na primeira não precisa do `ref`, mas na segunda precisa?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref

Comment: Na primeira você usou return e a variável passada não é uma referencia, logo alternando o valor diretamente não funcionaria, com ref ao alterar a variável irá referenciar a fora da função que foi passada no argumento e fica referenciado no parâmetro. Comece a estudar por aqui: [Referência de C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/) e [Palavras-chave C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/)

Answer (score 2):

Parece que o exemplo está justamente mostrando o uso do `ref` e não é uma necessidade real, é um exemplo artificial, se você fosse programar algo real jamais faria assim. O `ref` é usado no mundo real em casos diferentes deste, este caso é melhor fazer de outra forma.

Uma [função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122429/101) é um caixa preta, ou seja, é algo que faz algo que você não precisa saber como é dentro, precisa apenas fazer uma comunicação básica dos valores que interessam para o que ela sabe fazer. Então é muito comum uma função receber algum valor (como parâmetro) que será passado na chamada da função, é a entrada de dados. E para dar a saída de dados, ou seja, dar um resultado. você retorna o valor que deseja que a função entregue para quem chama, e este chamador pegará o valor e usará do jeito que achar adequado.

Então a preferência deveria ser sempre o retorno do valor, como acontece em `soma()`. Note que tem um tipo específico indicando que tipo de dado será retornado, no caso um valor inteiro (`int`).

O segundo exemplo preferiu não retornar um valor, indicado através do tipo de retorno `void` que justamente é sem um tipo, assim a função não pode retornar nada, a função faz o que sabe fazer e não devolve um resultado, o que é raro você precisar de algo assim, e tecnicamente isso nem deveria ser chamado de função, matematicamente falando. Se você não quer comunicar uma saída de dados da função está tudo bem fazer isso. Até a versão que tem um `WriteLine()` dentro faz mais sentido, ainda que conceitualmente errado.

O problema é que na verdade parece querer dar uma saída, pelo menos em `dobrar1()`. Existe outro mecanismo que permite dar a saída, que é a passagem dos dados de entrada como referência. Então em vez e copiar o valor para dentro da função ele "envelopa" o valor e manda apenas onde esse dado está. Assim se você alterar esse valor passado para dentro da função o original será alterado junto, já que o local de armazenamento da [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) é o mesmo dentro e fora da função, justamente o que o `ref` faz, é como se fosse uma variável só, de fato isso é chamado de *aliasing* de variável.

Em `dobrar2()` não tem o `ref`, então uma cópia do valor acontecerá, e aí quando mudar aquela variável não mudará o [argumento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101), são coisas independentes, e costuma ser melhor assim. O problema é que se não tem um retorno de resultado a alteração feita dentro da função será perdida, o que foi feito dentro da caixa preta não é comunicado para fora da função e aquilo não tem serventia alguma. Só serve para mostrar que não funciona como imaginaria, exemplo artificial.

A maioria dos exemplos artificiais que as pessoas usam para mostrar como um mecanismo funciona para ensinar programação são assim, eles não devem ser usados no mundo real.

Veja mais:

- [O que são os parâmetros out e ref](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82630/101)
- [Para que serve esse 'in' em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/309784/101)
- [Por que usar modificadores de parâmetros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/395571/101)