# Quando devo usar ref ou tuplas no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, método, tuple

O `ref` e as tuplas tem um funcionamento diferente, mas em algumas situações dá pra obter um resultado desejado usando qualquer um dos dois, porém eu quero saber qual seria o ideal para o exemplo que vou colocar abaixo e em que situação (não necessariamente o meu exemplo) um terá um resultado diferente do outro?

Vamos supor que eu tenho um método estático e quero retornar um sinalizador indicando se a operação foi bem sucedida e uma mensagem. Além de usar uma classe como retorno, tendo 2 propriedades. Também tem como usar o `ref` ou tuplas.

```cs
// Exemplo com ref.
public static bool SetBag(ref msg)
{
    // ...
}

// Exemplo com tupla.
public static (bool, string) SetBag()
{
    // ...
}
```

Além da pergunta que fiz no primeiro parágrafo, qual seria a melhor prática, se tiver uma? Utilizar uma classe, `ref` ou tupla? Caso não seja subjetivo.

O motivo dessa é pergunta é querer evitar utilizar recursos da linguagem que não eram pra ter essa finalidade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este caso especificamente é simples, a tupla é melhor.

Note que para ser exatamente igual deveria usar um `out` e não o `ref`. O `ref` passa a ideia que um dado também é passado, e de fato pode ter acontecido isso. E pode até ser menos eficiente em algum caso usar o `ref` do que o `out`. Poderá haver uma ligeira diferença de performance o fato de passar a referência na chamada ou no retorno, ainda que raro ou impossível em uma implementação da linguagem.

Eu também acho a tupla mais semântica. Você está retornando dois dados. O uso de `ref` é quase uma gambiarra, que funciona direitinho, e antes era a única opção, mas não é o mais certo, mesmo dando o mesmo resultado.

Se tivesse um favorecimento claro e universal de um contra o outro em eficiência, eu já pensaria mais e poderia usar o `out` se ele se mostrasse melhor, e se for necessário.

Usar uma classe parece bem fora de questão. Teria que criar só para isso, ela aloca no *heap*, é ineficiente. Se fosse uma `struct`, seria um pouco melhor, mas ainda seria um trabalho extra para nenhum ganho. A tupla justamente cria uma `struct´ para você. Se fosse interessante você criar, seria para usar em outros contextos também, mas aí a comparação não seria equivalente.

Se o [`TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) fosse criado hoje ele usaria uma tupla. Mais simples e diz com clareza que retorna dois dados, que é o que deseja.

Veja mais:

- [O que são os parâmetros out e ref](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82630/101)
- [Por que usar modificadores de parâmetros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/395571/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

#### Recursos diferentes para situações diferentes

O `ref` indica a passagem de um dado por referência, e por consequência, que o dado pode e provavelmente sofrerá uma mutação local e remotamente. Isso pode ser o que você deseja, mas também dificulta entender e alterar o código posteriormente.

`ref` é mais utilizado justamente em códigos especialistas, na tentativa de diminuir a alocação de espaço no stack e/ou de diminuir a penalidade de performance de cópias de `structs`.

Tuplas são basicamente `structs` automáticas, com algumas restrições e funcionalidades extras, algo otimizadas para o caso de você querer ter menos mutações ou "efeitos à distância", ao mesmo tempo facilitando a escrita de funções que retornam mais de um dado, sem ter de ficar criando structs só para isso.

Então não é um caso de um ou outro. Em código super especialista, onde performance é uma preocupação vital (por exemplo, jogos), provavelmente terá mais `ref struct`. E em código de negócio, onde clareza e facilidade de manutenção são mais relevantes, você provavelmente usará structs normais ou tuplas, para o código estar um tanto mais voltado a mutabilidade local e controlada.