# Por que consigo alterar arrays sem referência fora do escopo em C#?

Tags: c#, array, passagem-por-referência, imutabilidade

Quando quero que uma função altere o valor da variável fora da função, eu uso a palavra-chave `ref`, como no exemplo:

```
public void Alterar(ref string input) {
    input += "mundo!";
}

string olamundo = "Olá, ";
Alterar(ref olamundo);
```

Na função acima o valor de `olamundo` será `Olá, mundo!`, pois `Alterar(string)` alterou sua propriedade passada com referência. Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TKtksX).

Se remover ambos `ref` no código acima, ele funcionará, mas o resultado final será apenas `Olá,` .

O que ocorre é que, quando o tipo do parâmetro é um *array*, a palavra-chave `ref` não é mais necessária. Seu valor é passado como referência automaticamente. Veja um exemplo:

```
public static void AlterarArray(int[] input) {
    input[1] = 10;
}

int[] teste = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
AlterarArray(teste);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join('\n', teste));

// 1
// 10
// 3
// 4
// 5
```

Veja funcionando o código acima no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4WKVlW).

Por que é naturalmente desnecessário usar `ref` quando usando *arrays* como parâmetros? E como evitar que essa coleção seja alterada ao passar como parâmetro, garantindo que será a mesma que entrou?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade a melhor pergunta seria:

> Por que a `string` se comporta assim?

E já foi respondido em [Como passar string por referência?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194151/101).

Um *array* é um tipo por referência, então o comportamento normal é o dele, como passa a referência em vez de passar o objeto, qualquer alteração feita no novo contexto acontece no objeto original e não em um novo objeto. Tudo simples e fácil de entender se entende como funciona tipos por referência: [Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101).

Também pode ser útil: [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101).

A questão é justamente a exceção da `string` que é explicada pela [imutabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103460/101). Este tipo é por referência por otimização, mas a semântica ele é por valor, então ele se comporta como um `int` ou outro tipo por valor. Se quer usar a referência real tem que fazer igual em um tipo por valor, usar o `ref`.

O *array* em si não tem como proteger. Tem como não aceitar um *array* e aí sim proteger, por exemplo usar [`ReadOnlyCollection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0). Tente:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void AlterarArray(ReadOnlyCollection<int> input) {
        input[1] = 10;
    }
    
    public static void Main() {
        int[] teste = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        AlterarArray(Array.AsReadOnly(teste));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join('\n', teste));
    }
}
```

Veja [não funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Zo9uM). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Collection/ReadOnly.cs).

Ainda é o possível usar uma [coleção imutável](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) desde o início, que vai se assemelhar ao tipo `string`, inclusive com os contras.

O *array* é um tipo que não deveria ser muito usado pensando no mais conceitualmente correto. Na prática o próprio .NET obriga fazer isto em alguns casos, mas não porque ele quer isso, é porque não valia o esforço de mudar tudo no .NET 2.0 quando pode fazer de uma forma melhor.

O *array* resolve bem várias situações, mas ele tem vários problemas. Mais uma vez a falta de tempo para lançar e ter copiado do Java fez o C# ter alguns defeitos.

Percebeu que para ter um tipo por referência imutável ou só de leitura teve que fazer um tipo mais abstrato? O normal da linguagem é o *array*. Uma pena.