# Referência e Parâmetro em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Eu possuo uma classe em Python que tem uma função que me retorna uma tripla (3 informações juntas) e eu queria criar 4 objetos diferentes pois preciso de 4 triplas diferentes. A questão é que os valores vão acumulando e o 4º objeto possui as informações dele e dos outros 3 anteriores. Alguem sabe o porque? Ou seja, a cada vez que eu chamo a função, a lista (global na classe) não é sobrescrita.

```
class Anel():

    nomeResiduo = ""
    numCadeias = 1
    centroide = []

    def preencheAnel(self, residuo):

        i=0
        aux = residuo[0][4]

        while i < (len(residuo)):
            if ((i+1) < len(residuo)):
                if(aux != residuo[i+1][4]):
                    self.numCadeias += 1
                aux = residuo[i+1][4]
            i=i+1

        i = 0
        atomosPorCadeia = len(residuo)/self.numCadeias

        while i < self.numCadeias:
            centroide.append(Anel().calculaCentroide(residuo, self.numCadeias, i))
            i += 1

        self.nomeResiduo = residuo[0][2]

        return (self.nomeResiduo, self.numCadeias, centroide)
```

Comment: Se você definiu a propriedade na classe, fora do inicializador da instância, ela será uma propriedade da classe e não do objeto, desta forma não faz sentido sobrescrever a cada instância. Para contornar isso, você pode definí-la dentro do `__init__`, mas se possível, [edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/197681/edit) sua pergunta e coloque o código fonte, aí poderemos ajudar com maior exatidão.

Comment: Sem ver o seu código, não ha como explicar o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Mas provavelmente você está confundindo atributo de classe com  atributo de instância - ou usando uma lista como parâmetro padrão de um método.

Comment: Acho que realmente pode ser isso, pois quando eu declarei a lista como uma variavel local de uma função ao invés de uma variável global da classe, funcionou normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como discutido nos comentários, você confundiu atributo de classe com atributo de instância. Quando definido o atributo da forma:

```
class Foo:
    attribute = ["Hello"]

    def add(self, value):
        self.attribute.append(value)
```

Chamamos de atributo de classe e ele será comum à todas as instâncias da mesma. Por exemplo, considere os dois objetos:

```
>>> foo1 = Foo()
>>> foo2 = Foo()
```

Se alterarmos o valor do atributo de um objeto, do outro será alterado também, pois o atributo é da classe.

```
>>> foo1.add("Stack Overflow")
>>> print(foo2.attribute)
['Hello', 'Stack Overflow']
```

Para contornar isso, você pode definir o atributo como atributo de instância, definindo-o dentro do inicializador da mesma:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attribute = ["Hello"]
    ...
```

Desta forma, alterando o valor de um objeto, o outro não será afetado:

```
>>> foo1.add("Stack Overflow")
>>> print(foo2.attribute)
['Hello']
```

No seu caso, o atributo em questão é o `centroide` então pode fazer:

```
class Anel:

    def __init__(self):
        self.nomeResiduo = ""
        self.numCadeias  = 1
        self.centroide   = []
    ...
```

Ou utilizar as variáveis como locais ao método, se não houver necessidade delas serem atributos da instância.

Vale notar que isso acontece apenas com **tipos mutáveis**, como a lista, pois para alterá-la não é necessário uma atribuição.

- [O que "imutável" realmente significa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/5878)

Quando o tipo utilizado é imutável não terá este problema:

```
class Foo:
    number = 1
```

Assim:

```
>>> foo1 = Foo()
>>> foo2 = Foo()
>>> foo1.number = 2
>>> foo2.number
1
```

Isso acontece porque ao fazer `foo1.number = 2` você não está **modificando** o valor, mas sim criando uma nova instância de `int` e referenciando ela em um atributo de instância. Sim, passa a ser um atributo de instância. O Python armazena internamente os atributos em um dicionário; os atributos de classe ficam armazenados em um dicionário da classe (`Foo.__dict__`) enquanto os atributos da instância ficam armazenados em um dicionário da instância (`foo1.__dict__`). Quando você acessa um atributo, internamente o Python fará a busca no dicionário da instância e, caso não encontre a definição do atributo, buscará no dicionário da classe, seguindo as definições da MRO.

- [Python Ordem de resolução de métodos (MRO)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/304178/5878)
- [Python chamada super() em classe que não implementa herança](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/320217/5878)

Quando você faz uma nova **atribuição** na instância você definirá um **atributo de instância**, que terá preferência perante o atributo de classe. Isso é válido inclusive para tipos mutáveis:

```
class Foo:
    numbers = [100]
```

Assim:

```
>>> foo1 = Foo()
>>> foo2 = Foo()
>>> foo1.numbers = [100, 200]
>>> foo2.numbers
[100]
```

Pois, neste caso, você não está **modificando** o atributo de classe, mas sim definindo um atributo de instância em `foo1` com uma lista completamente diferente da definida como atributo de classe; tanto que você ainda poderá fazer `foo1.__class__.numbers` e verá que a lista `[100]` permanece lá como atributo de classe inalterada.

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigado mesmo. Resolveu aqui e também entendi o que eu fiz de errado.