# Python chamada super() em classe que não implementa herança

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, middleware

Estou desenvolvendo alguns middlewares e ao me aprofundar no código fonte do Django me deparei com o seguinte:

```
class MiddlewareMixin:

    def __init__(self, get_response=None):
        self.get_response = get_response
        super().__init__()

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = None
        if hasattr(self, 'process_request'):
            response = self.process_request(request)
        response = response or self.get_response(request)
        if hasattr(self, 'process_response'):
            response = self.process_response(request, response)
        return response
```

Essa classe é usada para compatibilidade com versões anteriores do Django, mas o que me chamou a atenção foi a chamada: `super().__init__()`
quando a mesma não possui uma classe base.
Alguém poderia me explicar o porquê disso?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Na verdade, o `super` do Python faz mais do que localizar os ancestrais explícitos de uma classe. Se ele fizesse só isso, poderia muito bem nem existir - era só sempre colocar a classe pai explicitamente no código - o `super` inclusive deixaria isso menos explícito, e talvez fosse melhor nem usar.

O que o `super` faz de verdade é achar a linha de herança correta em hierarquias de herança múltipla - aí que está a mágica dele!

Perceba que essa classe é um "mixin" - em Python, em geral classes desse tipo se destinam a sere combinadas com outros "mixin"  numa hierarquia comum - e o diagrama de herança não só tende a ficar complicado, como nõa tem nem como ser previsto por quem escreve o mixin - (ainda mais nesse caso que são coigos escritos em momentos diferentes - o mixin está no framework, e o código que vai herdar dele vai ser escrito pelo usuário do framework, junto com as classes próprias do sistema lá).

Agora, se todos os métodos relevantes chamarem o seu ancestral  com  o `super`, não importa a ordem de composição da classe final: todos os métodos vão ser executados.

E sim, todas as classes herdam de `object`, então mesmo que essa seja a última classe colocada na hierarquia de heranças, o `super` chamado a partir dela ainda vai chamar o método correspondente em `object`

Python tem [um algoritmo muito bacana para determinar a ordem de chamada de métodos](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/), normalmente referido só pela sigla em inglês "**mro**" (method resolution order). Formalmente ele é complicadinho, mas intuitivamente, ele faz "a coisa certa". Esse artig que eu linkey é a documentação oficial do algoritmo.

No programa, essa ordem fica explícita em qualquer classe no atributo `__mro__` - essa é a ordem de ancestralidade considerada quando o `super()`  faz a sua chamada.. Se você achar código com alguma classe que faça uso desse mixin, e imprimir `<nome_da_classe>.__mro__` vai ver ela lá no meio.

Aqui tem um exemplo de uma hierarquia de classes com herança múltipla-  veja como todos os métodos `__init__` são chamados:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        print(__class__.__name__)
        super().__init__()

class MixinBranch1(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print(__class__.__name__)
        super().__init__()

class MixinBranch2(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        print(__class__.__name__)
        super().__init__()


class Branch1(MixinBranch1):
    def __init__(self):
        print(__class__.__name__)
        super().__init__()

class Final(MixinBranch2, Branch1):
    def __init__(self):
        print(__class__.__name__)
        super().__init__()
```

E no modo interativo:

```
In [177]: Final.__mro__
Out[177]: 
(__main__.Final,
 __main__.MixinBranch2,
 __main__.Branch1,
 __main__.MixinBranch1,
 __main__.Base,
 object)
In [178]: Final()
Final
MixinBranch2
Branch1
MixinBranch1
Base
```

(esse exemplo usa uma outra feature pouco conhecida do Python 3 que é a variável mágica `__class__` (não confundir com `self.__class__`) - `__class__` é uma referência automática para a classe onde está o código que faz uso dela, não importa se o método foi chamado de uma sub-classe.)

Answer (score 2):

Toda classe possui uma classe base. Quando você não especifica a classe base, automaticamente a classe herda de `object` que é a classe "pai de todos":

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
... 
>>> print(Foo.__mro__)
(<class '__main__.Foo'>, <class 'object'>)
```

No seu exemplo o `super()` está chamando o `__init__` de `object` (que não faz nada, mas existe). Ele foi colocado ali para que, no caso de uma herança múltipla, todos os `__init__` sejam executados.

Comment: não é a "razão de ser"  do super.