# Qual é a diferença no Kotlin entre var e val?

Tags: variáveis, imutabilidade, kotlin

Aprendendo Kotlin me deparei com a seguinte dúvida, segundo a documentação:

> Classes in Kotlin can have properties. These can be declared as
>   mutable, using the var keyword or read-only using the val keyword.

*Classes em Kotlin podem ter propriedades. Estes podem ser declarados como mutável, usando a palavra-chave `var` ou somente leitura usando a palavra-chave `val`.*

Eu entendi a diferença entre os tipos de declaração de variáveis, porém como explicar o código abaixo em que `money` e `myMoney` são declaradas como `val` e uma delas permite alterar seu valor e a outra não?

[image: Código]

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    data class Money(var value: Int)

    operator fun Money.plusAssign(value: Money) {
        this.value += value.value
    }

    val money = Money(10)
    money += Money(20)

    val myMoney = 10
    myMoney += 20 //erro

    println(money.value)
}
```

Pelo que entendi do código `Money` é uma classe, mesmo assim queria entender o uso do `val` nessa declaração.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`val` declara uma variável [imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) e `var` declara uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) mutável, por isso o compilador detectou que você tentou mudar o valor de algo que não pode. Parece que já sabe isso. Mas tem uma pegadinha.

O que tem na variável `money` é apenas uma referência para um objeto `Money`. Nada impede de alterar o objeto em si. A imutabilidade é apenas do conteúdo da variável, não do objeto e `money += Money(20)` só altera o objeto, não sua referência, ou seja, não cria um novo objeto, uma nova identidade.

Algumas pessoas preferem dizer que a variável é de apenas leitura e não imutável. Eu não vejo problema em chamar de imutável, desde que entenda a diferença entre a variável e o objeto. Mas pode dizer que é `readonly`, C# chama assim. Eu discordo um pouco porque toda variável que só pode ler é imutável, o fato do seu objeto referenciado ser mutável não muda a situação da variável em si.

Já `myMoney` é um tipo por valor, possui uma identidade própria, não tem referência, só pode alterar seu valor na própria variável, o que é proibido pelo compilador.

Kotlin prefere a imutabilidade até que precise o contrário. A linguagem incentiva um estilo diferente de programação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Kotlin/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Neste caso `money += Money(20)` funciona em cima de efeito colateral por conta da sobrecarga do operador `plusAssign`. Se tivesse apenas feito a sobrecarga do `plus`, então `money += Money(20)` iria se comportar como `money = money + Money(20)`, o que iria causar gerar um novo objeto a ser atribuído a `money` e, portanto, erro de compilação.