# Qual é a diferença do var entre Kotlin e Java?

Tags: java, característica-linguagem, kotlin, java-10

Com o lançamento do Java 10, foi introduzido a possibilidade da utilização do `var`:

`var list = new ArrayList<String>();`

Já vi qual é a diferença entre [`val` e `var`no Kotlin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/224552/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-no-kotlin-entre-var-e-val), mas, gostaria de saber mais sobre o `var`, no que se refere ao Java.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basicamente em Kotlin pode ser usado em membros de tipos e em Java só pode ser usado para variáveis locais, assim como em Kotlin também pode.

Provavelmente este é um dos motivos do compilador de Kotlin ser lento, inferir tipo em membros é bem mais complicado.

Apesar de ter pequenos detalhes diferentes, funcionam de forma igual.

Em Java o `final` pode ser usado para ter efeito semelhante ao `val` do Kotlin.

Funciona de forma [análoga ao C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47383/101) também.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 11):

`var` no Java veio para reduzir um pouco a verbosidade da linguagem. O compilador faz inferência do tipo e evita que você tenha que repetir o tipo em algumas situações.

Em vez de escrever:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

Agora é possível escrever:

```
var bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

É uma feature que já existia em diversas linguagens, e agora o Java resolveu adotar.

Uma importante observação é que só pode ser utilizado em variáveis locais ( dentro de métodos, no bloco inicializador, como index do enhanced for loop, lambdas expressions, e variáveis locais declaradas dentro do for tradicional)