# Exigir que um método precisa obrigatoriamente estar após outro?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, método

Digamos que eu possuo uma classe com dois métodos, e o método x precisa obrigatoriamente ser executado após o método y caso o contrário o método x deverá executar o método y para pegar o valor *default*.

```
class Classe 
{
   private $metodoX;
   private $metodoY;

   public function result(){
       $rs = $this->metodoX * $this->metodoY;
       return $rs;
   }

   public function metodoX(int $x = 1)
   {
      $this->metodoX = $x;
      return $this;
   }

   public function metodoY(int $y = 10)
   {
      $this->metodoY = $y;
      return $this;
   }
}
```

Caso eu chame os métodos da seguinte maneira, vou ter um dos resultados desejado:

```
$class = new Classe();

$data = $class->metodoY(3)->metodoX(2)->result();
echo $data;
//response = int 6
```

Mas, caso eu deseje usar do seguinte modo, fazendo duas chamadas, nesse caso não possuo o resultado desejado, pois o valor de `metodoY()` da primeira chamada é espelhado para a segunda chamada:

```
$class = new Classe();

$data = $class->metodoY(3)->metodoX(2)->result();
echo $data;
echo '<br>';
$data2 = $class->metodoX(2)->result();
echo $data2;
//response = (int) 6 <br> (int) 6
```

Primeiro:

> Como impedir a classe de continuar caso esteja faltando algum método na chamada?

Ex: no caso, `result()` não deveria responder com sucesso caso `metodoY()` não fosse chamado.

Segundo:

> Existe como declarar ordenamento obrigatório na execução dos métodos
>   em uma classe?

Ex: Definir que `metodoX()` deve sempre ser iniciado após `metodoY()`, caso contrário responder um erro ou em outras situação, o `metodoX()` executar o `metodoY()` para buscar um valor *default*.

Comment: Se isso é uma regra, então não seria melhor chamar o método Y sempre dentro do método X antes de qualquer coisa?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Não acaba sendo uma regra fixa, os métodos que preciso disso, são componentes de outros métodos, esses sim ditarão as regras, mas eu queria impedir que certas coisas 'naturais' prosseguissem, como por exemplo, na segunda chamada, ele recuperar o valor do metodoY da primeira, queria fazer com isso não acontecesse, respondendo um erro se for possível de forma nativa.

Comment: Sinceramente, eu não vejo sentido algum em fazer isso. Tem como descrever sua real necessidade? Se os métodos são do mesmo objeto, então não faz sentido você não utilizar o mesmo valor definido anteriormente. Para objetos distintos, sim; aí bastaria verificar se o valor de Y é diferente de `NULL`, por exemplo.

Comment: Acho que me expressei mal na pergunta, eu posso por exemplo, comparar se for null, caso seja solicitar o método, mas o que eu queria saber é se existe alguma regra, nativa do PHP, pra indicar que metodoX é obrigatoriamente dependente de metodoY ter sido chamado antes dele na mesma cadeia.

Comment: O ambiente em questão que preciso disso é um grupo de classes PHP pra construção de elementos bootstrap, e posso por exemplo:
Em uma chamada posso querer o botão com atributo->active(true), e na mesma instância da classe, mas num segundo objeto, não precisar indicar ->active(false), e sim, se eu não indicar nada que ele busque automaticamente o valor padrão para ->active(), que no caso seria false, e renderizar o elemento como ->active(false). Sei que posso fazer isso dentro dos métodos, só queria saber se é possível por regra nativa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isto normalmente é um erro conceitual. Um objeto deveria ser criado já em estado válido para executar qualquer comportamento em qualquer momento. Pra isso [existe o construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). A garantia do estado válido deveria idealmente ser feita no construtor. E qualquer mudança de estado do objeto deveria garantir também que ele ainda está em estado válido.

Ter um estado válido que logo em seguida se torna inválido parece esquisito e errado conceitualmente. Dá para criar um mecanismo que indique isso, mas não parece correto.

Se o dado pode mudar e quer o mesmo resultado deveria [criar outro objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101) (o que parece ser o caso pelos comentários). Se quer mudar o estado do objeto aceite que ele nem sempre funcionará como espera, o que obviamente não é o ideal.

Se ainda quiser fazer do jeito conceitualmente errado até é possível tentando verificar se o estado é válido antes de executar o comportamento. Em alguns casos a verificação pode ser feita dentro de regras previamente estabelecidas, em outros precisa de algum mecanismo extra.

Dependendo do caso pode manter o valor inicial nulo e só deixar fazer cálculos quando ele não estiver nulo. Se isso não for possível pode manter *flags* indicando se o valor foi *setado* anteriormente e aí ele pode ser usado. É uma enorme gambiarra. Parece que resolve um problema, mas na verdade pode até causar outros. O correto é repensar o conceito.

Mas nesse caso me parece que nem funcionaria.

Se quer que um método que sempre tenha antes dois argumentos, faça este método ter os dois argumentos.

Mas neste caso específico nem vejo solução porque deseja que o objeto deixe sozinho de ter um estado que ele já tinha antes. A forma de fazer isso é criar outro objeto. Faça o `result()` receber os valores e os use como quer. É complicado criar uma forma atômica em métodos diferentes, ainda mais que logo em seguida o que vale deixa de valer.

Se as regras são variáveis de quando pode fazer de um jeito ou de outro então provavelmente deveria ter objetos diferentes para cada regra. Ou ser algum tipo de política (alguma *flag*) que indique como deve ser o comportamento naquele caso.

Pelo que entendi nem deseja ter um objeto. É o que eu falo sempre, é comum as pessoas querem fazer orientado a objeto o que não deve ser. Se não quer manter estado, não crie um objeto.

Então a pergunta parte de uma premissa errada.

Mas respondendo objetivamente não tem como exigir ordem de chamada na forma estabelecida na pergunta que é complicada demais até para manter *flags*.

Resolva o problema do jeito certo e não terá esta dificuldade. Tentar colocar um parafuso com um martelo pode até dar um resultado, mas não será adequado e será muito difícil.

Existe uma situação em que até faz sentido ter algo assim, mas para resolver em geral precisa de um *framework de workflow*, o que não é o caso.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu queria saber, o que eu quero fazer não teria como funcionar se não for possível dar um ordem obrigatória aos métodos, vou procurar outro modo de fazer isso.

Comment: Eu não poderia ter respondido melhor.