# Definir os métodos encadeados de um método

Tags: php, classes, método, encapsulamento

Digamos que eu tenha a seguinte classe:

```
class animal{

    private $animal;
    private $som;

    function gato(){
        $this->animal = 'gato';
        return $this;
    }

    function cachorro(){
        $this->animal = 'cachorro';
        return $this;
    }

    function mia()
    {
        $this->som = 'miau';
        return $this;
    }

    function late()
    {
        $this->som = 'au au';
        return $this;
    }
}
```

A partir desse ponto eu poderia encadear os metodos da seguinte maneira

```
$animal = new animal();

$animal->gato()->mia();
$animal->cachorro()->late();
```

Ou então:

```
$animal = new animal();

$animal->gato()->late();
$animal->cachorro()->mia();
```

Como pode vê acima, pelo código eu disse que o "cachorro mia", mas eu gostaria quer determinados métodos ficassem inacessíveis, ou seja, se eu chamar o método "gato" eu gostaria que só o método "mia" ficasse acessível para encadear.

> Sei que se eu dividir os métodos em classes distintas fica mais fácil realizar essa tarefa, até mais organizado, porém quero saber se é possível realizar tal tarefa dentro de uma mesma classe.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Exigir que um método precisa obrigatoriamente estar após outro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/230172/exigir-que-um-m%c3%a9todo-precisa-obrigatoriamente-estar-ap%c3%b3s-outro)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não dá, até porque esse conceito está totalmente errado. Gato e cachorro não podem estar dentro de Animal, eles são animais, eles não fazem parte de um animal. E o conceito está errado, todo o resto estará errado e tentar fazer coisa para acertar é só criar um erro novo em cima do erro já existente.

Ainda que eu seja crítico não só a essas exemplos abstratos que ensinam nada, ou até causam mal, e que OO em regras de negócios costuma ser uma prática duvidosa, e ainda que PHP não é a linguagem mais adequada para fazer este tipo de coisa, muito menos a linguagem que precisa deste tipo de coisa, eu diria que a solução é criar uma herança tomando `animal` como uma base `abstract` para não deixar ser instanciada, e aí as derivadas de cada animal ter o método que faz sentido. Embora neste caso específico a herança fará bem pouco sentido porque sequer permite o reuso e polimorfismo. Ainda faria para indicar subtipo, mas que não é estritamente uma herança.

Não é questão de ser mais organizado, é questão de ser certo, com algo completamente sem sentido não tem porque fazer isto, e como isso não traz vantagem alguma até fazer a hipótese não faz sentido.

Se ainda quiser insistir nisso, o que pode fazer é ter um campo que guarde o objeto que esse animal está representando, neste caso está trocando a herança pela composição, aí terá um objeto `Gato` ou um objeto `Cachorro` dentro do objeto `Animal`, e quando for chamar o objeto específico só poderá chamar os métodos que estão dentro dele.

Isso elimina a herança, mas não a necessidade de ter os objetos criados separadamente.

Poderá até ter mais de um campo para conter mais de um tipo de objeto ao mesmo tempo, pode ser até um *array*. Mas ainda me parece maluquice a não ser que a classe chame `Zoologico` ou algo assim, o que ainda não parece muito adequado.

Comment: Obrigado, e na verdade eu não tenho necessidade de fazer isso, mas estava lendo sobre métodos encadeados e fiquei com duvida se isso seria possível

Comment: O método encadeado em si não é problema, o problema é selecionar o que pode ou não acessar, ainda mais em PHP.