# Uso de funções estáticas encadeadas

Tags: php, funções, classes, static

Queria usar funções estáticas do PHP da seguinte forma:

```
class A {
    static function a1() {
        echo "A1";
        return A;
    }
    static function a2() {
        echo "A2";
        return A;
    }
}

A::a1()::a2();
```

Funciona, porém mostra esse erro:

> A1
>
> NOTICE Use of undefined constant A - assumed 'A' on line number 4
>
> A2
>
> NOTICE Use of undefined constant A - assumed 'A' on line number 8

O que é `assumed 'A'`?

Devo retornar a classe de outra forma, ou criar uma constante com o valor da classe A? No caso, como?

É correto dizer que essas funções seguem o padrão Builder mesmo **não** sendo construtoras?

Comment: É meio estranho, qual a necessidade de ser estático?

Comment: Os métodos seriam para alterar o status de resposta e para retornar um objeto ou array que será convertido em json, primeiro fiz junto, mas gostaria de separar em duas partes

Comment: Relacionadas: [O que é encadeamento de métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105259/91), [Definir os métodos encadeados de um método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/311724/91) e [O que é Fluent Interface?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106955/91). Talvez o primeiro link responda a sua pergunta.

Comment: @rray valeu pelos links, o primeiro só faltou mostrar com funções estáticas, vou ler melhor mais tarde

Comment: `return A` seria retornar uma constante pré definida - por isso o erro.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Comment: @Maniero resolvi o proble retornando `__CLASS__` nas funções, a sua resposta responde a segunda pergunta mas não a primeira, se quiser edita-la com essa solução eu a aceito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para usar funções estáticas encadeadas precisa retornar `__CLASS__`, por exemplo:

```
class A {
    static function a1() {
        echo "A1";
        return __CLASS__;
    }
    static function a2() {
        echo "A2";
        return __CLASS__;
    }
}

A::a1()::a2();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Padrão Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) nada tem a ver com o que deseja. Está querendo fazer uso do que se chama [interface fluente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106955/101) que é obtido através do [encadeamento de método](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105259/101). O Builder poder ser usado junto com o [Method Chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) para fazer oque quer com objetos.

Se deseja usar um *builder* algo será construído. Seu código está construindo nada. E de fato o que é algo estático faz bem pouco sentido construir porque existirá apenas um na aplicação toda, é mais fácil fazer de outra forma. Normalmente faz-se isso na criação de objetos.

Até onde eu sei PHP sequer permite método estático ter um objeto (que nem é a intenção deste código) como argumento dele. Isto é chamado de [Uniform Function Call Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Function_Call_Syntax). Não tendo esse mecanismo é impossível fazer o que deseja, poderia fazer:

```
A::a2(A::a1(objeto));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Function/NestedCall.php).

Note o uso de um objeto que em tese esses dois métodos saberá o que fazer com ele.

Nem entrei no mérito de usar este tipo de mecanismo em PHP, que faz bem pouco sentido. Inclusive o uso de classe só com métodos estáticos.

E pra mim esse tipo de construção é *language smell*, ou *code smell* quando a linguagem tem mecanismo melhor.

Comment: O uso da classe faz sentido, além desses tem outros métodos e variáveis privadas. não entendi o porque de passar o resultado da função como parâmetro de outra, poderia explicar mais?

Comment: Não sei, o seu código faz menos sentido ainda, eu só tentei dar um mínimo de sentido para ele, ainda assim é ruim, conforme eu falei na resposta. Quem diz que algo faz sentido tem que explicar qual é o sentido, não tem nem na pergunta nem nos comentários.

Comment: O código faz parte de uma biblioteca de roteamento que estou criando, por isso quero deixar todas as funções dentro da classe, que possui variáveis privadas com as rotas definidas, configurações, etc. Esses métodos serviriam para dar uma resposta (um altera o status e outros dois o corpo). Poderia simplesmente fazer `Router::status(404); Router::json(array("error" => "Página não encontrada"));` porém queria que fosse mais direto e separado em dois métodos diferentes, que podem ou não ser combinados. Como estou me baseando no Express do node busco fazer algo o mais parecido possível