# Como modificar uma lista dentro de um método em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suponhamos que eu tenha o seguinte método e a seguinte lista:

```
def ModificaValores(Valores):
      dados = [6,5,4,3,2,1,0]

      Valores = dados

Valores = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

print(Valores)
ModificaValores(Valores)
print(Valores)
```

Por que na saída tenho o seguinte resultado:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Se eu modifico elemento por elemento funciona, mas assim não. Me expliquem por que isso acontece!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não funciona porque as alterações feitas dentro do escopo da função não são repletidas para o escopo externo - e nem deveria, pois isso poderia gerar efeitos colaterais e dificultar muito a manutenção do código. **Ou seja, não faça isso a menos que realmente faça sentido**.

Vamos por partes.

Fora da função, no escopo global, você define a lista `Valores`. Neste momento, o objeto `Valores` terá um identificador único que o representa que pode ser obtido via `id(Valores)`. Em CPython, esse valor representa o endereço de memória do seu objeto. Este objeto é passado via parâmetro para a função `ModificaValores` e, como no Python o tipo `list` é um [tipo mutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/5878), o objeto será passado por referência, o que implica que dentro da função será o mesmo objeto que foi criado fora, com os mesmos valores e mesmo endereço de memória. O fato de ser passado via referência explica o porquê de refletir as alterações feitas elemento a elemento, pois você está apenas modificando o objeto. Mesmo que assim reflita as mudanças para o escopo externo, deve-se usar com muita cautela, apenas em casos que realmente isso faça sentido. No geral, o ideal seria retornar uma nova lista e atribuí-la ao objeto desejado. Algo como:

```
def ModificaValores(Valores):
    # Neste caso o parâmetro é desnecessário
    # mas mantive por questões didáticas
    dados = [6,5,4,3,2,1,0]
    return dados

Valores = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

print(Valores)
Valores = ModificaValores(Valores)
print(Valores)
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/k1xHF9) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/CruelDearestIcelandgull)</sup>

E por quê não funciona quando você atribui a nova lista?

Pois você, quando define `dados` sendo uma nova lista, define um novo objeto na memória, com um novo endereço, que existirá apenas no escopo da função. Quando você atribui `dados` para `Valores`, você quebra a referência que `Valores` tinha com o objeto externo e passa a referenciar o objeto `dados` local, porém essa alteração é feita no escopo local, não sendo refletida para o escopo externo - em outras palavras, você passa a ter um objeto `Valores` no escopo global e outro no escopo local, sendo diferentes entre si. As modificações que você faz em `Valores`, no escopo local, não serão refletidas em `Valores` do escopo global, pois são objetos diferentes.

Comment: Muito boa sua resposta, obrigado pela rapidez em responder! Mas e agora no caso se eu precisar modificar a lista como no meu exemplo, existe alguma forma de fazer isso?
É porque eu preciso retornar True ou False, e modificar uma lista.

Comment: Faltou ressaltar em negrito outra parte, mas eu comentei que você pode fazer isso se realmente fizer sentido. Não é errado, só que se utilizado de maneira indevida, pode gerar efeitos colaterais difíceis de reconhecer. Se sua função realmente precisa alterar o objeto, pode fazer.

Comment: Eu vi que você disse que posso usar se realmente for necessário, mas tem como fazer uma cópia direta de outra lista? Ao invés de modificar elemento por elemento?

Comment: Pelo visto você precisa alterar todos os elementos da lista, é isso? Talvez este seja um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/5878), em que você pede ajuda em uma solução que possivelmente não é a mais adequada. Por quê precisa alterar todos os elementos e ainda retornar um booleano?

Comment: Isso mesmo, no escopo global tenho uma lista chamada BufferRx que preciso modificar dentro da leitura serial com os dados recebidos, e retornar um True ou False para informar se os dados vieram corretos e de acordo com o protocolo de comunicação criado!

Comment: @FilipeSantos Se quiser, acesse o [chat Estouro de Pilha](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha), mas acho que alterar a lista no escopo global, nesse caso, não seja a melhor solução.