# Quais as diferenças entre Object.freeze() e Object.seal()?

Tags: javascript

Sei que o `Object.freeze()` e `Object.seal()` são usados para "congelar" um objeto. Logo, sabendo disso, se você executar o exemplo abaixo irá ver que os dois objetos foram congelados e logo não pude atribuir valores para eles.

```js
let object1 = {}, object2 = {};

Object.freeze(object1);
Object.seal(object2);

object1["test"] = "valor teste";
object2["test"] = "valor teste";

console.log(object1["test"]);   
console.log(object2["test"]);
```

### **Dúvidas**

1. Existem diferenças entre o  `Object.freeze()` e `Object.seal()`? Se
   sim, quais?
2. Ao congelar um objeto com um dos dois métodos eu tenho um aumento de performance?
3. Qual o suporte dos navegadores em relação aos métodos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Existem diferenças entre o Object.freeze() e Object.seal()? Se sim, quais?

O [`seal()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) coloca uma metapropriedade no objeto que indica que propriedades não podem ser adicionadas ou apagadas. Lembrando que objetos em JS no fundo são apenas dicionários de dados, então é só adicionar ou remover um elemento na estrutura.

O [`freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) marca também que as propriedades existentes não podem ser alteradas, o que torna o objeto [imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101), seu estado nunca muda.

Para ver melhor seria bom ter uma propriedade existente e mudá-la em cada caso para perceber a diferença:

```js
let object1 = {}, object2 = {};
object2["test1"] = "valor teste";
object1["test1"] = "valor teste";
Object.freeze(object1);
Object.seal(object2);
object1["test"] = "valor teste";
object2["test"] = "valor teste";
object1["test1"] = "mudei";
object2["test1"] = "mudei";
console.log(object1["test"]);
console.log(object1["test1"]);
console.log(object2["test"]);
console.log(object2["test1"]);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/ObjectFreezeSeal.js).

> Ao congelar um objeto com um dos dois métodos eu tenho um aumento de performance?

Deveria, mas curiosamente não afeta muito, e pode até piorar, como de fato acontece ou já aconteceu. Não entrarei em detalhes porque isto depende de implementação, pode ser uma coisa na versão atual, mas mudar na próxima, então uma resposta que diga que é mais lento ou mais rápida poderá estar defasada em um mês. Não descarto os *engines* atualmente estarem sofisticados que conseguem otimizar até mesmo sem essa garantia em alguns casos onde ele percebe que não haverá problemas. Por isso não confiaria em testes superficiais de quem não entendem onde pode dar diferença (as pessoas costumam fazer testes ingênuos).

No momento que é garantido que a estrutura não muda poderiam otimizar e usar algo que não seja um dicionário e até mesmo algumas outras otimizações são possíveis, principalmente em ambiente concorrente,já que é garantido que o dado não será afetado.

> Qual o suporte dos navegadores em relação aos métodos?

Todos os padrões muitos usados possuem estes métodos há muitas versões então podemos dizer que tem aceitação universal.

Comment: Show! Agora ficou mais claro! Obrigado pela resposta!