# É possível aplicar ou simular imutabilidade em um "objeto" do tipo Map no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, objetos, imutabilidade

Para objetos, podemos deixá-lo imutável, de modo que tentar re-atribuir um novo valor a uma propriedade, adicionar nova propriedades ou remover propriedades não seja possível. Claro, para o caso de o objeto que sofreu [`Object.freeze`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/338409/quais-as-diferen%c3%a7as-entre-object-freeze-e-object-seal).

Vamos de exemplo:

```js
var obj = { foo: 'baz' };

Object.freeze(obj);

obj.foo = null;

delete obj.foo;

obj.bar = 10;

console.log(obj); // Não mudou
```

Ou, também, para novas propriedades, podemos as definir de modo imutável através do `Object.defineProperty` passando alguns parâmetros para chegarmos lá:

```js
var obj = { foo: 'baz'};

Object.defineProperty(obj, 'key', {
  enumerable: false,   // não enumerável
  configurable: false, // não configurável
  writable: false,     // não gravável
  value: 'static'
});

obj.key = 100;

console.log(obj.key); // 'static'
```

Posso até impedir um objeto de ser estendido usando `Object.preventExtensions`:

```js
var obj = { a: null };

Object.preventExtensions(obj);

obj.b = true;

console.log(obj);

// lança um erro
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'foo', {
  configurable: false,
  writable: false,
  value: 'true',
});
```

A minha curiosidade surgiu em relação ao `Map`. Apesar deste ser "parecido" com objetos, ele tem [comportamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/313921/95771) um pouco distinto, o que diferencia de objetos. Queria saber se é possível aplicar imutabilidade a instâncias de `Map`, da mesma forma que pode ser feito com objetos. Obviamente, as tentativas acima não terão efeito algum no `Map`, até porque são métodos de objetos:

```js
var map = new Map();

map.set('foo', 'baz');

// nem adiciona, como esperado
Object.defineProperty(map, 'footest', { configurable: false, writable: false });

// não fica frio
Object.freeze(map);

// não impede novas adições
Object.preventExtensions(map);

console.log(map);

map.set('baz', null);
map.set('foo', true);

console.log(map.get('baz'));
console.log(map.get('foo'));

// remove sem problema
map.delete('baz');

console.log(map.get('baz'));
```

- Existe alguma maneira de trabalhar com imutabilidade com `Map`s?
- Existe alguma maneira de impedir um `Map` de ser estendido quando este atinge um tamanho, por exemplo, `size` igual a 3?
- Podemos deixar alguma chave de um `Map` imutável?
- Se não, é pelo menos possível criar e simular algo como um *immutable Map*?

---

Esta minha dúvida é só uma prova de conceito. Eu não vejo nenhuma utilidade para tal, mas acho que vale saber.

Comment: O monkey patch `map.set = ()=> undefined;` seguido de `Object.freeze(map);` não soluciona?

Comment: @AugustoVasques, o `Object.freeze` no `map` não tem nenhum efeito sobre o que de fato está sendo armazenado no mapa. Mas o _monkey patch_, de fato, é uma solução para um mapa já instanciado via `Map`.

Comment: Sim @LuizFelipe, mas se fizer `map.set = ()=> undefined;` ele para de inserir dados no `map` e Object.freeze(map); impede que a restauração seja feita tornado o read only.

Comment: Ah sim, justíssimo.

Comment: @AugustoVasques essa ideia que eu tinha em mente mesmo, só não tinha pensado no `Object.freeze(map)`. Bom complemento! :D

Comment: @CmteCardeal, mas também não escapa da manipulação do protótipo tal como o Luiz Felipe disse. Se fizer `Map.prototype.set.call(map,'foo','123');` a alteração é realizada.

Comment: @LuizFelipe, consegui com um proxy tornar um map ready-only, porém causa tantos efeitos colaterais, alguns ainda desconhecidos por mim, que se torna uma atividade impraticável.

Comment: Manda o código, @AugustoVasques, fiquei curioso!

Comment: @LuizFelipe  https://replit.com/@RonaldoVasques/TestesJS#index.js

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124489/https-pt-stackoverflow-com-q-509804-69296, @AugustoVasques

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

É impossível tornar uma instância de `Map` imutável em JavaScript.

---

Antes de tudo, é preciso esclarecer algumas coisas.

Todos os mecanismos utilizados na pergunta para tornar um objeto "imutável" são apenas válidos para objetos, de modo que podemos definir propriedades imutáveis:

- `Object.defineProperty` permite a definição de uma *propriedade* com atributos customizados. De modo, você pode definir uma propriedade com `[[Writable]]` e `[[Configurable]]` `false`s, tornando-a imutável.

Ou modificar o comportamento de um objeto já existente:

- `Object.freeze`, o suprassumo dos três, essencialmente, torna um objeto imutável, de modo que:

  1. Previne a modificação de suas propriedades;
  2. Previne a remoção de suas propriedades; e:
  3. Previne a adição de novas propriedades.
- `Object.seal`, similar ao `Object.freeze`, mas um pouco menos rigoroso, já que ainda permite a modificação de propriedades já existentes. Então:

  1. Previne a remoção de suas propriedades; e:
  2. Previne a adição de novas propriedades.
- `Object.preventExtensions`, que apenas previne a adição de novas propriedades. É o mais fraquinho dos três.

Mas repare que esses quatro mecanismos trabalham exclusivamente sobre objetos, atuando sobre os [descritores de propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/478411/69296). Somente a adição de novas propriedades que não tem a ver com os descritores, mas sim com a propriedade interna `[[Extensible]]`, que faz parte de um objeto (e não de suas propriedades, tal como os [atributos de propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/478411/69296)).

---

Desse modo, não é esperado que esses quatro mecanismos funcionem para *imutabilizar* instâncias de `Map`.

Para entender melhor, vamos comparar as formas como objetos e mapas (instâncias de `Map`) armazenam seus valores.

| Objetos | Instâncias de `Map` |
| --- | --- |
| Armazenam seus valores, qualificados por uma chave, como uma propriedade do próprio objeto. | Armazenam seus valores, qualificados por uma chave, como um "membro" do "armazém" interno de cada `Map`. |

Portanto, ao contrário de objetos, cujos valores armazenados podem ser acessados pelo programador (através de APIs do próprio JavaScript), os valores de mapas são mantidos em um "armazém" protegido do programador. Você pode saber mais sobre esse *internal store* dos mapas na [seção § 23.1](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-map-objects), sobre `Map`, na especificação da linguagem. É bem esclarecedor.

Isso significa que, a partir das APIs do JavaScript, é **impossível** tornar, de fato, algum membro de um mapa imutável.

---

O que poderia ser feito é criar uma "subclasse"<sup>1</sup> de `Map` chamada `ImmutableMap` que, ao sobrescrever o método `set`, impede qualquer tipo de modificação em valores. Ademais, valores só podem ser adicionados na construção.

```js
class ImmutableMap extends Map {
  constructor(initialEntries) {
    super();
    for (const [key, val] of initialEntries) {
      super.set(key, val);
    }
  }
  
  // Sobrescreve o método `set`:
  set() {
    console.log('This map is readonly.');
    // Não vou lançar erro para fins didáticos, mas seria de bom tom:
    // throw new TypeError('Attempted to mutate a readonly map.');
  }
}

const imap = new ImmutableMap([
  ['name', 'Luiz Felipe'],
  ['publicUserId', 'lffg']
]);

console.log(imap.get('name')); //=> 'Luiz Felipe'
imap.set('name', 'Luiz Felipe 2'); //=> This map is readonly.
console.log(imap.get('name')); //=> 'Luiz Felipe'
```

Claro que realmente a utilidade disso me parece mínima, mas a ideia é essa.

É interessante mencionar, também, que nada disso realmente funciona para tornar uma instância de `Map` (ou `ImmutableMap`, que implementamos acima) realmente imutável, já que o pode-se utilizar o método `Map.prototype.set` com `this` sendo a instância modificada. Para isso, pode-se utilizar `Function.prototype.call` ou `Function.prototype.apply`.

As três últimas linhas deste exemplo demonstram isso. Queira verificar:

```js
class ImmutableMap extends Map {
  constructor(initialEntries) {
    super();
    for (const [key, val] of initialEntries) {
      super.set(key, val);
    }
  }
  
  // Sobrescreve o método `set`:
  set() {
    console.log('This map is readonly.');
    // Não vou lançar erro para fins didáticos, mas seria de bom tom:
    // throw new TypeError('Attempted to mutate a readonly map.');
  }
}

const imap = new ImmutableMap([
  ['name', 'Luiz Felipe'],
  ['publicUserId', 'lffg']
]);

console.log(imap.get('name')); //=> 'Luiz Felipe'
imap.set('name', 'Luiz Felipe 2'); //=> This map is readonly.
console.log(imap.get('name')); //=> 'Luiz Felipe'

// CONTRA ISTO NÃO HÁ ESCAPATÓRIA.
Map.prototype.set.call(imap, 'name', 'Luiz Felipe 3');
console.log(imap.get('name')); //=> 'Luiz Felipe 3'
```

Nem o *monkey patch*, [sugerido nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/509804/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-aplicar-ou-simular-imutabilidade-em-um-objeto-do-tipo-map-no-javasc#comment936290_509804), resolveria essa limitação. É uma limitação que se deve ao fato de que não temos próprio acesso ao *store* do mapa.

Ah! O a natureza prototípica do JavaScript nos atrapalhando. Mas quem se importa, né? :-)

Em suma, é válido concluir que **é impossível tornar um mapa imutável em JavaScript**.

---

A única "solução" que vejo para isso é criar uma implementação completamente diferente, que usa um `Map` internamente como detalhe de implementação. Mas nesse caso, para ser justo, nem se trata mais de uma instância de `Map`. É um objeto completamente diferente. Então não acho que funciona como resposta. De todo modo, a ideia está aí.

---

#### Rodapé

Nota 1: Coloquei entre aspas porque a orientação a objetos do JavaScript não é *clássica*, mas sim prototípica.

Comment: O lançe da classe que estende `Map` foi genial. O que eu tinha em mente era o que o Augusto tinha comentado. Obrigado por ter me dado outra ideia ;)