# O que são "Fancy Words" (palavras extravagantes) em linguagens de programação?

Tags: independente-de-linguagem

Antes de tudo, não sei se é um conceito restrito a linguagens como TypeScript ou JavaScript, então assumo que seja de propósito geral.

Me deparei com os seguintes códigos que vou usar como base de exemplo:

```js
// F.W. ephemeral
const getAccessTokenOfUser = (id: string) => {
  // ....

  return token;
};
```

Pensei que `F.W.` se referia a um nome de pessoa, mas descobri que esse `F.W.` significa *Fancy Word* (*palavra extravagante* em pt-Br).

Em `getAccessTokenOfUser`, o conceito de `ephemeral` (efêmero) é de algo que não dura muito, ou que dura 1 dia. O que está de acordo como o código que analisei, pois a chave do `token`, que é um JWT, tem duração de 1 dia.

Em outro trecho de código, simplificado para exemplificar, tenho o seguinte:

```js
/**
 * @param {string} storageType F.W. Idempotent, according what is defined on STORAGE in .env
 * file and never change during life time.
 *
 * @returns {boolean} F.W. Predicate, according what is defined in storageType.
 */

export const storageTypeStatusIsProductionReady = (
  storageType: string
): boolean => {
  const storage = {
    a: {
      // ...
      isProductionReady: false
    },
    b: {
      // ...
      isProductionReady: true
    }
  };
  // ...

  return storage[storageType].isProductionReady;
};
```

Ele faz referência a `Idempotent` e `Predicate` nesse JSDoc e pelo que eu entendi,
essas palavras "chave", por assim dizer, representam algum significado padronizado de alguma ação, valor ou recurso.

Analisando a função `storageTypeStatusIsProductionReady`, ela retorna um *boolean* `true` ou `false`, então, pelo o que eu entendi, ***Predicate*** se refere a um grupo de valores possíveis de serem retornados. Algo como previsível ou pré-determinado a retornar (acho que a programação funcional define assim) de acordo com o que é `Idempotent` como o `storageType`.

Me parece que essas *Fancy Words* são palavras que servem de valor semântico, não para máquinas, mas para pessoas que irão analisar, documentar e/ou usar um determinado trecho de código. Posso estar enganado, mas pelo que entendi dos exemplos acima citados, elas tem significância maior para documentar códigos.

Gostaria de saber mais do assunto de *Fancy Words*, quais outras palavras possuem maior valor semântico e quais são mais usadas. Se *Fancy Words* são palavras chaves para definir conceitos de programação, se é um sinônimo para algum conceito que eu já conheço...

... ou se foi só um padrão adotado somente pelos criadores dos códigos acima.

Comment: Até onde eu sei, _predicate_ é, geralmente, uma função que se passa para... determinar um "predicado"! Por exemplo, há quem diga que o _callback_ que se passa ao `Array.prototype.filter` do JS é um predicado (note que retorna um _boolean_). Quanto às demais, nunca nem vi. :P Mas me permita observar - talvez fosse melhor utilizar a tag [independente-de-linguagem], já que me parece ser algo que vai além do escopo do JS, TS ou qualquer linguagem...

Comment: @LuizFelipe editado. Eu tambem nunca nem vi. Tô começando a achar (de acordo com a resposta do @Piovezan) que é só alguem querendo escrever "bonito".

Comment: Outra coisa... Fiquei curioso para saber de onde os excertos de código foram retirados. Foi de algum repositório aberto do GitHub? :D

Comment: Não, foi de uma postagem em um grupo de internacional de NodeJS no linkedIn (denovo), onde o autor falava sobre comentar o código com palvras semânticas de uso comum. Acho que era só pra os outros pensarem _"Nossa!!! que código mais bem documentado..."_

Comment: Acho que vou até excluir a pergunta... :(

Comment: @LuizFelipe tem [uma issue](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1286) que menciona `predicate`....

Comment: Sim... Como disse no meu primeiro comentário, dos termos que você citou na sua pergunta, o único que eu já tive contato (e ainda tenho) é o _predicate_. Comumente utilizado com "jargão" de programação – vejo mais comumente em contextos de programação funcional, aliás.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119793/discussion-between-cmte-cardeal-and-luiz-felipe).

Comment: @CmteCardeal Eu sou suspeito pra falar :) mas não acho que deva excluir a pergunta, tem um relação ainda que eventual com conceitos de programação e também conta como curiosidade gramatical que não é impossível alguém mais da área se interessar em procurar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O termo em si não tem relação direta com programação ou com uma determinada linguagem, pois é um termo de uso geral no idioma inglês para descrever certos tipos de palavras, mas acredito que está sendo aplicado num contexto de programação por duas razões, para nomear certas palavras de uso pouco comum que podem causar certa impressão para quem não conhece bem o termo e também principalmente para apontar que essas palavras representam certas qualidades técnicas/computacionais desejáveis no código em questão.

A palavra ***"fancy"*** em inglês, entre outros significados, é um adjetivo que significa o oposto daquilo que é *"plain"* (comum, regular, sem graça). Traduz qualidades como especial, atraente, elaborado, requintado, entre outras. "Extravagante" que você citou descreve bem. Por exemplo: *"A cosplayer in a fancy dress/costume"* passa a ideia de um vestido ou fantasia "incrementada".

A expressão ***"fancy word"*** também é de uso comum no inglês, referindo-se a quaisquer palavras que sejam elaboradas, requintadas, *"showy"* (que "gostam de aparecer"), "intelectuais". Para dar a ideia eu traduziria como "palavras difíceis" ou quem sabe até "metidas a besta". Não é nada mais além de querer dizer que uma palavra é difícil ou extravagante (tipo "papibaquígrafo"). Inclui portanto aí qualquer jargão técnico que soe portentoso, ainda mais para quem não sabe direito o que ele significa, ou por equivaler a um conceito mais amplo que se está tentando resumir em uma única palavra, o que no caso da nossa área incluiria por exemplo "efêmero", "idempotente", "ortogonal" (*"cross-cutting"*), "atômico", "concorrente", "persistente" (no sentido de persistir dados), "multiparadigmático", etc., em especial os que descrevem qualidades ou características (portanto frequentemente adjetivos), que se poderia chamar de "padronizados" ou semânticos" como é dito na pergunta, mas serve também para qualquer palavra, técnica ou não, que seja pouco comum ou que possa soar um pouco pedante.

Por exemplo, num contexto fora da computação, "resplandecente" é uma palavra difícil para se dizer simplesmente "bonito". "Ósculo" no lugar de "beijo". "Bibliófilo" para "gostar de livros".

"Efêmero" é uma forma pouco usual de dizer "breve", "de vida curta", em computação pode ter um significado mais específico de uma informação volátil, não-persistente, não-durável. Exemplos são os já citados tokens de acesso com prazo de vencimento curto, dados que estejam em memória RAM e não chegaram a ser salvos em dispositivos de armazenamento permanente, e a qualificação de certas variáveis no Java como `volatile` ou `transient`.

"Idempotente" é usada em computação para qualificar uma operação que produz sempre o mesmo resultado independente do número de vezes que seja chamada, dado que suas entradas sejam as mesmas todas as vezes (característica a ser observada ao implementar o comportamento esperado de certos métodos do protocolo HTTP, como o GET, e em outros não, com o POST). Uma diferenciação importante quando se usa esses métodos em desenvolvimento web, portanto.

Não citei o "predicate", mas se for procurar verá que é um termo usado em matemática e em computação.

Veja esses títulos que traduzi de dois artigos não ligados a computação, que dão a entender que *fancy words* soam intelectuais ou pouco usuais. Sugerem bastante que o termo possa ser traduzido como "palavras difíceis" mesmo:

- [25 Fancy Words Que Irão Fazer Você Parecer Mais Inteligente](https://www.rd.com/list/fancy-words-sound-smarter/)
- [12 Fancy Words Para Palavras Cotidianas](https://www.dictionary.com/e/keep-classy-fancy-words-listicle/)

Na comunidade [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=fancy+words) ninguém perguntou ainda o que significa essa expressão, mas está sendo mencionada em vários exemplos que subentendem essa ideia que descrevi.

Na antiga *Escolinha do Prof. Raimundo* (para entregar a minha idade) quem usava muitas *fancy words* era o Seu Rolando Lero para bajular o professor e também o próprio professor na hora de elogiar o Seu Ptolomeu depois de um de seus esclarecimentos intelectuais para os outros alunos. :) *"O senhor hoje está adstringente! Insofismável! Avassalador!..."* , etc.

Acredito que o termo esteja sendo usado na documentação citada para dizer que a intenção daquele código documentado seja a de possuir ou fornecer determinada qualidade ou propriedade técnica conhecida, como o caso das que foram citadas (ser efêmero, ser idempotente). Está querendo designar qualidades específicas de uma maneira concisa (isto é, em poucas palavras). Certamente é uma forma bastante factível de se transmitir uma ideia precisa quando se documenta um software.

Em tempo, achei [esse vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Zc9ci9L5wY&t=323s): *"Sete palavras difíceis da programação"*, incluindo as que foram citadas na pergunta :)

Aproveitando a deixa da resposta do AP, acredito que os termos *[overengineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering)* e *overengineered* ("feito com excesso de engenharia" ou "com engenharia excessiva" - complicado achar tradução exata) também entram como "palavras díficeis" usadas na nossa área (e também em outras) que encerram um significado especial, dando a ideia de que soluções e produtos devam ser feitos com a medida certa de funcionalidades, design e esforço, e em particular evitando excessos.

Comment: Entendi seu ponto e gostaria de dar um +1, mas acho que como não tem haver com programação, vou analisar se vale a pena manter ou não a pergunta. Estou começando a achar que foi só uma padronização de um grupo especifico de programadores para documentar um código.

Comment: acho que [imutabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15510/o-que-imut%c3%a1vel-realmente-significa/15512#15512) seria um exemplo de Fancy Word

Comment: @CmteCardeal Com certeza. Em Computação tem muitas. Humanas e Biológicas também. :) Acho difícil uma área do conhecimento humano não ter para descrever suas especificidades de maneira concisa.

Comment: Publiquei a resposta com o link que voce informou para termos uma resposta mais técnica. Bom saber que essas palavras tem realmente um significado na programação.

Answer (score 2):

## Resolvido

Agradecendo a contribuição do @Piovezan e sua excelente resposta, ele compartilhou um material para complementá-la.

Neste [excelente material](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Zc9ci9L5wY&t=14s) informado pelo @Piovezan, é explicado algumas *Fancy Words* comuns em programação e gostaria de elaborar uma resposta mais completa e compartilhar com os interessados no assunto.

Eu achei até o presente momento que *Fancy Words* eram decisões de times para padronizar uma documentação ou até mesmo achar que era semelhante a Overengineering, algo como OverengineeringDocuments, mas minha visão mudou.

A lista é essa:

- `Idempotent` (Idempotente)
- `Ephemeral` (efêmero)
- `Anonymous` (Anônimo)
- `Predicate` (Predicado)
- `Memoization` (Memoização)
- `Abstraction` (Abstração)
- `Serialization` (Serialização)

Vamos às explicações...

### Idempotent

Se refere a uma operação que dado os mesmos parâmetro, resultará nos mesmos resultados. Isso me remeteu imediatamente a programação funcional, mais especificamente à funções puras.

Exemplo do dia-a-dia:

- Apertar o botão do elevador várias vezes, não vai fazer o elevador subir mais rápido.

Exemplo com código:

1. Não Idempotente - O array muda com as mesmas operações

```js
const arr = [];

arr.push('oi');
arr.push('oi');
arr.push('oi');

console.log(arr); // (3) ["oi", "oi", "oi"]
```

2. Idempotente - O `set` não muda com as mesmas operações

```js
const set = new Set();

set.add('oi');
set.add('oi');
set.add('oi');

console.log(set); // Set(1) {"oi"}
```

### Ephemeral

Algo que dure 1 dia... ou pouco tempo. Basicamente nos diz sobre algo (estado) que não é persistido, como por exemplo um valor salvo em memória cache. Uma memória ram de computador seria um exemplo componente efêmero. De certa forma, tem uma relação com *mutabilidade*, pois se trata da não conservação de estado, mas creio que isso possa ser uma boa discursão [sobre imutabilidade ou mutabilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15510/o-que-imut%c3%a1vel-realmente-significa/15512#15512).

Exemplos:

1. Código efêmero:

```js
const automovel = {
  rodas: 2,
  motorizado: true
};

// ....

// em algume momento futuro, depois de alguma condição...

automovel.motorizado = false;

console.log(automovel); // {rodas: 2, motorizado: false}
```

2. Código não efêmero:

```js
const automovel = {
  rodas: 2,
  motorizado: true
};

Object.freeze(automovel); // não permite mudança

// ....

// em algume momento futuro, depois de alguma condição...

automovel.motorizado = false;

console.log(automovel); // {rodas: 2, motorizado: true}
```

### Anonymous

Algo o qual não foi atribuído nenhuma identificação ou intencionalmente não a possui, é anônimo. Acho que não há muito que explicar...

Exemplos:

1. Código anônimo: Usando o `map` do JavaScript é comum passarmos um função anônima como argumento.

```js
const arr = ['olá', 'stackoverflow', 'português'];

const arrUppercase = arr.map((el) => el.toUpperCase());

console.log(arrUppercase); // (3) ["OLÁ", "STACKOVERFLOW", "PORTUGUÊS"]
```

2. Código não anônimo: Usando `map`, mas agora passamos uma função com nome definido.

```js
const arr = ['olá', 'stackoverflow', 'português'];

function upperCaseWordsFunction(el) {
return el.toUpperCase();
}

const arrUppercase = arr.map(upperCaseWordsFunction);

console.log(arrUppercase); // (3) ["OLÁ", "STACKOVERFLOW", "PORTUGUÊS"]
```

### Predicate

Em programação, geralmente, se refere a uma função/método que retorna somente 1 valor booleano. Pode ser usado em funções para validar algum parâmetro de função, por exemplo, e prosseguir de maneira X ou Y.

Exemplos:

```js
// função "predicate"
const isBrazil = (country) => {
return country === 'brasil';
}

const sayHelloToSO = (to) => {
if (isBrazil(to)) console.log('Olá comunidade do StackOverflow!')
else console.log('Hello community StackOverflow!')
}

sayHelloToSO('spain');
sayHelloToSO('brasil');
```

### Memoization

Memorizar, salvar, guardar, armazenar alguma coisa em algum lugar. Podemos nos referir a uma função que
mantém um valor em memória (caching). São usadas principalmente em funçoes de alto custo de processamento.

**Wikipedia**:

> In computing, memoization or memoisation is an optimization technique used primarily to speed up computer programs by storing the results of expensive function calls and returning the cached result when the same inputs occur again.

Tradução:

> Na computação, memoização ou memoização é uma técnica de otimização usada principalmente para acelerar programas de computador, armazenando os resultados de chamadas de funções caras e retornando o resultado em cache quando as mesmas entradas ocorrerem novamente.

Exemplo do dia-a-dia: O React tem um ḿetodo chamado [`useMemo`](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) que retorna um valor *memoizado*.

Exemplo com código:

1. Código memoizado: Uma função recursiva usada para retornar a sequência de Fibonacci.

```js
const memo = {};

function fibonacci(x) {
if (memo[x]) return memo[x];
if (x <= 1) return x;

return (memo[x] = fibonacci(x - 1) + fibonacci(x - 2));
}

console.time();
console.log(fibonacci(20));
console.timeEnd();
```

No caso acima, salvamos o valor no objeto `memo` para quando encontrarmos o mesmo valor novamente, não será necessário computá-lo novamente. Isso evita processamento extra.

Se fosse recursão sem memoization:

2. Código não memoizado:

```js
function fibonacci(num) {
if (num <= 1) return num;

return fibonacci(num - 1) + fibonacci(num - 2);
}

console.time();
console.log(fibonacci(20));
console.timeEnd();
```

Complexidade

1. Recursão com memoization:

- Time complexity: O(2N)

2. Recursão sem memoization:

- Time complexity: O(2^N)

### Abstraction

Significado `"drawn from"`, traduzindo `"retirado/extraído de (algum lugar)"`. Em geral, se trata de "esconder" os detalhes de implementações do usuário final.

Exemplos do dia-a-dia: Uma API é uma abstração.

Exemplo com código:

1. Uma classe abstrata que não revela detalhes de sua implementação:

```js
abstract class Fish {
  swin() { return 'Nadando rápido' }
}

class Nemo extends Fish {
  filme: 'Procurando Nemo'
}

class Aquaman extends Fish {
  filme: 'Liga da justiça'
}
```

### Serialization

Algo devidamente ordenado, de uma forma que partes distintas possam entender o mesmo objeto. Podemos dizer que "serializar" seria construir uma estrutura de dados todas as partes distintas possam manipular e tabalhar com.

Exemplo clássico: JSON, um objeto em JavaScript pode ser serializado (convertido para o formato JSON) e pode ser enviado por uma API para um programa em Python, por exemplo. Este código em Python pode desserializar esse JSON para um objeto o qual o Python pode entender e manipular.

Exemplo com código:

**JavaScript**:

```js
const person = {
  name: 'Darth Vader'
};

JSON.stringify(person);
```

**Python**:

```py
import json

dataFromJs = "{name:'Darth Vader'}"

x = json.loads(dataFromJs)
```

Comment: Algumas correções: 1) Embora "to draw" signifique desenhar, "drawn from" geralmente tem o sentido de "retirado/extraído de (algum lugar)", por exemplo extrair um exemplo de um livro, tirar uma carta do baralho ou sacar uma arma (da bainha).

Comment: 2) Abstração (abstrair algo) significa representar o essencial de uma coisa ao mesmo tempo que omite as partes irrelevantes (detalhes). Por exemplo, dizer "pessoa" em vez de "cabeça, tronco e membros". Sua consequência imediata é permitir representar e trabalhar com conceitos e informações num nível mais alto (de abstração ou entendimento de um problema) que outros, além de permitir intercambiar os detalhes (forma de fazer) dos níveis inferiores sem afetar o comportamento esperado para os superiores (exemplo: trocar de veículo sem ter que reaprender a dirigir). Também funções e objetos.

Comment: 3) O exemplo de abstração não está bom, classe Peixe tudo bem mas classe Tubarão é melhor que classe Nemo, que seria uma instância de Peixe-Palhaço. 4) Serializar vem de colocar em série (sequência), no caso para fins de transmitir ou armazenar. Tem a ver com dados e não com falar algo na mesma língua (isso é protocolo de comunicação). 5) Memoization deve estar certo mas provavelmente não é exatamente igual a memoRização senão se chamaria memoRization de uma vez. Pelo jeito é o mesmo que, ou um caso específico de, caching. Ou vice-versa, quem sabe.

Comment: O conceito-chave de um dos dois a meu ver é que muitas vezes uma informação tem um custo alto de tempo ou recursos para ser obtida e então se permite duplicação dessa informação ou pelo menos parte dela a fim de disponibilizar os dados resultantes mais rápido/barato que o custo de trazer ou computar a informação original. A consequência é ter que gerenciar essa duplicidade. Caches em geral têm a ver com isso.

Comment: Obs importantes. Vou editar a resposta.