# Como funciona a execução de uma aplicação .NET?

Tags: .net, compilação, clr

Existem vários termos que sempre ouço/leio quando vejo falarem sobre a execução de aplicações .NET, tais como ***MSIL***, ***CIL***, ***IL***, ***JIT***, ***JITer***, ***Roslyn***, ***CLR***, entre outros que eu devo ter esquecido.

Eu gostaria de uma breve explicação de como funciona a execução de uma aplicação .NET, junto com uma pequena explicação sobre esses nomes que citei.

Se fizer diferença, tenho preferência por exemplos em C# e, se for possível, que os exemplos se baseiem nesse código (isso para manter um padrão entre as respostas).

```
using System;
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     string nome = "Joaquim da Silva";
     Console.WriteLine(nome);
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: [Compilador Roslyn - O que é, e porque foi criado?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/91)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O [.NET Compiler Platform](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101) (<strike>anteriormente</strike> chamado de Roslyn) é usado como base do compilador de códigos de C# ou VB.NET. Isto pode ser entendido na pergunta [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101).

Depois de compilado, a linguagem em si não tem mais importância. Tudo vira um "código de máquina".

Após o processo de compilação do código fonte, é gerado um executável (no fundo um *container*, não é um executável comum como os gerados nativamente por compilador como do C++, por exemplo) com o código IL (Intermediate Language) que é um código binário que poderíamos chamar de código de máquina da plataforma [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101) (Commom Language Runtime) e com [metadados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/107111/101).

O CIL é o nome "oficial" deste código intermediário (Common Intermediate Language). MSIL é como alguns chamam isso. O MS obviamente é de Microsoft, já que inicialmente a expectativa era que isto seria uma tecnologia proprietária desta empresa.

Um dos componentes do CLR é o [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101). Poderíamos chamá-lo de JIT Compiler (embora o "er" possa ser explicado pela gramática inglesa indicando que aquilo é um agente executor de alguma ação). JIT significa Just-In-Time, ou "na hora que precisa". Isto significa que ele será invocado quando o código for executado. O papel dele é transformar esse código de máquina interno desta plataforma (o .NET, o Mono, etc.) para o código de máquina da plataforma física onde o software compilado está executando.

Após esse processo o código, grosso modo, roda como se fosse nativo desde o princípio. O JITter traz a vantagem de sempre poder otimizar a execução a cada execução, mas demora mais para inicializar o software e exige um ambiente mais completo e pesado para acompanhar a execução.

Este ambiente é implementado pelo [VES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Execution_System) (Virtual Environment System).

Tudo isto está [definido pelo padrão](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) da [CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure) (Common Language Infraestructure).

[Essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14334/101) pode ajudar um pouco.

Os [nomes e versões](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21672/101), o que é o que, são um pouco confusos.

O [.NET 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) mudou um pouco a relação entre essas coisas todas.

Obviamente muitas dúvidas ainda podem persistir e sugiro novas perguntas mais específicas em cada ponto que mereça algo dedicado.

O código acima é compilado para o código CIL (mostrado de forma para um humano visualizar e não para o computador):

```
// Metadata version: v4.0.30319
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
.assembly '41188d85-05c0-4a3b-bbaf-cfc8464a6216'
{
  .hash algorithm 0x00008004
  .ver 0:0:0:0
}
.module '41188d85-05c0-4a3b-bbaf-cfc8464a6216.dll'
// MVID: {A36CB87C-35BA-4424-83CC-9E8C29792DDE}
.imagebase 0x10000000
.file alignment 0x00000200
.stackreserve 0x00100000
.subsystem 0x0003       // WINDOWS_CUI
.corflags 0x00000001    //  ILONLY
// Image base: 0x00BD0000


// =============== CLASS MEMBERS DECLARATION ===================

.class public auto ansi beforefieldinit Exemplo
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
  .method public hidebysig static void  Main() cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  1
    .locals init (string V_0)
    IL_0000:  nop
    IL_0001:  ldstr      "Joaquim da Silva"
    IL_0006:  stloc.0
    IL_0007:  ldloc.0
    IL_0008:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_000d:  nop
    IL_000e:  ret
  } // end of method Exemplo::Main

  .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname 
          instance void  .ctor() cil managed
  {
    // 
    .maxstack  8
    IL_0000:  ldarg.0
    IL_0001:  call       instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
    IL_0006:  nop
    IL_0007:  ret
  } // end of method Exemplo::.ctor

} // end of class Exemplo
```

Esta é uma forma de visualizar humanamente o código, no executável só tem uns bytes que não fazem sentido pra gente, não tem essa organização e comentários assim.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Qual ferramenta você usou para gerar este `CIL`? Eu estou usando o LINQPad, mas pelo jeito ele só gera o outro tipo.

Comment: O IL Disassembler que vem junto com o .Net.

Comment: Não esquecer da não menos importante C++/CLI, que tem forte influência  no desenvolvimento de interfaces entre códigos, como por exemplo Java executando chamadas em módulos escritos em CSharp.

Comment: ótima explicação!

Answer (score 5):

O processo de execução gerenciada inclui as seguintes etapas, que são discutidas em detalhes mais adiante neste tópico:

**Escolhendo um compilador.**

Para obter as vantagens fornecidas pelo common language runtime, você deve usar um ou mais compiladores de linguagem que visa o runtime.

**Compilar seu código para MSIL.**

Compilação converte seu código fonte em Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL) e gera os metadados necessários.

**Compilação MSIL para código nativo.**

No momento da execução, um just-in-time (JIT) traduz o MSIL em código nativo. Durante esta compilação, o código deve passar um processo de verificação que examina o MSIL e metadados para descobrir se o código pode ser determinado para ser fortemente tipado.

**Executando código.**

O common language runtime fornece a infra-estrutura que permite a execução ocorra e serviços que podem ser usados durante a execução.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/k5532s8a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx