# O usuário precisa ter o .NET se eu compilar usando Mono?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, f#

O usuário que vai usar minha aplicação precisa ter a versão do .NET no PC? Vi em alguns tópicos na internet falando sobre essa vantagem do Mono.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Windows

De uma maneira geral precisa sim. A não ser que use o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) que permite rodar qualquer aplicação baseada na [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118707/101) ([outra referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101)) sem precisar ter nada instalado. Tudo o que você precisa vai junto com sua aplicação. Claro ele tem suas limitações, mas pode. Logo deverá ter o [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101) disponível para todo tipo de aplicação, hoje só pode rodar alguns tipos.

Mas é possível fazer um [*bundle*](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/guiderunning_mono_applications/#bundles) com o Mono e evitar essa dependência toda. Só não garanto que ficará tudo do jeito que deseja, que rodará tudo o que precisa. Essa forma é muito parecida com o que o .NET Core oferece.

O próprio pessoal do Mono não costuma recomendar tanto assim o seu uso no Windows. Não que tenha algum problema, mas o .NET é melhor. Tem casos que o Mono pode ser a única opção.

## Linux/MacOS

O .NET Core está disponível aqui também e o .NET Native deve ser disponibilizado. O Mono, claro, também funciona, mas tende a ser legado para a maioria das aplicações, mas, novamente, algumas aplicações ainda farão sentido.

## Informação extra

É possível misturar arquivos *assemblies* gerados com Mono e .NET, afinal eles devem ser compatíveis. Claro que nada garante que seu código será compatível em todas plataformas. Não adianta tentar rodar WPF no Linux, por exemplo.

## Atualização

[O .NET Framework está morto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101) (ou quase), e deve agora usar o .NET Core para qualquer coisa nova, então ainda precisa de um *runtime*, mas agora de uma forma diferente.

Comment: Opa! Infelizmente aposto que não vou poder pegar esse .Net Native e tacar um programa em um windows 7 sem o .Net, mas vai ajudar muito!

Comment: Melhorei a resposta, mas estão trabalhando para isto acontecer. Já com o .Net Core pode sim. Mas no fundo precisará do .Net, só não precisará instala=lo, ele vai junto com sua aplicação sem precisar da instalação.

Comment: O que é uma CLR?

Comment: @diegofm editei, veja se ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Não precisa. [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/download/) é Mono, .NET é .NET são duas coisas separadas. Aliás prova disso é que você corre Mono em sistemas Linux e Mac onde não existem a *framework* .NET criada pela Microsoft. O que pode estar a criar a sua confusão e do @Maniero é que você pode misturar bibliotecas criadas em .NET (Microsoft) com bibliotecas de Mono. Mas pode escrever o seu código completamente em Mono e compilar em Linux por exemplo, se o voltar a compilar em .net possivelmente poderá funcionar 100%.

Para mais informações leia sobre o [ECMA](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/ecma/) e a [compatibilidade entre .net e Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/)

Comment: Existe o .Net em Linux e Mac. Então a sua prova é falsa. Justamente por poder misturar as bibliotecas eu disse que em geral é necessário ter o .Net, ainda que exista a possibilidade de rodar sem ele. Ou seja, tive uma negativação baseado em falsos pressupostos.

Comment: "Existe o .Net em Linux e Mac." Desde quando? Se refere-se ao .net Core isso não é alternativa por enquanto. Qualquer pessoa prefere compilar em Mono do que em .net Core. Acredite.

Comment: Ele existe há vários meses e muita gente já o usa. Se quer uma versão final, sai esta semana. Eu não prefiro o Mono, por tudo o que leio vai haver uma debandada geral pro .Net Core e deixar o Mono em um nicho bem específico. Note que o AP, embora não tenha se referido especificamente ao Windows, dava a entender que era nesta plataforma que ele falava. De qq forma acrescentei sobre o Linux na minha resposta.

Comment: Sim sai esta semana. Mas continua a não ser nada de interessante por enquando tirando o Mvc e o Entity Framework quase não consegue fazer mais nda. Não tem reflection nem Memory Data, na minha opinião é comparavel ao Framework 1.1. O Mono faz tudo o que o Framework 4.0 faz e é muitiplataforma.

Comment: Fique com sua opinião então. Comparar o Core que é baseado no .Net 4.6 (sim faltam algumas coisas, mas coisas que ou não fazem sentido, ou que nunca deveriam ter existido no .Net, ou quase ninguém usa) com o 1.1 acabou com sua credibilidade. *Reflection* tem limitações apenas. Tem coisas que o .Net Core faz que o Mono não faz. Mas isso não leva a lugar algum. Escolha o que serve para seu projeto. Quase todos projetos funcionarão bem com o .Net Core.