# Publicar site Asp.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, compilação

Desenvolvi um site em ASP.NET MVC e agora quero publicá-lo no meu provedor usando o FTP.

Já fiz toda configuração do FTP no *Publish* do VS 2013 que estou usando. Quando mando publicar as pastas de **Controllers**, **Enums** e outras não são enviadas para o provedor e inclusive a pasta **App_Start**.

Fiz o teste e publiquei no fFile system_ e também essas pastas não são criadas. 
As únicas pastas que são enviadas para o provedor são: **bin**, **Content**, **fonts**, **Imagens**, **Scripts** e **Views**.

Minha dúvida é: por que essas outras pastas não são enviadas ao provedor pelo FTP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Porque os arquivos contidos nestas pastas não são necessários para a aplicação rodar.

Nestas pastas existem os arquivos que você desenvolve em C# (VB.NET ou outra linguagem suportada), estes arquivos serão compilados para uma DLL e é apenas desta DLL que o IIS precisa para rodar a aplicação.

As DLL's ficam todas na pasta **bin**, tanto as DLL's referentes ao seu código, quanto as DLL's de dependências do projeto.

Veja mais sobre isso:

- [Como funciona a execução de uma aplicação .Net?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118694/18246)
- [Diferença de linguagem compilada para linguagem interpretada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77070/18246)
- [C# é uma linguagem compilada ou interpretada?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125588/18246)

Comment: ótima explicação, obrigado.